# Site graduated! New design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live. Which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for your valuable [design feedback](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1501/updated-january-9-design-for-movies-se).

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with "design" and "bug."

We have also updated site's [Twitter](https://twitter.com/stackmovies) profile and [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888) themes. Congrats on the launch and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Hey, wow - thank you so much.

Comment: The chatroom theme is seriously awesome, especially the scroll feature.

Comment: This is one site where the black & white meta version of the design *really* works.

Comment: So cool.....^_^

Comment: Is there any way to turn it off? The Red - it . . . hurts.

Comment: For some reason, the links the Twitter bot posts are white & you can't read them...

Comment: I agree with @wbogacz , maybe too red for my taste... although meta is cool !!

Comment: I LOVE RED!!! Great theme :D I don't remember seeing anything like it in the rest of the SE, so straight AWESOMENESS! Good job :D

Comment: Finally! Looks awesome!

Comment: Just to point it out: the hover text color on the required tags here on Meta is white on light grey. Really hard to look at. I'm assuming the background-color is supposed to change like the other two tag styles.

Comment: @animuson good catch. Will fix.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I miss Oscar but new trophies looks good too and chatroom is good, i can't stop scrolling. Nice work and thanks for taking our suggestion and even implementing most of them.

Comment: I still think the red is a bit too intense with too little contrast (I see no difference at some distance/angle). How about making the red background a tad bit brighter? Contrast here on meta is a lot better for me.

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOVE IT!

Comment: Great design, I love how meta is just black and white, great Idea :)

Comment: In your original design post you also listed many other versions of the logo (i.e. different colors different text positioning). I'm not talking about older rejected versions, but all the different alternative logo versions for the same design. Is there a way to see (and copy) them anywhere? Or just the site icon in different sizes? Or the font you used? Because I'd like to use them to adapt [our promotion ad](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1487/49) to the new design. I.e. is there some place to view the particular design and logo guidelines/images in a formal way?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson if you contact me at my work email, I can send you an .EPS file.

Comment: Woo hoo!!! Congratulations to everyone actively participating in the site making it possible!!!

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: Congrats! The illustrations in the header are great. One thing is, the color in the body background looks dull and discordant comparing to the red color in the header. Is it only me?  [Is this voted or Are there any plans to change the body color?]

Comment: I wish the film strip moves when we hover over the mouse so we can create and see more illustrations as well :) [I know it might be too fancy, this is a Q&A site in the end. Just a wish...]

Comment: @ermanen Do you mean the plain white in the background. I love it and am glad we didn't get an overly playful background color. Though, I guess for voting, [you're a little late](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1501/49).

Comment: By the way, when is news on that "swag" stuff to be expected?

Comment: The new site is very good, I like it.