# Answer Challenge: Solve unanswered pre-graduation questions! [completed]

Tags: discussion, challenge, scheduled-event

40 days ago this site finally [graduated](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521/49) to a full-fledged SE site. We want to celebrate this event by closing some loose ends from this site's more than 3 years of beta history. So due to [popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1494/49) we're starting a new **biweekly challenge from 2015-03-09 00:00 UTC to 2015-03-23 01:00 UTC**. But instead of concentrating on asking questions about one topic only, we want you to provide **answers to any of the ~200 unanswered questions asked before graduation** (2015-01-28 21:40 UTC).<sup>1</sup> To check for questions without an answer you can use the [search function](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20closed%3ano), and to check for this challenge specifically you can use [this data query](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/284147).

Once the challenge is over we'll tally the results and winners (by answer votes) here. And in addition to that, we will **reward the top voted answer with a bounty (assuming it has a positive score)** of minimum 50 reputation, 50 additional reputation for each crossed 5 score mark and an additional 50 reputation if the answer gets accepted, too (up to the maximum amount of 500, though). Also don't forget to [suggest new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

1)  <sub>To simplify matters, we'll count every question that doesn't have any answer posted before the challenge and every answer given during the challenge is eligible (that means if more than one user answers such a question during the challenge, all answers will count).</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and has garnered a whole lot of 29 answers, with the **top voted answer** (with a score of 6 and acceptance) coming from [*Walt*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 150 additional reputation:

## 1. [How does the Basilisk roam around Hogwarts?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32027/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [Who put the Ojibwe phrase on the board at Tony's hospital room?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31948/49)

   [Value of Currency in Guardians of the Galaxy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31961/49)

   [What was in the letter to Epp's wife?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32030/49)

   [Style of shooting where common activities are filmed as if they were epic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32033/49)
3. (2+V) [Heartfire Quotes in Arrested Development](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31962/49)

   [What does Zach mean by “Machu Picchu”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32400/49)

   [On The Biggest Loser, do they interview contestants before AND after the weekly weigh-in?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31960/49)

   [Why is Brian Doyle Murray a coward?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31946/49)
4. (2) [What is the message behind Twelve Monkeys Cover?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31963/49)

   [How come the cops didn't find the gun thrown in the shallow river? But they had his prints on the murder weapon](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32457/49)
5. (1+V) [What is the website created by Walden?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32266/49)

   [What was the point of the empty container in the beginning of White Collar S06E04?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32065/49)
6. (1) [Why did the operators just came to the house?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31973/49)

   [Is this famous Michael Jackson dance move inspired by The Wizard of Oz (1939)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32047/49)

   [No Kick In Higher Level means they're stuck](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32250/49)

   [Did Tony post guys outside of Happy's hospital room and have them require badges to get in?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32210/49)

   [What is the message behind Twelve Monkeys Cover?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31972/49)

   [To which degree was the image of the “Angel of Verdun” influenced by Jeanne d'Arc?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32144/49)

   [Why is the title of The Big Bang Theory not translated in Quebec?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31965/49)

   [Why not use the wyrms to win?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31943/49)

   [What film form is Les Ordres by Michel Brault?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32459/49)
7. (0) [Why wasn't Kaffee charged?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31945/49)

   [No Kick In Higher Level means they're stuck](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32211/49)

   [What was Petit Pierre's contribution to the scheme in Micmacs?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32137/49)

   [What were the animated loops supposed to be?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/31949/49)

   [How did the bullet lodged in his brain affect Bazil in Micmacs?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32142/49)

   [Why is Bobby Munson's cut different than everyone else's?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32304/49)

   [What was the meaning of Fiona's visit to the killer in prison, in the last scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/32257/49)

---

Afterall I would say the challenge was quite a success, especially compared to our previous topic challenges, maybe because of the broader topic, maybe just because answering is indeed easier than asking, or maybe even the promised bounty provided a stronger incentive than mere honour would have done. Of course it is natural for answers to old questions to not gain too much attention and votes, but we managed to get ~13% of all the unanswered beta questions answered, some of them even accepted and thus effectively solved. I think the challenge might have motivated one or the other user to engage more deeply into questions they might always have found interesting but never felt confident enough to answer, at least this was the case for me. I might even go as far as making it a regular habit to reward the best answer to an old unanswered question each month.