# Monthly Answer Challenge 2015-2017: Solve old unanswered questions!

Tags: discussion, challenge, answers

Due to the success of our previous [challenge for answering unanswered pre-graduation questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1700/49), We've decided to make it a **monthly habit** to reward the best answer to any old unanswered question in order to encourage people to engage into solving some of our old unsolved problems. Thus independent from our more question-centered [weekly topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49), we'd like you to **answer any question that was asked more than 3 months before the current month and that doesn't have an answer yet**.

To check for eligible questions you can use the [search function](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+created%3A..2017-09) or [this data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/370061). The top-voted answer given each month will be rewarded **a bounty of 100 points if it has a score of at least 3 or has been accepted**.

Comment: How do you find these answers?

Comment: @AbhishekAggrawal With an appropriate SEDE query, combined with a customized search for the time periods that SEDE doesn't capture.

Comment: Could you accept the last month so it gets on top ?

Comment: Maybe you should make annual additions of this post, as it's becoming too long to scroll.

Comment: Hmm, true. But then again, you can as well sort the answers by "active" or "oldest".

Comment: @NapoleonWilson  This seems to be available only on desktop, not in the SE app.

Answer (score 8):

The **July 2015** challenge has garnered 15 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 4 and acceptance) coming from [*Ignorante*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22679), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Where did the “dream effect” originate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36162/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3) [What's with Mamet's dialogue style?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36886/49)
3. (2+V) [What is Stephen Chow working on post Journey to the West?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36406/49)
4. (2) [Was there any mutual inspiration between Copper and Ripper Street?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36415/49)

   [In which way do the engravings represent Dean Corso's journey towards The Ninth Gate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36224/49)
5. (1+V) [Was it Uday or Latif who took the pill overdose?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36061/49)
6. (1) [Why did Church believe Barney owed him?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36197/49)

   [When did Sullivan exactly realize who the undercover guy (DiCaprio) was?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36419/49)

   [What was Oldman spinning around in?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36538/49)
7. (0+V) [Why didn't little Barry get vanished?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36286/49)
8. (0) [Who is the second Hamlin in Hamlin, Hamlin and McGill?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36995/49)

   [Why did Ben manipulate Locke into not entering the code?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36116/49)

   [Were the characters of Tiwana, Lydia, and Calvin also in the book?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36537/49)

   [Did Trevor Reznik really go to the amusement park?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36627/49)
9. (-1) [Was Johnston supposed to be speaking in Mandarin all the time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/36541/49)

Answer (score 6):

The **May 2015** challenge has garnered 17 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 4 and acceptance) coming from [*bizentass*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/20441), [*MJ6*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1606) and [*nelruk*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/21286), which makes them the winners of this challenge and earns them each a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Was this character from 'Better Call Saul' also in 'Breaking bad'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34767/49)

## [Does" Jane Kaczmarek actually whistle in “Mrs. Tri-County”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34453/49)

## [Season 2: What is so important about the bridge?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34411/49])

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3) [Did Lucy become a Buddha?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34298/49)
3. (2+V) [Why hasn't Team Machine told Control who was really behind Vigilance?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34891/49)
4. (2) [How can Jack deliver such toys to the children?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34475/49)

   [Is the series based on a game?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34371/49)

   [Captions in Mexican TV Commercials](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34253/49)
5. (1+V) [Does anyone know the version of the song “Strange Fruit” played in Criminal Minds S09E09?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34439/49)
6. (0) [Grabbing someone's wrist before they strike…?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34226/49)

   [Why does Emily give Will the diary?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34223/49)

   [What were the numbers shouted by the dwarf woman?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34030/49)

   [Laura's coconut secret](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34243/49)

   [How does Murphy overcome the “Red Asset”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34341/49)

   [What is the “vector analysis” used in The Bletchley Circle?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34449/49)

   [What is the origin of the “face behind a wall of equations” shot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34369/49)

   [Does anyone know the version of the song “Strange Fruit” played in Criminal Minds S09E09?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/34432/49)

Answer (score 4):

The **August 2015** challenge has garnered 7 answers, with the top-voted answer (with a score of 2 and acceptance) coming from [*Tom Cody*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/49), which makes him the winner of this challenge and will earn him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Who are the people who mug the ghost outside of Rhinehart's publishing firm?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39021/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (2) [Why do Penny and Sheldon's mom sing “Soft Kitty, Warm Kitty” differently?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/37378/49)
3. (1) [What were Henryk, Halina and others chosen for?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/37464/49)
4. (0) [Why does the mugger that Finch pays off react this way?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/37302/49)

   [What is the real story behind movie Badlapur?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/37403/49)

   [How did the DHARMA Initiative fit into Lost's story?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/37459/49)
5. (-1) [Why is Borg a 'Jarl', while everyone else is an 'Earl'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/38731/49)

Answer (score 4):

The **November 2015** challenge has garnered 29 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 3 and acceptance) coming from [*Richard*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/7812) and [*Orace*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/20080), which makes them the winners of this challenge and earns them each a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Was Birdemic planned to be a bad movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43464/49)

## [Captain on his motorcycle got a speed-ticket](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43977/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (2+V) [Why do Minions want to serve vicious villains?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43360/49)
3. (2) [Do they ever really wake up from the sedative test?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43465/49)

   [Jason Bourne as Gilberto di Piento and passports](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43785/49)

   [A show about a woman released from prison who works in a hotel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43488/49)

   [Why do the sheep in the movie “Babe” have a password?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43725/49)
4. (1+V) [S01E10: How did Romero know about the money?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43940/49)

   [Why does Reid scribble into his notebook `Extreme Aggressor`](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43921/49)
5. (1) [Why do the pirates have white teeth?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43778/49)

   [How do they locate the physical body in Animatrix: Kid's story?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43773/49)

   [How does Impractical Jokers get the permission to be in places like IKEA?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43777/49)

   [Can this quote from The Fifth Estate be attributed to Julian Assange?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43774/49)

   [Need help understanding “Finding Forrester”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43920/49)

   [Was the stutter intentional?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43795/49)

   [Where is Angel 06 being sent?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43472/49)

   [Why didn't Cinderella's slippers disappear?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43326/49)
6. (0) [What is the laser sound in the tunnel?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43473/49)

   [What happened in “If I Stay”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43178/49)

   [In the movie The Colony (2013), please explain this scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43171/49)

   [What's the relationship between Claire and Stephen in Southcliffe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43790/49)

   [Where did the cantina and fishing boats come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43948/49)

   [Where did the 2nd Ooze canister come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43791/49)

   [Did Melody actually fall through the door?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43951/49)

   [When did Carroll get out of the transport?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44116/49)

   [Why does Annie say “Susan” after Abed proposes calling the group the “Stephen King's Dreamcatchers”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43957/49)
7. (-1) [Movie about an evil witch trapped in a mirror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43014/49)
8. (-2) [Switch in *The Matrix* - Two Actors?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43648/49)
9. (-3) [How did Cruella de Vil and Ursula not age a bit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/43102/49)

Answer (score 4):

The **January 2017** challenge has garnered 27 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 16 and acceptance) coming from [*Cearon O'Flynn*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22037), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Who played the locksmith in the first Men in Black film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/54992/who-played-the-locksmith-in-the-first-men-in-black-film/67069#67069)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (11+V) [Is there any reason for the absence of Walt in Lost?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51290/is-there-any-reason-for-the-absence-of-walt-in-lost/67200#67200)
3. (5+V) [Are David Attenborough documentaries still dubbed in the US?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47343/are-david-attenborough-documentaries-still-dubbed-in-the-us/67160#67160)
4. (4+V) [Why was Schillinger so brutal in the very beginning even if he hoped for parole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/why-was-schillinger-so-brutal-in-the-very-beginning-even-if-he-hoped-for-parole/66511#66511)
5. (3+V) [Member Berries in South Park](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62211/member-berries-in-south-park/66990#66990)

   [Are Dylan and the Four Horsemen still wanted criminals?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50545/are-dylan-and-the-four-horsemen-still-wanted-criminals/67838#67838)

   [Why couldn't Krall and crew repair the USS Franklin when Scotty and Jaylah could?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62507/why-couldnt-krall-and-crew-repair-the-uss-franklin-when-scotty-and-jaylah-could/67849#67849)
6. (3) [Did Emerald City have any success stories?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45113/did-emerald-city-have-any-success-stories/66435#66435)

   [Did Emerald City have any success stories?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45113/did-emerald-city-have-any-success-stories/66915#66915)

   [Ocean's Twelve hotel scene with Saul's card having problem?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62263/oceans-twelve-hotel-scene-with-sauls-card-having-problem/66400#66400)

   [What was the point of releasing the President's 'unofficial schedule' in S1E13?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45329/what-was-the-point-of-releasing-the-presidents-unofficial-schedule-in-s1e13/67538#67538)

   [Why does Mycroft say this in that time period?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46124/why-does-mycroft-say-this-in-that-time-period/67013#67013)

   [Relationship between White Walkers and Children of the Forest](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53395/relationship-between-white-walkers-and-children-of-the-forest/67834#67834)

   [Which Salvatore Brothers' emotion got heightened up after becoming vampires?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60652/which-salvatore-brothers-emotion-got-heightened-up-after-becoming-vampires/67768#67768)
7. (2) [Why was Schillinger so brutal in the very beginning even if he hoped for parole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32119/why-was-schillinger-so-brutal-in-the-very-beginning-even-if-he-hoped-for-parole/66646#66646)
8. (1) [Who is the monologue targeted at at the end of White Tiger?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33226/who-is-the-monologue-targeted-at-at-the-end-of-white-tiger/66114#66114)

   [What are the devices that Stryker's team use](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/what-are-the-devices-that-strykers-team-use/66793#66793)
9. (0) [What are the devices that Stryker's team use](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/what-are-the-devices-that-strykers-team-use/66789#66789)

   [Are the performances on Glee largely the characters' imagination?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61261/are-the-performances-on-glee-largely-the-characters-imagination/67389#67389)

   [Why is Catwoman so blonde all of a sudden in Gotham S02?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52921/why-is-catwoman-so-blonde-all-of-a-sudden-in-gotham-s02/66780#66780)

   [Does what happened to Jon Snow make him immune to White Walkers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55686/does-what-happened-to-jon-snow-make-him-immune-to-white-walkers/66398#66398)

   [Does what happened to Jon Snow make him immune to White Walkers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55686/does-what-happened-to-jon-snow-make-him-immune-to-white-walkers/66144#66144)

   [Why did Dr. Linda stop doing Lucifer?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52690/why-did-dr-linda-stop-doing-lucifer/66578#66578)

   [What effect does the non linear narrative of Mr.Nobody give?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56713/what-effect-does-the-non-linear-narrative-of-mr-nobody-give/67384#67384)

   [Why can the other Wybie help Coraline, but other characters can't?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53600/why-can-the-other-wybie-help-coraline-but-other-characters-cant/66265#66265)

   [How was Cooper confident about landing his Ranger on Miller's planet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60659/how-was-cooper-confident-about-landing-his-ranger-on-millers-planet/67835#67835)
10. (-1) [Pilots crash-landing in Australia, natives passing message over long distance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50892/pilots-crash-landing-in-australia-natives-passing-message-over-long-distance/66215#66215)

Answer (score 4):

The **March 2017** challenge has garnered 20 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 13 and acceptance) coming from [*Marzipanherz*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27900), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Elevator operator tells scary stories, ends up trapped in the mirror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55682/elevator-operator-tells-scary-stories-ends-up-trapped-in-the-mirror/70493#70493)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5+V) [Why were Lucy and Rajesh not developed as a couple?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56329/why-were-lucy-and-rajesh-not-developed-as-a-couple/69489#69489)
3. (4+V) [Was there a production rule forbidding the depiction of parents in Disney shows such as Ducktales?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62532/was-there-a-production-rule-forbidding-the-depiction-of-parents-in-disney-shows/70754#70754)

   [What was the point of showing a sexually provocative film in the Asylum?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44443/what-was-the-point-of-showing-a-sexually-provocative-film-in-the-asylum/70140#70140)
4. (4) [Why was Deadpool's origin as being imbued with Wolverine's mutant healing factor changed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65078/why-was-deadpools-origin-as-being-imbued-with-wolverines-mutant-healing-factor/70046#70046)

   [Why did Will need to speak first in the film "Good Will Hunting"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56115/why-did-will-need-to-speak-first-in-the-film-good-will-hunting/70152#70152)
5. (3+V) [Why is this person killed in the season finale of Homeland's season 5?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55992/why-is-this-person-killed-in-the-season-finale-of-homelands-season-5/69629#69629)
6. (3) [Why did Mortal Kombat: Legacy S01E06 have a special notice added from the director in the start?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65576/why-did-mortal-kombat-legacy-s01e06-have-a-special-notice-added-from-the-direct/70201#70201)

   [How far does the depiction of the pirates' characters match the book?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15320/how-far-does-the-depiction-of-the-pirates-characters-match-the-book/70194#70194)
7. (2+V) [Looking for an old Chinese cowboy film](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63751/looking-for-an-old-chinese-cowboy-film/70958#70958)
8. (2) [How was Michael Douglas' apparent facelift achieved in "Behind the Candelabra"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38965/how-was-michael-douglas-apparent-facelift-achieved-in-behind-the-candelabra/70499#70499)

   [What was the Chinese man's role in the attempt to kill Bill the Butcher?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/25073/what-was-the-chinese-mans-role-in-the-attempt-to-kill-bill-the-butcher/69708#69708)

   [Why would Lew Hayward be doomed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64367/why-would-lew-hayward-be-doomed/70269#70269)

   [On the Jeeves and Wooster TV show does Wooster say “Don’t you know?” much like the character does in the P.G. Wodehouse books?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39110/on-the-jeeves-and-wooster-tv-show-does-wooster-say-don-t-you-know-much-like-t/69578#69578)
9. (1) [In Fargo, why is the 180° rule broken during this scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46919/in-fargo-why-is-the-180-rule-broken-during-this-scene/71023#71023)

   [What was Summer doing with her tongue, and why did it surprise Seth?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53834/what-was-summer-doing-with-her-tongue-and-why-did-it-surprise-seth/69874#69874)
10. (0) [What is Jason's role / purpose in Continuum?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32957/what-is-jasons-role-purpose-in-continuum/69883#69883)

    [Why doesn't the guy in jail recognize Walter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14324/why-doesnt-the-guy-in-jail-recognize-walter/70712#70712)

    [Was Will Byers's search intentionally shown differently thematically from each character's perspective?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59796/was-will-byerss-search-intentionally-shown-differently-thematically-from-each-c/70733#70733)
11. (-1) [What is the timeline of The Lorax? Why don't the older townspeople remember the trees?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63943/what-is-the-timeline-of-the-lorax-why-dont-the-older-townspeople-remember-the/70938#70938)

Answer (score 3):

The **June 2015** challenge has garnered 11 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 4) coming from [*Deepak Kamat*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/15590), [*Ankit*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/301) and [*Shrilekha*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/21342), which makes them the winners of this challenge:

## 1. [Why did Veera keep saying “dan…dan…dan…danaka!” and what does it mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35782/49)

## [Why did Veera keep saying “dan…dan…dan…danaka!” and what does it mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35779/49)

## [Why did Veera keep saying “dan…dan…dan…danaka!” and what does it mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35775/49)

Unfortunately for them, though, their answers are all three on the exact same question. This means only one of them can get the bounty for the challenge. Yet, this question is also one of mine that I have already running a personal bounty on anyway, so the judgment which answer will get it is in the end again left to me. Strange circumstances indeed.

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3) [Is this an homage to Trading Places?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35301/49)
3. (2+V) [Why did Bishop start burning in sunlight?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35134/49)
4. (0+V) [Meaning of the 'magic circle' quote](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35197/49)
5. (0) [What does Billy show Marty that makes him leave?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35053/49)

   [Ultimate fate of Captain Hook in 1991's Hook movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35584/49)

   [Why was the actor who played Kreese in Community given credit 'Someone Else'](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35897/49)
6. (-2) [What's the deal with the bullets?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35441/49)

   [Post apocalyptic movie with cans](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/35713/49)

Answer (score 3):

The **September 2015** challenge has garnered 14 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 3 and acceptance) coming from [*cde*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/23541) and [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes them the winners of this challenge and earns them each a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How do HYDRA get the Leviathan to Strucker's base?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41201/49)

## [How “directed” were the activities filmed in Disney's Monkey Kingdom?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41331/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (1+V) [Why and how did Valentine disappear?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41219/49)
3. (1) [How did Harrison know the Enterprise had warp core issues?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41320/49)

   [What is the relevance of the Unabomber sideplot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39579/49)

   [How does ADR work?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41498/49)

   [Whom or what is the whale supposed to symbolize?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41346/49)

   [Why did Joey Gazelle choose this exit strategy at the end of Running Scared?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41357/49)
4. (0) [Was The Reverse Flash gay?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41435/49)

   [Why did Joey Gazelle choose this exit strategy at the end of Running Scared?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41349/49)

   [Why are most mobile phones set to vibrate in a TV series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39601/49)

   [Time taken assembling the meth cooking unit and again dismembering it in Breaking Bad](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39641/49)

   [Time taken assembling the meth cooking unit and again dismembering it in Breaking Bad](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/39661/49)

   [Why doesn't the temporal agent recognize himself?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41691/49)

Answer (score 3):

The **October 2015** challenge has garnered 22 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4 and acceptance) coming from [*Raiden616*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22762), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Showing journey on the map](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41762/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [Question regarding the finale of White Collar](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42190/49)

   [Why did Michael ditch his car in the river?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42398/49)
3. (2+V) [Was Fenton Mikes planning the actions FBI agent in Frailty (2001)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42403/49)

   [How did Michael end up in that basement in Season 1?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41997/49)
4. (2) [The Bodyguard hotel kitchen scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42449/49)

   [Shouldn't Skipper still be a werewolf (dog)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42452/49)

   [Who was Beni calling a “bastard” in The Mummy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42448/49)
5. (1) [Why Patrick was not arrested for his murder?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41835/49)

   [Was the suspicion that fell on The Counselor really a coincidence?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42483/49)

   [Why didn't Noah go to Allie's school or home when she didn't reply](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42454/49)

   [Against whose DNA does Cisco match?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42264/49)

   [Why does Malkina go to the church and try to confess?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42484/49)

   [Why is the Metacognitive Processor in Caprica needed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42166/49)

   [Where do the T-1000 machines come from in Terminator Genisys](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42956/49)
6. (0+V) [How did Deathbolt (Arrow/The Flash) become a meta-human?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41995/49)
7. (0) [Won't Helena get old?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42659/49)

   [If “Steel Mountain” in Mr. Robot is underground, how does that offer the implied vulnerability?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42678/49)

   [Against whose DNA does Cisco match?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42251/49)
8. [Dance and costume scenes in 'The Act of Killing'](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42198/49)

   [Was the superstition in Vikings historically accurate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42810/49)

   [What happened to the Future Flash?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42250/49)

Answer (score 3):

The **January 2016** challenge has garnered 11 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 5 and acceptance) coming from [*user29714*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/29714), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Was CGI used to make Will Smith look different in the movie Concussion?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46063/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (2) [What was the first movie to feature a person seated on a toilet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45890/49)

   [Where is the Fall located in the Colony in Total Recall (2012)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45916/49)
3. (1+V) [What's the “toss you for it” wager Jake Green makes in the casino?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46288/49)
4. (1) [Why didn't Jeetu and Yogi just lodge an FIR against the hacker?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46327/49)

   [What was the first movie to feature a person seated on a toilet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45887/49)
5. (0) [Please help identify this TV series/movie from the '90s - pirates, tropical island, sailing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46970/49)

   [Why do the male clones seem more similar to each other than the female clones do?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46287/49)

   [What does the automaton symbolise?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46717/49)

   [Trying to remember the name of an avant garde movie from the '70s](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45892/49)
6. (-1) [Movie with black vigilantes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/46978/49)

Answer (score 3):

The **February 2016** challenge has garnered 19 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 7 and acceptance) coming from [*Walt*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Movie set in or near China about a boy and his family's forced relocation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47647/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (6+V) [Is Cosmos (1980) obsolete now that Cosmos: A Spacetime Odyssey (2014) has come out?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47645/49)
3. (6) [Early 90's short film made up entirely of “bullet time” camera work](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49430/49)
4. (4+V) [What is the significance of the “fly scene”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47094/49)
5. (4) [How did Saladin obtain iced water in the middle of the desert?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47644/49)

   [Was Snow turning Senile?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47594/49)
6. (3+V) [Jodorowsky's Dune artbook](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/48816/49)
7. (3) [Does the Film Drive Have a Cameo from the star of Maniac Cop](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49093/49)

   [Comedy (Arabic?) about school teacher adopting her boyfriends' lifestyles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49193/49)
8. (2+V) [What is the first occurence of pre-show (cinema advertising) in the world?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47648/49)

   [Did Donnie Brasco really know the diamond was fake?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47522/49)
9. (2) [In Wild Wild West, what kills “Metal Head”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47600/49)

   [Why was Christopher Walken not credited in Sleepy Hollow?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/48821/49)

   [Plot-wise, what is the chronological order of all the Bond Films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49422/49)
10. (1+V) [Was the Connie/Donna transformation part of Arctor's hallucination?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47096/49)
11. (1) [Is the witch in “The Witch” (2015) real?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49188/49)
12. (0) [Animated apocalyptic sci-fi movie from the 70's or early 80's](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47695/49)

    [The Fall series 2 finale - Rose's message](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47499/49)

    [12 Monkeys: Season 1, Episode 3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/49494/49)

Answer (score 3):

The **March 2016** challenge has garnered 18 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 2 and acceptance) coming from [*Anuj Shah*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/31826), [*noob*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/30432) and [*ABcDexter*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/21081), which makes them the winners of this challenge and earns them each a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why does Harvey Specter tell Donna that finding an allegedly buried document will help the case?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39184/why-does-harvey-specter-tell-donna-that-finding-an-allegedly-buried-document-wil/49625#49625)

## [Why was the code cracking device needed in S02E10?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38644/why-was-the-code-cracking-device-needed-in-s02e10/50083#50083)

## [Can The Zeta Project be understood enough individually?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44338/can-the-zeta-project-be-understood-enough-individually/50686#50686)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (1+V) [At what point was Morgana chained to the bottom of a well?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43731/at-what-point-was-morgana-chained-to-the-bottom-of-a-well/49977#49977)

   [Final scene in Turist / Force Majeure](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26806/final-scene-in-turist-force-majeure/50419#50419)
3. (1) [Breaking Bad Confusion](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35489/breaking-bad-confusion/49588#49588)

   [How did Richard Parker manage to get the goat inside the cage?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32246/how-did-richard-parker-manage-to-get-the-goat-inside-the-cage/50622#50622)

   [What was the purpose of Abel's family being sent to meet Donovan in Bridge of Spies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44038/what-was-the-purpose-of-abels-family-being-sent-to-meet-donovan-in-bridge-of-sp/50621#50621)

   [Name of this device](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44524/name-of-this-device/50015#50015)

   [Is Heath Ledger seen in the restaurant scene in The Dark Knight?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33684/is-heath-ledger-seen-in-the-restaurant-scene-in-the-dark-knight/50692#50692)
4. (0) [When discussing box office revenue why do we typically only refer to the domestic total and not the worldwide total?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33815/when-discussing-box-office-revenue-why-do-we-typically-only-refer-to-the-domesti/50625#50625)

   https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41416/movie-with-fanatical-religious-man-who-whip-woman-and-boyfriend/50078#50078

   https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39329/true-story-2015-ending-meaning/50095#50095

   [Why does John Reese always speak with such a low voice volume?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45623/why-does-john-reese-always-speak-with-such-a-low-voice-volume/49743#49743)

   [Dr. Brennan's Academic Position?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44263/dr-brennans-academic-position/49742#49742)

   [Why is Kathryn's dog's name Ajax?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39204/why-is-kathryns-dogs-name-ajax/50627#50627)

   [Why do post-war Hollywood WWII-themed movies ignore Japan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/why-do-post-war-hollywood-wwii-themed-movies-ignore-japan/50623#50623)

   [Why were witnesses to the initial assassination in “The Parallax View” (1974) systematically killed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/why-were-witnesses-to-the-initial-assassination-in-the-parallax-view-1974-sy/49727#49727)

Answer (score 3):

The **July 2016** challenge has garnered 16 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 2 and acceptance) coming from [*user38454*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/38454), [*moviegique*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/32410), [*jfren484*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/13620) and [fabrice d](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/23193) which makes them the winners of this challenge and earns them each a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Kids tv series with tiny humans (2 men, 1 woman)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50843/kids-tv-series-with-tiny-humans-2-men-1-woman/57459#57459)

## [Why is the phone ringing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21930/why-is-the-phone-ringing/57251#57251)

## [Is the exact same sound clip used in A New Hope and The Force Awakens?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46088/is-the-exact-same-sound-clip-used-in-a-new-hope-and-the-force-awakens/56698#56698)

## [Was the development of Lockout influenced by Escape from New York?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38895/was-the-development-of-lockout-influenced-by-escape-from-new-york/56284#56284)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (2) [Why are brand names in Hindi TV series censored?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47504/why-are-brand-names-in-hindi-tv-series-censored/56610#56610)

   [What is the meaning of Jacob's line, "What about you?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51406/what-is-the-meaning-of-jacobs-line-what-about-you/56328#56328)
3. (1+V) [Did Yitzhak become a new Hedwig?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44714/did-yitzhak-become-a-new-hedwig/56236#56236)
4. (1) [Artificial intelligence movies between 1927 and 1968](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49951/artificial-intelligence-movies-between-1927-and-1968/56864#56864)

   [What deal does Finch make with H.R. In "Person of Interest"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35566/what-deal-does-finch-make-with-h-r-in-person-of-interest/56265#56265)
5. (0+V) [What is the reason for these 10-second gaps?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46438/what-is-the-reason-for-these-10-second-gaps/56763#56763)
6. (0) [Did Kwenthrith have all of the drinks poisoned in Season 3 episode 4?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49060/did-kwenthrith-have-all-of-the-drinks-poisoned-in-season-3-episode-4/57044#57044)

   [How was Deke Simmons married to Mimi Corcoran](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51665/how-was-deke-simmons-married-to-mimi-corcoran/56824#56824)

   [90s non-English spoken Demonology film from Europe; black mist, girl in a tub and guy at the library.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41220/90s-non-english-spoken-demonology-film-from-europe-black-mist-girl-in-a-tub-an/56857#56857)

   [Why did Teddy ask to change the place where the picture was about to be taken?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44592/why-did-teddy-ask-to-change-the-place-where-the-picture-was-about-to-be-taken/56565#56565)

   [The dark one appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49580/the-dark-one-appearance/56366#56366)
7. (-1) [Does Starling City have active subway or not?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44606/does-starling-city-have-active-subway-or-not/56402#56402)

Answer (score 3):

The **September 2016** challenge has garnered 35 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 4 and acceptance) coming from [*Tin Man*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/40901) and [*Montag451*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16523), which makes them the winners of this challenge and earns them bounties of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How did they achieve the crack in the ice scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45214/how-did-they-achieve-the-crack-in-the-ice-scene/60323#60323)

## [What did the German street thugs say to Donovan when they stole his coat?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49120/what-did-the-german-street-thugs-say-to-donovan-when-they-stole-his-coat/60205#60205)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (4) [Why did Sean get onto the plane in the Event?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33386/why-did-sean-get-onto-the-plane-in-the-event/61319#61319)

   [Is Toy Story inspired by The Velveteen Rabbit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44351/is-toy-story-inspired-by-the-velveteen-rabbit/60314#60314)

   [Movie or TV show from 70's or 80's about a (Russian?) scientist? with brain replaced by a computer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51223/movie-or-tv-show-from-70s-or-80s-about-a-russian-scientist-with-brain-repl/60152#60152)
3. (3+V) [How much of the film Baahubali: The Beginning is inspired from actual history of India?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49480/how-much-of-the-film-baahubali-the-beginning-is-inspired-from-actual-history-of/60786#60786)

   [Why does a character talk to the back of another character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52068/why-does-a-character-talk-to-the-back-of-another-character/61064#61064)

   [Where is Hannibal's extra finger?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43397/where-is-hannibals-extra-finger/60930#60930)
4. (3) [What is this thing that brings Nicky back to life?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50953/what-is-this-thing-that-brings-nicky-back-to-life/60678#60678)

   [Where are the spoons?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52977/where-are-the-spoons/60716#60716)
5. (2+V) [Fantasy cartoon from the 2000s about a world where people have animal companions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52778/fantasy-cartoon-from-the-2000s-about-a-world-where-people-have-animal-companions/61021#61021)

   [Olivia Godfrey's reflection in the mirror](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41213/olivia-godfreys-reflection-in-the-mirror/60862#60862)

   [Why does Ugarte trust Rick with the exit visas?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39197/why-does-ugarte-trust-rick-with-the-exit-visas/60093#60093)

   [What is the real vehicle used as The Highwayman's truck?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53652/what-is-the-real-vehicle-used-as-the-highwaymans-truck/60879#60879)
6. (2) [Why is Raymond K. Hessel an Asian man with an accent in Fight Club?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49313/why-is-raymond-k-hessel-an-asian-man-with-an-accent-in-fight-club/60753#60753)
7. (1+V) [Is Banksy's movie "Exit Through the Gift Shop" a new (sub)genre?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55940/is-banksys-movie-exit-through-the-gift-shop-a-new-subgenre/60932#60932)
8. (1) [Post-apocalyptic movie with food cans](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/post-apocalyptic-movie-with-food-cans/60739#60739)

   [Movie with children chased by adults dressed in black](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36901/movie-with-children-chased-by-adults-dressed-in-black/60572#60572)

   [What was the deal with 9:30 in M Night Shyamalan's 'The Visit'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44459/what-was-the-deal-with-930-in-m-night-shyamalans-the-visit/60453#60453)

   [Why did Vera beg for her life?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52513/why-did-vera-beg-for-her-life/61174#61174)

   [Motivation of the murderer in Season 3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52298/motivation-of-the-murderer-in-season-3/61170#61170)

   [NYC Police Codes in Blue Bloods 10-13?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49032/nyc-police-codes-in-blue-bloods-10-13/61169#61169)

   [Were the 30 Rock Live episodes shot at 30 Rock?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50823/were-the-30-rock-live-episodes-shot-at-30-rock/61166#61166)

   [Boats in Philadelphia Story](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17448/boats-in-philadelphia-story/60092#60092)

   [What is the significance of the ape movies in X-Files S10E02: Founder's Mutation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46821/what-is-the-significance-of-the-ape-movies-in-x-files-s10e02-founders-mutation/61280#61280)

   [Sherlock, The Abominable bride, opening scene explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53559/sherlock-the-abominable-bride-opening-scene-explanation/61081#61081)

   [How did David come back to life for choosing dreams?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55631/how-did-david-come-back-to-life-for-choosing-dreams/60895#60895)

   [Why did Chico go to Calvera's camp?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41583/why-did-chico-go-to-calveras-camp/61270#61270)
9. (0) [Female fight scene from a movie or TV show, 1979 or 1980](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53516/female-fight-scene-from-a-movie-or-tv-show-1979-or-1980/61155#61155)

   [Sherlock, The Abominable bride, opening scene explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53559/sherlock-the-abominable-bride-opening-scene-explanation/61060#61060)

   [What was Kyle really after in Money Monster?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/what-was-kyle-really-after-in-money-monster/60411#60411)

   [What was Kyle really after in Money Monster?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53352/what-was-kyle-really-after-in-money-monster/60412#60412)

   [Does what happened to Jon Snow make him immune to White Walkers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55686/does-what-happened-to-jon-snow-make-him-immune-to-white-walkers/61015#61015)

   [Was Dulé Hill appearing so briefly in *The West Wing* because he was co-starring in *Psych*?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46639/was-dul%c3%a9-hill-appearing-so-briefly-in-the-west-wing-because-he-was-co-starring/60107#60107)
10. (-1) https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/25093/man-at-a-farm-saves-two-women-from-a-rapist-and-then-robs-a-bank-with-them-sata/60332#60332

Answer (score 3):

The **August 2017** challenge has garnered 18 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6 and acceptance) coming from [*Walt*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Help me Identify a recent movie about isolation in the future](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72407/help-me-identify-a-recent-movie-about-isolation-in-the-future/79514#79514)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (2+V) [Does Fredrick Zoller feel remorse for the actions he's famous for?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55573/does-fredrick-zoller-feel-remorse-for-the-actions-hes-famous-for/79735#79735)
3. (2) [Why were there so many repeat performances in Columbo?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41909/why-were-there-so-many-repeat-performances-in-columbo/78377#78377)
4. (1+V) [Looking for a cartoon TV series with kids riding motorbikes in a desert-like area](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67815/looking-for-a-cartoon-tv-series-with-kids-riding-motorbikes-in-a-desert-like-are/78604#78604)
5. (1) [Why doesn't John use a silencer?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18710/why-doesnt-john-use-a-silencer/79168#79168)

   [Is Long Beach Poly in same league as De La Salle?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52145/is-long-beach-poly-in-same-league-as-de-la-salle/78706#78706)

   [What (relatively-recent) anime movie involved a child waking up in a village without memories](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71705/what-relatively-recent-anime-movie-involved-a-child-waking-up-in-a-village-wit/78907#78907)

   [Identify movie about failed author who falls in with child gang, finds his mojo](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72125/identify-movie-about-failed-author-who-falls-in-with-child-gang-finds-his-mojo/78821#78821)

   [Has the denouement of Limitless been retconned?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52073/has-the-denouement-of-limitless-been-retconned/78620#78620)

   [What happened to the humans?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66630/what-happened-to-the-humans/79028#79028)
6. (0) [Why didn't Author, Author reference A Measure of a Man?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67955/why-didnt-author-author-reference-a-measure-of-a-man/79627#79627)

   [Did Hannah Wells' have a 'story'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65530/did-hannah-wells-have-a-story/79445#79445)

   [Why doesn't John use a silencer?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18710/why-doesnt-john-use-a-silencer/79144#79144)

   [unknown B-movie with treasure seekers, a curse and nerdy guy wielding umbrella](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69083/unknown-b-movie-with-treasure-seekers-a-curse-and-nerdy-guy-wielding-umbrella/79802#79802)

   [Comparative Profitability of Genres in Movie History](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35208/comparative-profitability-of-genres-in-movie-history/78720#78720)

   [Movie based on a father's eulogy for his daughter based in early twentieth century](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65621/movie-based-on-a-fathers-eulogy-for-his-daughter-based-in-early-twentieth-centu/78930#78930)

   [Science fiction movie about parallel universe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71646/science-fiction-movie-about-parallel-universe/78971#78971)
7. (-2) [2000s TV childrens animated show - young girls with name like gemstones](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68428/2000s-tv-childrens-animated-show-young-girls-with-name-like-gemstones/78809#78809)

Answer (score 3):

The **September 2017** challenge has garnered 19 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4 and acceptance) coming from [*Coomie*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/855), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why is Toby Flenderson the way he is?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69359/why-is-toby-flenderson-the-way-he-is/80604#80604)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [Did the Soggy Bottom Boys ever get a record contract?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65444/did-the-soggy-bottom-boys-ever-get-a-record-contract/80698#80698)
3. (2+V) [Why is Jenna left on the other side?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72832/why-is-jenna-left-on-the-other-side/80835#80835)

   [Why does Darry think that Jez is the one who called him at the diner?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73835/why-does-darry-think-that-jez-is-the-one-who-called-him-at-the-diner/80357#80357)
4. (2) [St. Sebastian imagery in Silence of the Lambs](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73861/st-sebastian-imagery-in-silence-of-the-lambs/80147#80147)
5. (1+V) [When did the Tigress action figure change hands?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50568/when-did-the-tigress-action-figure-change-hands/80353#80353)

   [How was Supergirl able to beat up the guards?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73296/how-was-supergirl-able-to-beat-up-the-guards/80073#80073)
6. (1) [Why is Toby Flenderson the way he is?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69359/why-is-toby-flenderson-the-way-he-is/80581#80581)

   [Is Honey, I Shrunk the Kids scaled correctly?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70321/is-honey-i-shrunk-the-kids-scaled-correctly/80605#80605)

   [How accurate is this depiction of a big prison corporation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55683/how-accurate-is-this-depiction-of-a-big-prison-corporation/80659#80659)

   [Why don't the cops pursue Costello's crew after the shootout?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72227/why-dont-the-cops-pursue-costellos-crew-after-the-shootout/80900#80900)

   [What's the name of a horror movie about dark fairy tales?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70649/whats-the-name-of-a-horror-movie-about-dark-fairy-tales/80081#80081)
7. (0) [What was the recording order for How I Met Your Mother?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35880/what-was-the-recording-order-for-how-i-met-your-mother/80148#80148)

   [What is the term for the colour scheme/effect in e.g. Supernatural](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36258/what-is-the-term-for-the-colour-scheme-effect-in-e-g-supernatural/80051#80051)

   [Who exactly committed suicide in the movie 'The Bounty Hunter'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70236/who-exactly-committed-suicide-in-the-movie-the-bounty-hunter/80354#80354)

   [Identify a short psychological thriller film for me](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72351/identify-a-short-psychological-thriller-film-for-me/80809#80809)

   [Why is Marcus Corvinus's hybrid nature different from Michael Corvin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66577/why-is-marcus-corvinuss-hybrid-nature-different-from-michael-corvin/80176#80176)

   [Why did Jennifer lose all her powers just from losing the BFF chain?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67479/why-did-jennifer-lose-all-her-powers-just-from-losing-the-bff-chain/80635#80635)
8. (-1) [Little girl returns as a ghost to seek justice on her killer, repeats "Why", floats up with balloons](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71519/little-girl-returns-as-a-ghost-to-seek-justice-on-her-killer-repeats-why-flo/80325#80325)

Answer (score 3):

The **December 2017** challenge has garnered 13 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 8) coming from [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge and earns her a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Straight Outta Compton - claims of police abuse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57467/straight-outta-compton-claims-of-police-abuse/83799#83799)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5) [Psychological thriller involving woman in disguise](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72372/psychological-thriller-involving-woman-in-disguise/83603#83603)
3. (2+V) [How can I link The Ring Two (2005) and Rings (2017)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79035/how-can-i-link-the-ring-two-2005-and-rings-2017/83540#83540)
4. (2) [Did Jack Starks regain his memory after being shot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70435/did-jack-starks-regain-his-memory-after-being-shot/83526#83526)

   [Why does Travis Bickle have flowers in his apartment?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68545/why-does-travis-bickle-have-flowers-in-his-apartment/83288#83288)
5. (1) [Was Inspector Villiers part of the cover-up conspiracy at East Proctor?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43809/was-inspector-villiers-part-of-the-cover-up-conspiracy-at-east-proctor/83933#83933)
6. (0) [What did Lefors represent?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79026/what-did-lefors-represent/84258#84258)

   [Handwriting of Aaron and Abe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72781/handwriting-of-aaron-and-abe/84063#84063)

   [What happens to Tom in Enter Nowhere?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71395/what-happens-to-tom-in-enter-nowhere/84129#84129)

   [What does Viktor Navorski say to Milodragovich in Bulgarian?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31778/what-does-viktor-navorski-say-to-milodragovich-in-bulgarian/83671#83671)

   [Wall Street 2: Nationalisation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33940/wall-street-2-nationalisation/83696#83696)

   [Control the past, control the future in a different time-stream?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52251/control-the-past-control-the-future-in-a-different-time-stream/83420#83420)

   [Help remembering name of a 70's slasher movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61335/help-remembering-name-of-a-70s-slasher-movie/83636#83636)

Answer (score 2):

The **December 2015** challenge has garnered 16 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4) coming from [*Kovács Levente*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/28413), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [The Usual Suspects what's the joke?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44337/49)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [How exactly did Summers, Shelby, Abernathy organize their slavery empire?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44259/49)
3. (3) [Is there a real life inspiration behind Dexter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44845/49)

   [What does the painting in the hospital hall in Kill Bill mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44526/49)
4. (2+V) [Where did Loco get the rifle from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44786/49)
5. (2) [What are we to make of the ending of The Great Silence?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44788/49)

   [Why not just make him forget again?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44739/49)
6. (1) [Why the delay in Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45297/49)

   [Who is Bruce and does he have a real-world counterpart?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44583/49)

   [Explanation for A Tale of Two Sisters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44275/49)

   [What did Daniel Plainview whisper?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44527/49)
7. (0) [What did Daniel Plainview whisper?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44418/49)

   [How did they realize the truth about Josh?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44220/49)

   [Why doesn't Alan Shore contest for partnership?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44799/49)

   [What is the meaning of the symbols on the Arrowhead in the season 3 intro?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44816/49)
8. (-1) [Why exactly does the girl cry at the end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/44864/49)

Answer (score 2):

The **April 2016** challenge has garnered 18 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 5) coming from [*galacticninja*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1006), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Who is the second Hamlin in Hamlin, Hamlin and McGill?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33175/who-is-the-second-hamlin-in-hamlin-hamlin-and-mcgill/51312#51312)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (4+V) [What is the first instance of the "Saving humans from themselves" trope](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38678/what-is-the-first-instance-of-the-saving-humans-from-themselves-trope/51198#51198)
3. (3) [Why don't Michonne's walker drones try to attack her?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46064/why-dont-michonnes-walker-drones-try-to-attack-her/51367#51367)
4. (2+V) [Was this scene the first to show the wand massager in a mainstream movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32222/was-this-scene-the-first-to-show-the-wand-massager-in-a-mainstream-movie/51267#51267)

   [Japanese TV show that had a recurring plot device, the seal of the emperor](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46955/japanese-tv-show-that-had-a-recurring-plot-device-the-seal-of-the-emperor/51582#51582)
5. (1+V) [Was Ms. Overkill planning to trap minions in the first place?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/was-ms-overkill-planning-to-trap-minions-in-the-first-place/51781#51781)

   [What is the poem uttered by the saint in Dasavatharam?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43760/what-is-the-poem-uttered-by-the-saint-in-dasavatharam/51448#51448)
6. (1) [What was the two guys' relationship in the suits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34864/what-was-the-two-guys-relationship-in-the-suits/52171#52171)

   [Have people forgotten about Hannibal Lecter between Hannibal Rising and Red Dragon?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/40880/have-people-forgotten-about-hannibal-lecter-between-hannibal-rising-and-red-drag/51184#51184)

   [Have they edited the turning water to wine scene in 'Now You See Me'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46689/have-they-edited-the-turning-water-to-wine-scene-in-now-you-see-me/51544#51544)

   [Why did Luke not let the man on the street enter into the car in 'Vanishing on 7th Street'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36499/why-did-luke-not-let-the-man-on-the-street-enter-into-the-car-in-vanishing-on-7/52206#52206)

   [Why does Cookie give the painting to "one two" in RocknRolla?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42922/why-does-cookie-give-the-painting-to-one-two-in-rocknrolla/51853#51853)

   [Do actors actually carry actresses?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37311/do-actors-actually-carry-actresses/51238#51238)
7. (0+V) [Need help with film about people fighting/racing for survival](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41992/need-help-with-film-about-people-fighting-racing-for-survival/51666#51666)
8. (0) [Do any other episodes of The Big Bang Theory mention The Princess Bride when Kripke is present?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42541/do-any-other-episodes-of-the-big-bang-theory-mention-the-princess-bride-when-kri/52115#52115)

   [Embarrassed student goes on a killing spree and makes a kill list with hero's name on it](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37213/embarrassed-student-goes-on-a-killing-spree-and-makes-a-kill-list-with-heros-na/51250#51250)
9. (-1) [What did Ripley tell Schenk in S01E06?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43757/what-did-ripley-tell-schenk-in-s01e06/51701#51701)

   https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44665/movie-drama-about-racism-in-an-all-white-neighborhood/51457#51457

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/P96Av.gif

Answer (score 2):

The **May 2016** challenge has garnered 19 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4 and acceptance) coming from [*followthemeow*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34591), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [A mother takes her children to a buffalo farm](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46242/a-mother-takes-her-children-to-a-buffalo-farm/53055#53055)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3) [Erroneous scene with the studio's parking lot in the original Star Wars release](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44767/erroneous-scene-with-the-studios-parking-lot-in-the-original-star-wars-release/53202#53202)
3. (2+V) [Motivations for killing Rayna Boyanov in Spy (2015)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41871/motivations-for-killing-rayna-boyanov-in-spy-2015/52651#52651)
4. (2) [What is Sauron saying when Galadriel defeats him at Dol Guldur?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34416/what-is-sauron-saying-when-galadriel-defeats-him-at-dol-guldur/52941#52941)
5. (1) [Utopia realistic shootings](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24661/utopia-realistic-shootings/53204#53204)

   [Is Hannibal's last will to eat himself?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39516/is-hannibals-last-will-to-eat-himself/53558#53558)

   [Does Magnussen have any disorders?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41337/does-magnussen-have-any-disorders/53035#53035)

   [Is "The Conspiracy" based on a real secret society?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45785/is-the-conspiracy-based-on-a-real-secret-society/53171#53171)

   [Scary movie from the late 90s/early 2000s, 2 young girl ghosts, a tall man, and Thomas Edison ghost box](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43191/scary-movie-from-the-late-90s-early-2000s-2-young-girl-ghosts-a-tall-man-and/53175#53175)
6. (0) [Why was Ant-Man excluded from the Civil War trailer?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43992/why-was-ant-man-excluded-from-the-civil-war-trailer/52786#52786)

   [How were some gods brought back to life?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-were-some-gods-brought-back-to-life/53158#53158)

   [Why does Heroes show inconsistent versions of the same scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46423/why-does-heroes-show-inconsistent-versions-of-the-same-scene/53523#53523)

   [Why does Heroes show inconsistent versions of the same scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46423/why-does-heroes-show-inconsistent-versions-of-the-same-scene/53530#53530)

   [Tetsuo: The Iron Man, Analysis, Interpretations and randomness](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19101/tetsuo-the-iron-man-analysis-interpretations-and-randomness/52930#52930)

   [Does time travel in the 12 Monkeys TV show work differently than in the movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48848/does-time-travel-in-the-12-monkeys-tv-show-work-differently-than-in-the-movie/53003#53003)

   [Why did Corder leak information in "The Final Cut"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27267/why-did-corder-leak-information-in-the-final-cut/53079#53079)

   [Why is classic IMAX not digital?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36484/why-is-classic-imax-not-digital/53310#53310)
7. (-1) https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46488/70s-movie-about-a-boy-girl-who-discover-2-extraterrestrials-in-a-supposedly-a/52853#52853
8. (-3) [Was casting adults as teenagers more common in the past?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/was-casting-adults-as-teenagers-more-common-in-the-past/52801#52801)

Answer (score 2):

The **June 2016** challenge has garnered 13 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4 and acceptance) coming from [*Movers*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/37286), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Significance of the air dancers in Nightcrawler](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36893/significance-of-the-air-dancers-in-nightcrawler/56144#56144)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [Who was the caller in the episode "Last Call" (S03E15)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33851/who-was-the-caller-in-the-episode-last-call-s03e15/53808#53808)
3. (3) [How long did it take the infected to starve in 28 Days Later?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/37184/how-long-did-it-take-the-infected-to-starve-in-28-days-later/56149#56149)

   [What does Paul Avery tell the coffee guy after the coffee guy calls him a "drunken reprobate"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/what-does-paul-avery-tell-the-coffee-guy-after-the-coffee-guy-calls-him-a-drunk/56196#56196)
4. (2) [Is the trial at the end of S11E07 a reference to a previous episode?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49157/is-the-trial-at-the-end-of-s11e07-a-reference-to-a-previous-episode/55598#55598)

   [Did John Locke have a mental condition?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/did-john-locke-have-a-mental-condition/55424#55424)

   [Why do some characters call the Machine "she"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51102/why-do-some-characters-call-the-machine-she/55267#55267)
5. (1+V) [Original Cooties ending](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41350/original-cooties-ending/53941#53941)
6. (1) [90s/2000s movie about a woman who was sent to an asylum, escapes, and throws herself off a bridge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49050/90s-2000s-movie-about-a-woman-who-was-sent-to-an-asylum-escapes-and-throws-her/53813#53813)

   [Looking for a 50~ year-old horror film about a cave filled with flying demons](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42694/looking-for-a-50-year-old-horror-film-about-a-cave-filled-with-flying-demons/56016#56016)
7. (0) [Legends of tomorrow quote, what is it from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50583/legends-of-tomorrow-quote-what-is-it-from/55595#55595)

   [What is Theo's father's reaction in the end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44383/what-is-theos-fathers-reaction-in-the-end/56138#56138)

   [Thriller/Horror movie about girl who moves in with couple](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51068/thriller-horror-movie-about-girl-who-moves-in-with-couple/56201#56201)

Answer (score 2):

The **August 2016** challenge has garnered 19 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 10 and acceptance) coming from [*dbugger*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/37467), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earned them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How does this studio(?) hierarchy work](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46166/how-does-this-studio-hierarchy-work/59059#59059)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (8) [Why does no one notice the Joker's presence as a policeman during the mayor's speech?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11072/why-does-no-one-notice-the-jokers-presence-as-a-policeman-during-the-mayors-sp/59154#59154)
3. (4+V) [Why does Dr. Cal Lightman walk with his back and neck bent front and spreading his shoulder on the sides?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52536/why-does-dr-cal-lightman-walk-with-his-back-and-neck-bent-front-and-spreading-h/59849#59849)
4. (4) [Homeland - possible "Better Call Saul" series reference](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46045/homeland-possible-better-call-saul-series-reference/59046#59046)

   [What is the significance to the manner of suicides in Virgin Suicides](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53144/what-is-the-significance-to-the-manner-of-suicides-in-virgin-suicides/59307#59307)
5. (2) [Is this a genre, a plot template or something else?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47664/is-this-a-genre-a-plot-template-or-something-else/59491#59491)

   [In this movie, man accidentally watches woman have breakdown in her home](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45093/in-this-movie-man-accidentally-watches-woman-have-breakdown-in-her-home/59299#59299)

   [What was with Ron Perlman's character's nose obsession in Cronos?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46563/what-was-with-ron-perlmans-characters-nose-obsession-in-cronos/59494#59494)
6. (1+V) [Is this race now completely wiped out?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/is-this-race-now-completely-wiped-out/59454#59454)

   [Is True Detective (S2) based on "The Big Nowhere"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49205/is-true-detective-s2-based-on-the-big-nowhere/59547#59547)
7. (1) [Why do we only see female Children of the Forest and male White Walkers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53713/why-do-we-only-see-female-children-of-the-forest-and-male-white-walkers/59599#59599)

   [Did Tony deceive Aldrich Killian into thinking that Mark 42 malfunctioned?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45507/did-tony-deceive-aldrich-killian-into-thinking-that-mark-42-malfunctioned/59404#59404)

   [Why are screeners released in DVD format instead of Blu-ray?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51481/why-are-screeners-released-in-dvd-format-instead-of-blu-ray/59376#59376)

   [Who did we hear in Bran's vision in S06E06?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53695/who-did-we-hear-in-brans-vision-in-s06e06/57695#57695)
8. (0) [Is It possible for the dread doctors to create alpha wolves?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46362/is-it-possible-for-the-dread-doctors-to-create-alpha-wolves/57651#57651)

   [Why didn't Julian tell Danny the truth about his last job?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33471/why-didnt-julian-tell-danny-the-truth-about-his-last-job/58786#58786)

   [How much time has passed since the beginning of the "Hot Lava" game?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51139/how-much-time-has-passed-since-the-beginning-of-the-hot-lava-game/59273#59273)

   [Movie about a transfer student that befriends a working student who is good at piano and a star athlete?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53462/movie-about-a-transfer-student-that-befriends-a-working-student-who-is-good-at-p/58739#58739)

   [How did Sia learn to fight in the movie Baaghi?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52812/how-did-sia-learn-to-fight-in-the-movie-baghi/59146#59146)

Answer (score 2):

The **October 2016** challenge has garnered 22 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 7) coming from [*Charles E. Grant*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34244), which makes him the winner of this challenge and already earned him a bounty of 250 additional reputation:

## 1. [How detrimental was the initial hull breach by the shipping container for the boat's ultimate fate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41965/how-detrimental-was-the-initial-hull-breach-by-the-shipping-container-for-the-bo/62038#62038)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5) [Why was the Elder Wand destroyed rather than returned to Dumbledore's tomb?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50797/why-was-the-elder-wand-destroyed-rather-than-returned-to-dumbledores-tomb/61517#61517)
3. (4) [Why was the Elder Wand destroyed rather than returned to Dumbledore's tomb?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50797/why-was-the-elder-wand-destroyed-rather-than-returned-to-dumbledores-tomb/61521#61521)

   [Is the Babadook symbolic of the dead father?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46788/is-the-babadook-symbolic-of-the-dead-father/61635#61635)
4. (3+V) [Rookie Cut - Which movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39213/rookie-cut-which-movie/62544#62544)
5. (3) [Is there a specific flag that should be raised when filming a boat scene with a pirate flag flying?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51114/is-there-a-specific-flag-that-should-be-raised-when-filming-a-boat-scene-with-a/62542#62542)
6. (2+V) [Why is the blackmail scene in Fight Club different from the book?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55585/why-is-the-blackmail-scene-in-fight-club-different-from-the-book/61716#61716)
7. (1) [Similarities between "The Equalizer" and "Hitman: Absolution"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38658/similarities-between-the-equalizer-and-hitman-absolution/61457#61457)

   [Is there any significance to the Angels' wing colours?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55454/is-there-any-significance-to-the-angels-wing-colours/62479#62479)

   [What happened to Sheldon's assistant, Alex?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45944/what-happened-to-sheldons-assistant-alex/61533#61533)

   [Is there any hidden significance to the song at the end o S06E09?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52124/is-there-any-hidden-significance-to-the-song-at-the-end-o-s06e09/62394#62394)

   [What is the chronology of Largo Winch (2008)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56462/what-is-the-chronology-of-largo-winch-2008/62600#62600)
8. (0) [Looking for medieval Star Wars type movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41055/looking-for-medieval-star-wars-type-movie/62100#62100)

   [What happened to Sheldon's assistant, Alex?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45944/what-happened-to-sheldons-assistant-alex/61535#61535)

   [How big is the Tanners' house?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57073/how-big-is-the-tanners-house/62210#62210)

   [How big is the Tanners' house?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57073/how-big-is-the-tanners-house/62177#62177)

   [What was the significance of the ending in Kaafiron Ki Namaaz?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56361/what-was-the-significance-of-the-ending-in-kaafiron-ki-namaaz/62366#62366)

   [Does Lucy create the human race while touching the ape Lucy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55183/does-lucy-create-the-human-race-while-touching-the-ape-lucy/62422#62422)

   [Why didn't Hundred Eyes assassinate Jia Sidao in their first encounter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/why-didnt-hundred-eyes-assassinate-jia-sidao-in-their-first-encounter/62312#62312)
9. (-1) [Thriller movie with woman afraid to leave her apartment](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32342/thriller-movie-with-woman-afraid-to-leave-her-apartment/62218#62218)

   [Why was Medivh hostile towards Khadgar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56084/why-was-medivh-hostile-towards-khadgar/61417#61417)

   [1990s sci-fi/horror film or episode where device lets women look into an underwater parallel dimension](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44234/1990s-sci-fi-horror-film-or-episode-where-device-lets-women-look-into-an-underwa/62214#62214)

Answer (score 2):

The **December 2016** challenge has garnered 34 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 9 and acceptance) coming from [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge and earns her a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Where did the line about the reason for the big eyes come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60021/where-did-the-line-about-the-reason-for-the-big-eyes-come-from/65819#65819)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (8) [Inverted rainbow in The Little Mermaid](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60501/inverted-rainbow-in-the-little-mermaid/65505#65505)
3. (6) [Most recent Hollywood feature film without closing credits](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61351/most-recent-hollywood-feature-film-without-closing-credits/65276#65276)
4. (5) [What was the purpose of Christopher Lee's scene with the eagle wings behind him?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60011/what-was-the-purpose-of-christopher-lees-scene-with-the-eagle-wings-behind-him/65903#65903)
5. (4+V) [How could you explain that Hank Schrader did know about altercation between Mike Ehrmantraut and Tuco?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52696/how-could-you-explain-that-hank-schrader-did-know-about-altercation-between-mike/64198#64198)
6. (4) [Why was the sound of an off-screen gunshot removed from a critical scene in a Magnum P.I. episode?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39176/why-was-the-sound-of-an-off-screen-gunshot-removed-from-a-critical-scene-in-a-ma/64275#64275)

   [Why weren't the Birches also being charged?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61216/why-werent-the-birches-also-being-charged/65544#65544)
7. (3) [How is Father James related to Jesus Christ in the movie "Calvary" (2014)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56313/how-is-father-james-related-to-jesus-christ-in-the-movie-calvary-2014/64427#64427)

   [What is the significance of the cat in the movie "Gone Girl"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43154/what-is-the-significance-of-the-cat-in-the-movie-gone-girl/64433#64433)

   [Why does the doctor help Ray Breslin at last?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32745/why-does-the-doctor-help-ray-breslin-at-last/65050#65050)

   [How did Joy escape?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52614/how-did-joy-escape/65545#65545)

   [Was the climax scene of Argo inspired by The Last King of Scotland?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55648/was-the-climax-scene-of-argo-inspired-by-the-last-king-of-scotland/65670#65670)
8. (2+V) [Pumpkin and Honey Bunny from Pulp Fiction - did they appear in another movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46030/pumpkin-and-honey-bunny-from-pulp-fiction-did-they-appear-in-another-movie/64197#64197)

   [Languages used in 'Embrace of the Serpent'](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50336/languages-used-in-embrace-of-the-serpent/65007#65007)

   [Where was Rhonda's/AF709's off switch?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52094/where-was-rhondas-af709s-off-switch/65920#65920)
9. (2) [Rear projection effect in The Hateful Eight](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53710/rear-projection-effect-in-the-hateful-eight/64675#64675)

   [Hand drawings in "A Walk Among the Tombstones"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51691/hand-drawings-in-a-walk-among-the-tombstones/64491#64491)

   [The Italian from Leverage](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41182/the-italian-from-leverage/65896#65896)

   [Is this character development with Lui Kang accurate to the source material?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10189/is-this-character-development-with-lui-kang-accurate-to-the-source-material/65671#65671)
10. (1+V) [What is the chronological order to watch Mortal Kombat: Legacy season 1?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/what-is-the-chronological-order-to-watch-mortal-kombat-legacy-season-1/65689#65689)

    [SCTV: is "Monster Chiller Horror Theatre" based on "Monsters we Know and Love?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24459/sctv-is-monster-chiller-horror-theatre-based-on-monsters-we-know-and-love/64522#64522)
11. (1) [ITV children's television series about a wise owl and imaginary animal friends?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50516/itv-childrens-television-series-about-a-wise-owl-and-imaginary-animal-friends/64547#64547)
12. (0) [Was there supposed to be any implication Maynard G. Krebs used drugs?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30566/was-there-supposed-to-be-any-implication-maynard-g-krebs-used-drugs/64189#64189)

    [Did Archer cause the elevator to break?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30815/did-archer-cause-the-elevator-to-break/64187#64187)

    [What was the movie Tom referred to when arguing with Chris?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44013/what-was-the-movie-tom-referred-to-when-arguing-with-chris/64957#64957)

    [Why is she a half-alien?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42400/why-is-she-a-half-alien/64214#64214)

    [Is the Reimagined Battlestar a reboot or a sequel to the Original Battlestar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53274/is-the-reimagined-battlestar-a-reboot-or-a-sequel-to-the-original-battlestar/64212#64212)

    [Why do Bell and Genesis say Ronnie is a magician in "Knock Knock"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46669/why-do-bell-and-genesis-say-ronnie-is-a-magician-in-knock-knock/64587#64587)

    [(Fantasy/Kids/Horror?) movie/TV show involving kids going to a faerie realm](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46834/fantasy-kids-horror-movie-tv-show-involving-kids-going-to-a-faerie-realm/64408#64408)

    [Was the Devil's Advocate showing multiple attempts to corrupt Kevin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56135/was-the-devils-advocate-showing-multiple-attempts-to-corrupt-kevin/64272#64272)

    [What happened to Victor's car?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56977/what-happened-to-victors-car/64270#64270)

    [Identify a movie about slavery and time travel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59765/identify-a-movie-about-slavery-and-time-travel/65365#65365)
13. (-1+V) [(Fantasy/Kids/Horror?) movie/TV show involving kids going to a faerie realm](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46834/fantasy-kids-horror-movie-tv-show-involving-kids-going-to-a-faerie-realm/64407#64407)
14. (-1) [Was the sunken ship in Finding Dory based on a real sunken ship?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55783/was-the-sunken-ship-in-finding-dory-based-on-a-real-sunken-ship/64971#64971)

Answer (score 2):

The **February 2017** challenge has garnered 28 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 9) coming from [*người Sàigòn*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/46540), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [What is the second prostitute saying in Vietnamese in Full Metal Jacket?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56779/what-is-the-second-prostitute-saying-in-vietnamese-in-full-metal-jacket/68139#68139)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (6+V) [Why was the Chinese drone replaced with an Indian drone by the filmmakers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63859/why-was-the-chinese-drone-replaced-with-an-indian-drone-by-the-filmmakers/68448#68448)

   [What computers and keyboards are in the eleventh Doctor's console?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/21427/what-computers-and-keyboards-are-in-the-eleventh-doctors-console/69249#69249)
3. (5+V) [What happened to Buddy (Jack Black's character) in Community?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/what-happened-to-buddy-jack-blacks-character-in-community/68067#68067)

   [Was the world ever more radioactive?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56875/was-the-world-ever-more-radioactive/67986#67986)
4. (5) [What was used to create the metal effect makeup in the Terminator robots?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57513/what-was-used-to-create-the-metal-effect-makeup-in-the-terminator-robots/68286#68286)

   [Movie that involves half a dozen people from the deep web gathered in a warehouse to see a live killing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59351/movie-that-involves-half-a-dozen-people-from-the-deep-web-gathered-in-a-warehous/68489#68489)
5. (4+V) [References to Voyager 1 / Cassini photographs?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28722/references-to-voyager-1-cassini-photographs/68418#68418)
6. (3+V) [Why is everyone's limbo space the same in Inception?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55227/why-is-everyones-limbo-space-the-same-in-inception/68504#68504)

   [What is the significance of the missing mouth in the Silent Hill and Silent Hill: Revelation film posters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62656/what-is-the-significance-of-the-missing-mouth-in-the-silent-hill-and-silent-hill/68969#68969)
7. (3) [How did they film the motorcycle jump in Point Break (2015)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52040/how-did-they-film-the-motorcycle-jump-in-point-break-2015/69063#69063)

   [Was the plan ever for Chewbacca to speak English (or Galactic Basic)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55096/was-the-plan-ever-for-chewbacca-to-speak-english-or-galactic-basic/68371#68371)

   [How much time passed from the end of season 5 to the Battle of the Bastards?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55887/how-much-time-passed-from-the-end-of-season-5-to-the-battle-of-the-bastards/67974#67974)

   [Who shot Bill Cutting 'The Butcher' in the theater?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42209/who-shot-bill-cutting-the-butcher-in-the-theater/69256#69256)

   [Nerve: Why not reject?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59223/nerve-why-not-reject/69021#69021)
8. (2) [Why do kids shows have so many musical numbers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46143/why-do-kids-shows-have-so-many-musical-numbers/69154#69154)

   [Identify film about plane crash in Europe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62531/identify-film-about-plane-crash-in-europe/68497#68497)
9. (1+V) [Why not protect against Kilgrave's powers in other ways?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62669/why-not-protect-against-kilgraves-powers-in-other-ways/68311#68311)
10. (1) [Why was Lagertha made mother of Bjorn?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43544/why-was-lagertha-made-mother-of-bjorn/67905#67905)

    [Why did Daryl Van Horne target Felicia?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63906/why-did-daryl-van-horne-target-felicia/68698#68698)

    [Cover Girl and a Hollywood-Bollywood Connection](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60953/cover-girl-and-a-hollywood-bollywood-connection/67946#67946)

    [Who was Jack talking to?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45340/who-was-jack-talking-to/68826#68826)
11. (0) [Why was Alex Jones driving the campervan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59243/why-was-alex-jones-driving-the-campervan/68754#68754)

    [Why is the child disclaimer incomplete?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43820/why-is-the-child-disclaimer-incomplete/68465#68465)

    [Why do kids shows have so many musical numbers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46143/why-do-kids-shows-have-so-many-musical-numbers/69146#69146)

    [Why did Harry not use Polyjuice Potion at the wedding of Bill and Fleur?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55124/why-did-harry-not-use-polyjuice-potion-at-the-wedding-of-bill-and-fleur/67931#67931)
12. (-1) [Did Daryl Van Horne participate in group sex with the three women?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63905/did-daryl-van-horne-participate-in-group-sex-with-the-three-women/68697#68697)
13. (-2) [What was with the giant location titles?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53614/what-was-with-the-giant-location-titles/69111#69111)

Answer (score 2):

The **May 2017** challenge has garnered 24 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4 and acceptance) coming from [*My10cents*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/51857), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why does Travis Bickle attempt the assassination?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68569/why-does-travis-bickle-attempt-the-assassination/73943#73943)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (4) [What is the meaning of the final scene of the first season of "House of Cards"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62792/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-final-scene-of-the-first-season-of-house-of-cards/73884#73884)

   [Would Devasena belong to the Kunthala Kingdom in Baahubali The Beginning?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49275/would-devasena-belong-to-the-kunthala-kingdom-in-baahubali-the-beginning/72864#72864)
3. (3+V) [How are the sound effects of the Shaw brothers martial art movies produced?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55986/how-are-the-sound-effects-of-the-shaw-brothers-martial-art-movies-produced/73854#73854)

   [A 50s/60s Horror B-Movie with a wobbly-spiked monster](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/a-50s-60s-horror-b-movie-with-a-wobbly-spiked-monster/73374#73374)
4. (3) [Did Marcel survive the fire?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55575/did-marcel-survive-the-fire/73895#73895)

   [How is dubbing done for fight sequences?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46247/how-is-dubbing-done-for-fight-sequences/73841#73841)

   [Who is "we" in Franks' monologue?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51769/who-is-we-in-franks-monologue/73886#73886)
5. (2+V) [Why does Master Ip want to sew a button onto a paper?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55420/why-does-master-ip-want-to-sew-a-button-onto-a-paper/73840#73840)
6. (2) [On what basis was Milkin's transfer possible?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52191/on-what-basis-was-milkins-transfer-possible/73885#73885)

   [A 50s/60s Horror B-Movie with a wobbly-spiked monster](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/a-50s-60s-horror-b-movie-with-a-wobbly-spiked-monster/73324#73324)

   [External justification in The Man from U.N.C.L.E](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62726/external-justification-in-the-man-from-u-n-c-l-e/72684#72684)
7. (1) [How did Finch and Reese know that Hersh is going to poison Shaw](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64434/how-did-finch-and-reese-know-that-hersh-is-going-to-poison-shaw/73413#73413)

   [A 50s/60s Horror B-Movie with a wobbly-spiked monster](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52376/a-50s-60s-horror-b-movie-with-a-wobbly-spiked-monster/73322#73322)

   [Why Carrie didn't kill gym teacher in 2013 movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67599/why-carrie-didnt-kill-gym-teacher-in-2013-movie/72871#72871)

   [How exactly did Will and Barb get into the Upside-Down?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61209/how-exactly-did-will-and-barb-get-into-the-upside-down/72610#72610)

   [How did Michael "Mike" Ehrmantraut end up working with Gus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39496/how-did-michael-mike-ehrmantraut-end-up-working-with-gus/73214#73214)
8. (0) [Why didn't Vito kill those two guys?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67052/why-didnt-vito-kill-those-two-guys/73097#73097)

   [Use of capital letters in credits](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67438/use-of-capital-letters-in-credits/73435#73435)

   [Frank's Refusal Of Number One Observatory Circle](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62434/franks-refusal-of-number-one-observatory-circle/72861#72861)

   [Married man and salesman have very pleasant conversation after marital argument](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55774/married-man-and-salesman-have-very-pleasant-conversation-after-marital-argument/73190#73190)

   [How did Cisco mess up the timeline by saving the Dominator from Agent Smith back in 1951?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64341/how-did-cisco-mess-up-the-timeline-by-saving-the-dominator-from-agent-smith-back/72505#72505)
9. (-1) [Kaplan's Mission in "North By Northwest"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67450/kaplans-mission-in-north-by-northwest/73466#73466)
10. (-2) [A Chinese-language movie about an alien boy with the ability to grant wishes](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55909/a-chinese-language-movie-about-an-alien-boy-with-the-ability-to-grant-wishes/73692#73692)

Answer (score 2):

The **June 2017** challenge has garnered 29 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 8) coming from [*A J*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Which victims were the killers individually responsible for murdering?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62458/which-victims-were-the-killers-individually-responsible-for-murdering/74795#74795)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5+V) [Lyman Zerga's taste of steel touching his skin](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66384/lyman-zergas-taste-of-steel-touching-his-skin/74277#74277)
3. (3+V) [Why does Tyler Durden leave the Narrator taking his suitcase?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50171/why-does-tyler-durden-leave-the-narrator-taking-his-suitcase/75036#75036)
4. (3) [Was Arthur Seldom based on a particular real-life mathematician?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67735/was-arthur-seldom-based-on-a-particular-real-life-mathematician/74226#74226)

   [What's the deal with Hank Hill's wall clock on King of the Hill?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55628/whats-the-deal-with-hank-hills-wall-clock-on-king-of-the-hill/74089#74089)
5. (2+V) [Why does cat point to the answer/safety/salvation in the Silence of the Lambs?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/39224/why-does-cat-point-to-the-answer-safety-salvation-in-the-silence-of-the-lambs/74190#74190)
6. (2) [What's the symbolism behind "The Frog Prince" fairy tale?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69304/whats-the-symbolism-behind-the-frog-prince-fairy-tale/74094#74094)

   [Which is this movie about childhood friends who move apart, the girl becoming an actress?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45690/which-is-this-movie-about-childhood-friends-who-move-apart-the-girl-becoming-an/74744#74744)

   [Why is Two-Face mad at Jim Gordon?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67744/why-is-two-face-mad-at-jim-gordon/75587#75587)
7. (1+V) [Why does the rift-causing machine not get sucked up into the rift as it is closing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65455/why-does-the-rift-causing-machine-not-get-sucked-up-into-the-rift-as-it-is-closi/74065#74065)
8. (1) [Movie with augmented reality](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61505/movie-with-augmented-reality/74373#74373)

   [Why were there traps outside of Colonia?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68512/why-were-there-traps-outside-of-colonia/75285#75285)
9. (0) [Is there a name for this storytelling technique?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64363/is-there-a-name-for-this-storytelling-technique/75560#75560)

   [Why did Ken Blundell have a burnt nose in Muriel's Wedding?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68048/why-did-ken-blundell-have-a-burnt-nose-in-muriels-wedding/75468#75468)

   [Soviet cartoon about quarrel of two at a bus-stop](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67217/soviet-cartoon-about-quarrel-of-two-at-a-bus-stop/75593#75593)

   [Was "The Black Echo"'s diegetic existence merely a nod to the books or an element from the books?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35948/was-the-black-echos-diegetic-existence-merely-a-nod-to-the-books-or-an-elemen/75554#75554)

   [Are There any Details Regarding Polly's Death?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62790/are-there-any-details-regarding-pollys-death/74848#74848)

   [Why did Brian Halloran go to the FBI in Black Mass?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41420/why-did-brian-halloran-go-to-the-fbi-in-black-mass/75317#75317)

   [Why does Milton also kill good people?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55273/why-does-milton-also-kill-good-people/74706#74706)

   [Why was Walt so careless in this situation?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/58732/why-was-walt-so-careless-in-this-situation/74362#74362)

   [Please help identify late 80's/early 90's movie: "Catfish" scams women](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68828/please-help-identify-late-80s-early-90s-movie-catfish-scams-women/74911#74911)

   [Why is Two-Face mad at Jim Gordon?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67744/why-is-two-face-mad-at-jim-gordon/75582#75582)

   [Role of death in Supernatural](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56873/role-of-death-in-supernatural/75230#75230)

   [Why was Luke behaving this way towards his mother in The Next Three Days?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67679/why-was-luke-behaving-this-way-towards-his-mother-in-the-next-three-days/74955#74955)

   [Why do chipped people obey A.L.I.E?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53236/why-do-chipped-people-obey-a-l-i-e/75051#75051)
10. (-1) [Why change translation text into a picture for international versions?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64336/why-change-translation-text-into-a-picture-for-international-versions/74734#74734)

    [What is the bird and/or the birdcage supposed to represent while Hank and Leticia have sex?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67365/what-is-the-bird-and-or-the-birdcage-supposed-to-represent-while-hank-and-letici/74377#74377)

    [What was in the present from Robert to Sandy in A Patch Of Fog](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67727/what-was-in-the-present-from-robert-to-sandy-in-a-patch-of-fog/74736#74736)
11. (-2) [Thriller where husband hires hitman to kill wife at a weekend home by a lake](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65642/thriller-where-husband-hires-hitman-to-kill-wife-at-a-weekend-home-by-a-lake/75148#75148)

Answer (score 2):

The **July 2017** challenge has garnered 25 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6) coming from [*Walt*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [The Big Lebowski -- the dog character arc](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53622/the-big-lebowski-the-dog-character-arc/76335#76335)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (4+V) [Why was Medivh hostile towards Khadgar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56084/why-was-medivh-hostile-towards-khadgar/76543#76543)

   [90's or 00's show/movie - Teens with super suit](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66585/90s-or-00s-show-movie-teens-with-super-suit/76312#76312)
3. (4) [What was the fuss about the Alzheimer's Trial tampering and FDA thing in Grey's anatomy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61241/what-was-the-fuss-about-the-alzheimers-trial-tampering-and-fda-thing-in-greys/75883#75883)
4. (3+V) [What are the controversies around the movie Elle?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66796/what-are-the-controversies-around-the-movie-elle/75806#75806)

   [Why did Kundun show India to have achieved independence that early?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56469/why-did-kundun-show-india-to-have-achieved-independence-that-early/75998#75998)
5. (3) [Why do the BPO henchmen wear hazmat gear?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59711/why-do-the-bpo-henchmen-wear-hazmat-gear/75795#75795)

   [Movie with college/high school guys, strippers and the strip club owner](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60723/movie-with-college-high-school-guys-strippers-and-the-strip-club-owner/77800#77800)

   [Does Arnold Schwarzenegger intentionally strengthen his accent in older movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52674/does-arnold-schwarzenegger-intentionally-strengthen-his-accent-in-older-movies/77844#77844)

   [Why do they call him Jack?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70014/why-do-they-call-him-jack/75861#75861)
6. (2+V) [To what movies do the soundtracks in this Masha and the Bear episode belong?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61239/to-what-movies-do-the-soundtracks-in-this-masha-and-the-bear-episode-belong/76124#76124)
7. (2) [Why was Vincent in his underwear?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67656/why-was-vincent-in-his-underwear/76689#76689)

   [So how did Will end up in the same room with her?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56446/so-how-did-will-end-up-in-the-same-room-with-her/77881#77881)

   [Rights to George A. Romero's "Night of the Living Dead"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63206/rights-to-george-a-romeros-night-of-the-living-dead/76390#76390)

   [Character foreknowledge in the climax of Paul Verhoeven's Elle](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67104/character-foreknowledge-in-the-climax-of-paul-verhoevens-elle/75790#75790)

   [What is the significance of the mute girl in The Seventh Seal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53442/what-is-the-significance-of-the-mute-girl-in-the-seventh-seal/75893#75893)

   [Why did Aramaki only speak in Japanese?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71015/why-did-aramaki-only-speak-in-japanese/75797#75797)
8. (1+V) [Where was the Batman during the "terrorist" event?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/58906/where-was-the-batman-during-the-terrorist-event/75776#75776)
9. (1) [In "The 100", has the issue of the Alpha Station Ring at Arkadia/Camp Jaha tipping over ever been addressed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56038/in-the-100-has-the-issue-of-the-alpha-station-ring-at-arkadia-camp-jaha-tippi/76117#76117)

   [Does Arnold Schwarzenegger intentionally strengthen his accent in older movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52674/does-arnold-schwarzenegger-intentionally-strengthen-his-accent-in-older-movies/77880#77880)

   [How did Gabriel write "BOAT" in the notebook?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69022/how-did-gabriel-write-boat-in-the-notebook/75884#75884)

   [Who is driving Thomas Jane's hair and wardrobe on the Expanse?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69977/who-is-driving-thomas-janes-hair-and-wardrobe-on-the-expanse/75736#75736)

   [Was Roohdaar intended to be the replacement of Hamlet's father's ghost?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55913/was-roohdaar-intended-to-be-the-replacement-of-hamlets-fathers-ghost/77817#77817)
10. (0) [Why are the Infinity stones different in appearance?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32416/why-are-the-infinity-stones-different-in-appearance/75800#75800)
11. (-1) [Why does the pilot unbuckle his harness?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42935/why-does-the-pilot-unbuckle-his-harness/75917#75917)

Answer (score 2):

The **October 2017** challenge has garnered 19 answers, with the top voted answers (with a score of 5 and acceptance) coming from [*Rahul*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/41237), [*motosubatsu*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/47289) and [*Mara*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/57742), which makes them the winners of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Lost: System Failure](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71845/lost-system-failure/81884#81884)

## [How many times was the Voyager self-destruct sequence activated?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64067/how-many-times-was-the-voyager-self-destruct-sequence-activated/82011#82011)

## [Was the incredible K-2SO inspired by an earlier kill droid, HK-47?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65738/was-the-incredible-k-2so-inspired-by-an-earlier-kill-droid-hk-47/81268#81268)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [What made Clarice so important to Hannibal Lecter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52815/what-made-clarice-so-important-to-hannibal-lecter/81634#81634)
3. (3) [In A Clockwork Orange did Alex actually want to be reformed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73377/in-a-clockwork-orange-did-alex-actually-want-to-be-reformed/81314#81314)
4. (2) [What is the significance of shooting through the glass?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73860/what-is-the-significance-of-shooting-through-the-glass/81547#81547)
5. (1+V) [Was Claire and Lee checking out the house a flashback?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68598/was-claire-and-lee-checking-out-the-house-a-flashback/81600#81600)

   [Why is Ali's father crying at the mosque?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75283/why-is-alis-father-crying-at-the-mosque/82084#82084)

   [Why ghost of Eleanor Reigns tries to kill Max's father in Mirrors 2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50720/why-ghost-of-eleanor-reigns-tries-to-kill-maxs-father-in-mirrors-2/81106#81106)
6. (1) [5 minute cartoon before main show started - Channel 4 UK - Early 90's](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60580/5-minute-cartoon-before-main-show-started-channel-4-uk-early-90s/81663#81663)

   [Police Arrests in "North By Northwest"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67446/police-arrests-in-north-by-northwest/82199#82199)

   [How close is Masters of Sex to the actual events?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23559/how-close-is-masters-of-sex-to-the-actual-events/81992#81992)
7. (0) [Have either of the Jennings used the "rub your thumb" technique in previous episodes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/have-either-of-the-jennings-used-the-rub-your-thumb-technique-in-previous-epis/81215#81215)

   [What show/movie has a killer that cocoons its victims in webbing then turns out to be an alien. 80s/90s](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72267/what-show-movie-has-a-killer-that-cocoons-its-victims-in-webbing-then-turns-out/81090#81090)

   [Why did iZombie add gourmet cooking shots in the second season?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50802/why-did-izombie-add-gourmet-cooking-shots-in-the-second-season/82162#82162)

   [How did smoke monster appear as John Locke while his body was still in coffin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63848/how-did-smoke-monster-appear-as-john-locke-while-his-body-was-still-in-coffin/81903#81903)

   [Lost: System Failure](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71845/lost-system-failure/81897#81897)

   [Who is responsible for sabotaging the car?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50385/who-is-responsible-for-sabotaging-the-car/81706#81706)

   [80s/90s martial arts movie where a character trapped in a shield wall has his feet cut off](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/46860/80s-90s-martial-arts-movie-where-a-character-trapped-in-a-shield-wall-has-his-fe/81370#81370)

Answer (score 1):

The **November 2016** challenge has garnered 30 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6) coming from [*Ashan*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43309), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earn them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [What is the name of this anime movie set in the 1960 with an alternative history plot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/what-is-the-name-of-this-anime-movie-set-in-the-1960-with-an-alternative-history/63409#63409)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5+V) [How do they shoot helicopter/aeroplane blast/crash scenes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55996/how-do-they-shoot-helicopter-aeroplane-blast-crash-scenes/63875#63875)

   [Why couldn't "Doctor Strange" cast a Chinese actress for the Ancient One, but make the character non-Tibetan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52350/why-couldnt-doctor-strange-cast-a-chinese-actress-for-the-ancient-one-but-ma/63183#63183)
3. (5) [Was Quaid's dream planted?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50406/was-quaids-dream-planted/63161#63161)
4. (4) [Why and to which extent was The Night Manager recut for international release?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52317/why-and-to-which-extent-was-the-night-manager-recut-for-international-release/62983#62983)

   [What stops government from turning off the feeds?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56266/what-stops-government-from-turning-off-the-feeds/63768#63768)

   [Was the Starfleet officer connected to the later series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57212/was-the-starfleet-officer-connected-to-the-later-series/63273#63273)

   [Is "White Men Can't Jump" a dream?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52387/is-white-men-cant-jump-a-dream/64150#64150)

   [Is Homer Simpson kissing Marge while listening to a slow motion record a deleted scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57509/is-homer-simpson-kissing-marge-while-listening-to-a-slow-motion-record-a-deleted/64183#64183)
5. (3+V) [In 'The Hateful Eight', Why is Minnie's Haberdashery's called that?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59052/in-the-hateful-eight-why-is-minnies-haberdasherys-called-that/63923#63923)
6. (3) [Why does Payne take Annie hostage?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/58969/why-does-payne-take-annie-hostage/63167#63167)

   [Why couldn't "Doctor Strange" cast a Chinese actress for the Ancient One, but make the character non-Tibetan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52350/why-couldnt-doctor-strange-cast-a-chinese-actress-for-the-ancient-one-but-ma/63541#63541)

   [Why did the alien invaders let Russell Casse go?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55482/why-did-the-alien-invaders-let-russell-casse-go/63308#63308)

   [Was the twist in The Empire Strikes Back leaked to the public before the movie's release?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/44930/was-the-twist-in-the-empire-strikes-back-leaked-to-the-public-before-the-movies/63997#63997)
7. (2) [Why can we hear Lisa's bracelets?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51265/why-can-we-hear-lisas-bracelets/63531#63531)

   [What is the origin of 'Why'd you do it?' on Frasier?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43558/what-is-the-origin-of-whyd-you-do-it-on-frasier/62788#62788)

   [Why did CBI launch an investigation into Todd Johnson's death and not Rebecca Anderson's?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45873/why-did-cbi-launch-an-investigation-into-todd-johnsons-death-and-not-rebecca-an/63282#63282)

   [Was Gabriel Osbourne really a psychic?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31356/was-gabriel-osbourne-really-a-psychic/63285#63285)

   [Do different types of Poké Balls exist in the anime?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/58993/do-different-types-of-pok%c3%a9-balls-exist-in-the-anime/63601#63601)
8. (1) [What did they need Hyde for?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/28389/what-did-they-need-hyde-for/63087#63087)

   [Movie with murderer in apartment building playing loud music?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43254/movie-with-murderer-in-apartment-building-playing-loud-music/62864#62864)

   [Whose idea was it to put an orange lightbulb in the mysterious briefcase?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47365/whose-idea-was-it-to-put-an-orange-lightbulb-in-the-mysterious-briefcase/63833#63833)

   [Did Andy wear mask and goggles in the original version?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59801/did-andy-wear-mask-and-goggles-in-the-original-version/64078#64078)
9. (0) [How do the guilty remnant get money?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53024/how-the-guilty-remnant-get-money/63703#63703)

   [What is the meaning of this conversation before making love?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59584/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-conversation-before-making-love/63191#63191)

   [Why doesn't Redridge kill Eli at the end of the first shootout?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50755/why-doesnt-redridge-kill-eli-at-the-end-of-the-first-shootout/63583#63583)

   [An episode from an old horror series with human sacrifice](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59811/an-episode-from-an-old-horror-series-with-human-sacrifice/62800#62800)

   [When do they prepare screenplay for sequels, after casting or before casting?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59122/when-do-they-prepare-screenplay-for-sequels-after-casting-or-before-casting/63424#63424)

   [Is Homer Simpson kissing Marge while listening to a slow motion record a deleted scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57509/is-homer-simpson-kissing-marge-while-listening-to-a-slow-motion-record-a-deleted/64144#64144)
10. (-1) [Why are Theo and Tabitha Galavan of different skin color?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56838/why-are-theo-and-tabitha-galavan-of-different-skin-color/63693#63693)

Answer (score 1):

The **April 2017** challenge has garnered 29 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 5 and acceptance) coming from [*Shiz Z.*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/763), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Unusual Death in Django Unchained (Female death censoring?)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59681/unusual-death-in-django-unchained-female-death-censoring/72432#72432)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (4) [How does Gogo's meteor hammer work?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67404/how-does-gogos-meteor-hammer-work/71312#71312)
3. (3+V) [Early 1980s made-for-TV-movie where the equation √e^5u^5 is significant](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63945/early-1980s-made-for-tv-movie-where-the-equation-%e2%88%9ae5u5-is-significant/71848#71848)
4. (3) [Willamson left the office before Roma got the Lingk contract](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53265/willamson-left-the-office-before-roma-got-the-lingk-contract/71695#71695)
5. (2) [Willamson left the office before Roma got the Lingk contract](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53265/willamson-left-the-office-before-roma-got-the-lingk-contract/71154#71154)

   [Is Cameron becoming human?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56988/is-cameron-becoming-human/72281#72281)

   [How long will the strike last?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45018/how-long-will-the-strike-last/72321#72321)
6. (1+V) [60s/70s Cartoon villain with large *white* moustache](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63286/60s-70s-cartoon-villain-with-large-white-moustache/72129#72129)

   [Was Inspector Highland the inside man?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41772/was-inspector-highland-the-inside-man/72366#72366)

   [When did Clay become a phoner?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66075/when-did-clay-become-a-phoner/71631#71631)
7. (1) [How did the incident near the end of Our Kind of Traitor happen?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60316/how-did-the-incident-near-the-end-of-our-kind-of-traitor-happen/71980#71980)

   [How does Gogo's meteor hammer work?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67404/how-does-gogos-meteor-hammer-work/71329#71329)

   [Was there a non-parasite killed in Total Rickall?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56512/was-there-a-non-parasite-killed-in-total-rickall/71257#71257)

   [Is "Ripley's Believe It or Not" mostly false?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67458/is-ripleys-believe-it-or-not-mostly-false/72274#72274)

   [Is Cameron becoming human?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56988/is-cameron-becoming-human/72277#72277)

   [Why is Donald Blythe depicted as a weak Acting President?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66334/why-is-donald-blythe-depicted-as-a-weak-acting-president/72314#72314)

   [How many people has Jim killed in Under the Dome?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42230/how-many-people-has-jim-killed-in-under-the-dome/71608#71608)

   [Why doesn't Wayward Pines wait a more couple of thousands of years?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36778/why-doesnt-wayward-pines-wait-a-more-couple-of-thousands-of-years/71684#71684)

   [How long will the strike last?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45018/how-long-will-the-strike-last/72315#72315)
8. (0) [Why did the Chipmunks' sweaters become shorter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61399/why-did-the-chipmunks-sweaters-become-shorter/72268#72268)

   [What explains the ending of Triple 9?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66795/what-explains-the-ending-of-triple-9/71324#71324)

   [What happened to the the USS Franklin crew?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57252/what-happened-to-the-the-uss-franklin-crew/71340#71340)
9. (-1) [An adventure movie similar to Romancing the Stone (1984)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61030/an-adventure-movie-similar-to-romancing-the-stone-1984/71770#71770)

   [How did Fred Madison change into Pete Dayton in prison?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56621/how-did-fred-madison-change-into-pete-dayton-in-prison/72082#72082)

   [What was the first trailer to use "in a world"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60914/what-was-the-first-trailer-to-use-in-a-world/71690#71690)

   [In Flash Season 2, why couldn't they just tell Grodd their plan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62828/in-flash-season-2-why-couldnt-they-just-tell-grodd-their-plan/71683#71683)
10. (-2) [Differences between the standard and extended versions of TWD S6 E16](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/differences-between-the-standard-and-extended-versions-of-twd-s6-e16/72456#72456)

    [TV show with the same premise as Supernatural](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60473/tv-show-with-the-same-premise-as-supernatural/72149#72149)

    [Ending of "Strangers On A Train"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49473/ending-of-strangers-on-a-train/71965#71965)

Answer (score 1):

The **November 2017** challenge has garnered 13 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 8 and acceptance) coming from [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge and earned her a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [What is the reason for the 1999 setting?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64399/what-is-the-reason-for-the-1999-setting/82337#82337)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (7) [Original script details of Flesh and Blood](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61470/original-script-details-of-flesh-and-blood/83124#83124)
3. (5+V) [Travel between South Park and Canada](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69481/travel-between-south-park-and-canada/82358#82358)
4. (4) [Why wasn't Anubis present on the day Horus got crowned?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51897/why-wasnt-anubis-present-on-the-day-horus-got-crowned/83139#83139)
5. (3) [Did Helen know the truth at the end of Enemy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/did-helen-know-the-truth-at-the-end-of-enemy/82641#82641)
6. (2+V) [Why is the fighter pilot angry that Akanye saved him from Mechagodzilla?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73904/why-is-the-fighter-pilot-angry-that-akanye-saved-him-from-mechagodzilla/83037#83037)
7. (2) [Magneto's Children in Avengers and X-Men](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74753/magnetos-children-in-avengers-and-x-men/82277#82277)
8. (1) [How did Trish's mom gain custody of Jessica?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74868/how-did-trishs-mom-gain-custody-of-jessica/82218#82218)
9. (0+V) [In Caprica, what caused the deterioration in friendship between Joseph Adama and Gautreau?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70288/in-caprica-what-caused-the-deterioration-in-friendship-between-joseph-adama-and/82245#82245)
10. (0) [Why did the Chechens leave the money in the bag with the bloody arm?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65141/why-did-the-chechens-leave-the-money-in-the-bag-with-the-bloody-arm/83020#83020)

    [Please help identify old animated film, maybe anime film](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74962/please-help-identify-old-animated-film-maybe-anime-film/82419#82419)

    [Why is the name 'Batman' avoided in the Dawn of Justice?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51742/why-is-the-name-batman-avoided-in-the-dawn-of-justice/82944#82944)
11. (-1) [Magneto's Children in Avengers and X-Men](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74753/magnetos-children-in-avengers-and-x-men/82274#82274)