# Monthly Answer Challenge 2018: Solve old unanswered questions!

Tags: discussion, challenge, answers

Due to the success of our [previous challenges for answering unanswered questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49), We're continuing our **monthly habit** of rewarding the best answer to any old unanswered question in order to encourage people to engage into solving some of our old unsolved problems. Thus independent from our more question-centered [weekly topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49), we'd like you to **answer any question that was asked more than 3 months before the current month and that doesn't have an answer yet**.

To check for eligible questions you can use the [search function](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+created%3A..2018-08) or [this data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/370061). The top-voted answer given each month will be rewarded **a bounty of 100 points if it has a score of at least 3 or has been accepted**.

Answer (score 7):

The **May 2018** challenge has garnered 15 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 9 and acceptance) coming from [*JenniP*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/28851), which makes her the winner of this challenge and earns her a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why was Dr Who not filmed in HD when Torchwood was?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84148/why-was-dr-who-not-filmed-in-hd-when-torchwood-was/89389#89389)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (6+V) [How is this shot in Batman made?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42434/how-is-this-shot-in-batman-made/89314#89314)
3. (5+V) [What percentage of movies make a net loss during their theatrical run?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43404/what-percentage-of-movies-make-a-net-loss-during-their-theatrical-run/88747#88747)
4. (4+V) [What changes were made in Princess Kaguya from the original Tale of the Bamboo Cutter story?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64418/what-changes-were-made-in-princess-kaguya-from-the-original-tale-of-the-bamboo-c/89067#89067)

   [What does Sicario have to do with Sabrina the Teenage Witch?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71679/what-does-sicario-have-to-do-with-sabrina-the-teenage-witch/89243#89243)
5. (3+V) [Was "Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D." planned after "The Avengers"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82351/was-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-planned-after-the-avengers/89271#89271)

   [Black Siren hair style change in Arrow Season 6 Episode 10](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85044/black-siren-hair-style-change-in-arrow-season-6-episode-10/89188#89188)
6. (3) [How is this shot in Batman made?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42434/how-is-this-shot-in-batman-made/89343#89343)

   [Why is there no cut in Philip's hand?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38867/why-is-there-no-cut-in-philips-hand/89253#89253)
7. (2) [Semen eating scene in Toni Erdmann](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69275/semen-eating-scene-in-toni-erdmann/88571#88571)

   [Millennium Falcon interiors, exteriors, and models](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83483/millennium-falcon-interiors-exteriors-and-models/89214#89214)

   [What's with the "gems" Delaney finds aboard the "Felice Adventurero"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79978/whats-with-the-gems-delaney-finds-aboard-the-felice-adventurero/88982#88982)
8. (1) [Whom was Andy working for when he was a shoe-shiner?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56918/whom-was-andy-working-for-when-he-was-a-shoe-shiner/89254#89254)
9. (0+V) [Why does Ivar say "who cares?" when Sigurd Snake-in-the-eye said "Siggy is dead."?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83352/why-does-ivar-say-who-cares-when-sigurd-snake-in-the-eye-said-siggy-is-dead/88646#88646)
10. (0) [What is the process for a movie getting a song written by a popular artist?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57067/what-is-the-process-for-a-movie-getting-a-song-written-by-a-popular-artist/89276#89276)

Answer (score 3):

The **March 2018** challenge has garnered 13 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 5) coming from [*theMayer*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/57349), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How does Regal's RPX format compare with IMAX?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82827/how-does-regals-rpx-format-compare-with-imax/87649#87649)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3) [Clay's Leadership - Was he right?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49088/clays-leadership-was-he-right/87490#87490)
3. (2) [Why did Brain ask Brendan about letting Dode go back to the theater?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76394/why-did-brain-ask-brendan-about-letting-dode-go-back-to-the-theater/87714#87714)
4. (1) [Three Days of the Condor - communications protocols. Script vs movie adaptation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45970/three-days-of-the-condor-communications-protocols-script-vs-movie-adaptation/87452#87452)

   [Origin of Mr. Burns use of "like a spaniard"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61908/origin-of-mr-burns-use-of-like-a-spaniard/87697#87697)

   [Is there any connection between Liz and Ron’s office food pictures?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62561/is-there-any-connection-between-liz-and-ron-s-office-food-pictures/86222#86222)

   [Why does Spyglass trust Lorraine?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82884/why-does-spyglass-trust-lorraine/87631#87631)

   [Why didn't the Beast kill Julia?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67730/why-didnt-the-beast-kill-julia/86186#86186)
5. (0) [How did Dom arrange the meeting with Magdalene Shaw?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72806/how-did-dom-arrange-the-meeting-with-magdalene-shaw/86275#86275)

   [What do Cohle's hallucinations represent?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61501/what-do-cohles-hallucinations-represent/86425#86425)

   [Is Planet Nowhere based on a real-world series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72647/is-planet-nowhere-based-on-a-real-world-series/87602#87602)

   [Why does Moe Greene speak with a strange voice?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73396/why-does-moe-greene-speak-with-a-strange-voice/86274#86274)
6. (-1) [How is it that no one knows who Arnold is?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64948/how-is-it-that-no-one-knows-who-arnold-is/86187#86187)

Answer (score 3):

The **April 2018** challenge has garnered 27 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6 and acceptance) coming from [*A J*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How can Hela hold or break Mjolnir?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81331/how-can-hela-hold-or-break-mjolnir/88366#88366)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5+V) [Did Mork and Mindy scripts really mark the gaps for Robin Williams's ad-libs?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48901/did-mork-and-mindy-scripts-really-mark-the-gaps-for-robin-williamss-ad-libs/87966#87966)

   [How does Kris realize what's going on?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69660/how-does-kris-realize-whats-going-on/88151#88151)
3. (5) [How does the medpod perform the abortion correctly if it is configured for male use?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47597/how-does-the-medpod-perform-the-abortion-correctly-if-it-is-configured-for-male/88433#88433)

   [How can Hela hold or break Mjolnir?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81331/how-can-hela-hold-or-break-mjolnir/88367#88367)
4. (4+V) [Was Bartlet's multiple sclerosis 'disclosure' crisis merely a plot device?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84377/was-bartlets-multiple-sclerosis-disclosure-crisis-merely-a-plot-device/87793#87793)
5. (3) [Why didn't Cinderella's slippers vanish?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73751/why-didnt-cinderellas-slippers-vanish/88426#88426)

   [Why does Burt say these words in "Go (1999)" movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72349/why-does-burt-say-these-words-in-go-1999-movie/88427#88427)

   [What is the exact relation of Hela to others?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82032/what-is-the-exact-relation-of-hela-to-others/88218#88218)
6. (2+V) [Where was the film "The Color of Paradise (original Rang-e khoda)" made?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83185/where-was-the-film-the-color-of-paradise-original-rang-e-khoda-made/88231#88231)
7. (2) [Where is this shot of Takodana taken from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73217/where-is-this-shot-of-takodana-taken-from/88374#88374)

   [First example of "super-wealthy steal younger bodies for immortality" plot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80779/first-example-of-super-wealthy-steal-younger-bodies-for-immortality-plot/87982#87982)

   [First example of "super-wealthy steal younger bodies for immortality" plot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80779/first-example-of-super-wealthy-steal-younger-bodies-for-immortality-plot/87995#87995)

   [What was governor Nix's motive to keep the Monitor on?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78701/what-was-governor-nixs-motive-to-keep-the-monitor-on/87913#87913)

   [Considering his wound, wouldn't Cheyenne have suffered far more?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70211/considering-his-wound-wouldnt-cheyenne-have-suffered-far-more/88428#88428)

   [What is Tony Soprano's rank at the begining of the show?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73535/what-is-tony-sopranos-rank-at-the-begining-of-the-show/88378#88378)
8. (1) [Why does Josh have a gun range target in his office?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81126/why-does-josh-have-a-gun-range-target-in-his-office/87871#87871)

   [Why does Lt. Manion stand mute, rather than plead not guilty in Anatomy of a Murder?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78589/why-does-lt-manion-stand-mute-rather-than-plead-not-guilty-in-anatomy-of-a-mur/88449#88449)

   [What official sequels have there been to the 1939 Wizard of Oz movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67247/what-official-sequels-have-there-been-to-the-1939-wizard-of-oz-movie/88280#88280)

   [How did the Lori-Gibb gang bring Freddy to life?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72429/how-did-the-lori-gibb-gang-bring-freddy-to-life/88090#88090)

   [Why did Gerty sudenly reveal the secret of the Lunar Industries to Sam?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82731/why-did-gerty-sudenly-reveal-the-secret-of-the-lunar-industries-to-sam/87783#87783)
9. (0) [How does Mike know that the monster craves blood?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82531/how-does-mike-know-that-the-monster-craves-blood/87905#87905)

   [Where is the Westworld park actually located?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/where-is-the-westworld-park-actually-located/88352#88352)

   [Why does David Grant hide when George & Jean showed up near his parents?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69803/why-does-david-grant-hide-when-george-jean-showed-up-near-his-parents/88228#88228)

   [How did Jesse run in an eight-like fashion without wearing the special speedster suit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62234/how-did-jesse-run-in-an-eight-like-fashion-without-wearing-the-special-speedster/88274#88274)

   [How did demon contact Janice while it's locked in a room?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81447/how-did-demon-contact-janice-while-its-locked-in-a-room/88078#88078)

   [Why didn't Hannah notice this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84162/why-didnt-hannah-notice-this/88157#88157)

Answer (score 2):

The **January 2018** challenge has garnered 12 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 8) coming from [*Ne Mo*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/28799), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [What was Jack's motivation in Felina?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70327/what-was-jacks-motivation-in-felina/85283#85283)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (6) [Why does the Stevenson Award show "Sheldon Cooper Ph.D." when he got his Ph.D. at 16?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57155/why-does-the-stevenson-award-show-sheldon-cooper-ph-d-when-he-got-his-ph-d-a/84656#84656)
3. (3+V) [Did EXOTICA use sign language?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51475/did-exotica-use-sign-language/84425#84425)
4. (3) [Where did Alien come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60165/where-did-alien-come-from/84473#84473)
5. (2+V) [Yellow substance being consumed](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80445/yellow-substance-being-consumed/84807#84807)
6. (2) [Why does the audience let Patty fall?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57446/why-does-the-audience-let-patty-fall/85129#85129)

   [About the pregnant woman in The Talented Mr.Ripley](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/about-the-pregnant-woman-in-the-talented-mr-ripley/84642#84642)

   [Was Mark genuinely supportive in A Dark Song?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80065/was-mark-genuinely-supportive-in-a-dark-song/84840#84840)
7. (0) [Did Sean Gullette actually trepan himself in Pi (1998)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52051/did-sean-gullette-actually-trepan-himself-in-pi-1998/84863#84863)

   [Did the castle's enchanted staff gain magical powers after the curse?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73448/did-the-castles-enchanted-staff-gain-magical-powers-after-the-curse/85008#85008)

   [What was Jack's motivation in Felina?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70327/what-was-jacks-motivation-in-felina/85077#85077)
8. (-1) [Did Sean Gullette actually trepan himself in Pi (1998)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52051/did-sean-gullette-actually-trepan-himself-in-pi-1998/84806#84806)

Comment: Many thanks. Not obvious from the name... but I'm a man ;)

Comment: Sorry, copied from last month. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The **February 2018** challenge has garnered 20 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 9 and acceptance) coming from [*gingerbreadboy*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/3818), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How did Queen feel about the Highlander film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66695/how-did-queen-feel-about-the-highlander-film/86003#86003)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (7) [In South Park S7E6 "Li'l Crime Stoppers", why does Cartman stick up for Kyle?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82091/in-south-park-s7e6-lil-crime-stoppers-why-does-cartman-stick-up-for-kyle/85875#85875)
3. (5+V) [Why the bollywood dance number in Legion?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68431/why-the-bollywood-dance-number-in-legion/85348#85348)

   [What was the thing that was blurred out during the 2 super market cash counter scenes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80198/what-was-the-thing-that-was-blurred-out-during-the-2-super-market-cash-counter-s/86000#86000)
4. (5) [Why do so many movies still use the Wilhelm scream?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45631/why-do-so-many-movies-still-use-the-wilhelm-scream/85363#85363)

   [Why is the "I coulda been a contender" line from On the Waterfront so famous?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/why-is-the-i-coulda-been-a-contender-line-from-on-the-waterfront-so-famous/86017#86017)
5. (4+V) [What does Johnny's father write about?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41050/what-does-johnnys-father-write-about/85545#85545)
6. (4) [How can one be nominated for an Oscar as "Best Actor" and "Best supporting Actor" in the same Film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68797/how-can-one-be-nominated-for-an-oscar-as-best-actor-and-best-supporting-actor/85750#85750)
7. (3) [Why was Michael Scott forgotten so easily?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70656/why-was-michael-scott-forgotten-so-easily/85899#85899)
8. (2) [Why was the demon after the little girl?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68979/why-was-the-demon-after-the-little-girl/85843#85843)

   [Is it possible that Eleanor orchestrated this event?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79107/is-it-possible-that-eleanor-orchestrated-this-event/85736#85736)
9. (1) [Did the DCAU ever hint about Harley Quinn's bisexuality?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75566/did-the-dcau-ever-hint-about-harley-quinns-bisexuality/85824#85824)
10. (0) [How was Margaret not going to get deported for marrying Andrew?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75126/how-was-margaret-not-going-to-get-deported-for-marrying-andrew/86007#86007)

    [How did Chigurh find the hotel he was staying at?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74459/how-did-chigurh-find-the-hotel-he-was-staying-at/85803#85803)

    [Why did the Secret Service confiscate all cell-phones/devices?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81328/why-did-the-secret-service-confiscate-all-cell-phones-devices/85977#85977)

    [What happened to Eric after the Dauntless invasion simulator?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79139/what-happened-to-eric-after-the-dauntless-invasion-simulator/85965#85965)

    [Why didn't Four warn the rest of Dauntless what was going to happen?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79604/why-didnt-four-warn-the-rest-of-dauntless-what-was-going-to-happen/85963#85963)

    [Was Berlin a part of the grand setup?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53935/was-berlin-a-part-of-the-grand-setup/85990#85990)

    [In the movie Sorcerer, why does Nilo make the dangerous truck trip to the burning oil field?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71587/in-the-movie-sorcerer-why-does-nilo-make-the-dangerous-truck-trip-to-the-burnin/85853#85853)
11. (-1) [How were the maze walls and ground suddenly intact again?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79240/how-were-the-maze-walls-and-ground-suddenly-intact-again/86011#86011)

Comment: Glad to help. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The **August 2018** challenge has garnered 22 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4) coming from [*m1gp0z*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/53231), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why do criminals whistle after doing something?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/why-do-criminals-whistle-after-doing-something/91887#91887)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [Why does the action look choppy in Captain America: Civil War?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60389/why-does-the-action-look-choppy-in-captain-america-civil-war/92149#92149)
3. (3) [Does Rogue One reference A New Hope in the way the Death Star's firing is depicted?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65107/does-rogue-one-reference-a-new-hope-in-the-way-the-death-stars-firing-is-depict/91958#91958)

   [What motivated Mr. Smith to carry on?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16594/what-motivated-mr-smith-to-carry-on/92170#92170)
4. (2+V) [Are aliens afraid of ghosts?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87710/are-aliens-afraid-of-ghosts/92152#92152)

   [Did Damian Lewis appear in Season 6?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78326/did-damian-lewis-appear-in-season-6/91957#91957)
5. (2) [Age issue in How Old Are You](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19991/age-issue-in-how-old-are-you/91973#91973)

   [Did Billy Bob Thornton really use crushed glass in his shoes in Sling Blade?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50644/did-billy-bob-thornton-really-use-crushed-glass-in-his-shoes-in-sling-blade/91790#91790)

   [When are dialect coaches brought in?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34660/when-are-dialect-coaches-brought-in/91778#91778)

   [Is the movie "Killing of a Sacred Deer", a metaphor or allegory?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82191/is-the-movie-killing-of-a-sacred-deer-a-metaphor-or-allegory/92172#92172)
6. (1+V) [How many mailgirls were there on Monstervision?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41072/how-many-mailgirls-were-there-on-monstervision/91873#91873)
7. (1) ['Tony Stonem' type in classical literature](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50917/tony-stonem-type-in-classical-literature/91660#91660)

   [Are there any global standards to identify a movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62130/are-there-any-global-standards-to-identify-a-movie/91959#91959)

   [How did so many helicopters fit on deck?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75518/how-did-so-many-helicopters-fit-on-deck/91885#91885)

   [Why do these three lines appear at the end of closing credits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73357/why-do-these-three-lines-appear-at-the-end-of-closing-credits/92169#92169)

   [How are answers judged on Dutch TV quiz show "De Slimste Mens"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79568/how-are-answers-judged-on-dutch-tv-quiz-show-de-slimste-mens/91979#91979)

   [Has the length of action scenes changed over time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51766/has-the-length-of-action-scenes-changed-over-time/91809#91809)

   [Are the first two episodes of season 4 of Bojack Horseman borrowing plots from films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80188/are-the-first-two-episodes-of-season-4-of-bojack-horseman-borrowing-plots-from-f/92099#92099)
8. (0) [Why did netflix change the number of episodes of La casa de papel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85228/why-did-netflix-change-the-number-of-episodes-of-la-casa-de-papel/92080#92080)

   [Did the paranormal debunker meet his end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56870/did-the-paranormal-debunker-meet-his-end/91737#91737)
9. (-1) [Significance of the painting for Chiaki and Makoto](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87740/significance-of-the-painting-for-chiaki-and-makoto/91597#91597)
10. (-3) [Has the length of action scenes changed over time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51766/has-the-length-of-action-scenes-changed-over-time/91798#91798)

Answer (score 2):

The **September 2018** challenge has garnered 15 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6 and acceptance) coming from [*sanpaco*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22993), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Did Walter’s cancer really relapse at the end of Breaking Bad — or is it possibly his lie, to justify his behavior?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82330/did-walter-s-cancer-really-relapse-at-the-end-of-breaking-bad-or-is-it-possibl/92189#92189)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5) [Were any Jedi actually successful at remaining completely emotionally unattached?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88945/were-any-jedi-actually-successful-at-remaining-completely-emotionally-unattached/92592#92592)
3. (4+V) [What was Jong-goo's sin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66784/what-was-jong-goos-sin/92208#92208)
4. (3+V) [PBS vs. BBC "Civilizations"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88613/pbs-vs-bbc-civilizations/92428#92428)

   [What was with the hinted suicidal tendencies of Henry?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78653/what-was-with-the-hinted-suicidal-tendencies-of-henry/92369#92369)
5. (2+V) [Jacob's Ladder timeline explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79380/jacobs-ladder-timeline-explanation/92451#92451)
6. (1) [When was the phrase "It's quiet, a little too quiet" first used?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79626/when-was-the-phrase-its-quiet-a-little-too-quiet-first-used/92576#92576)

   [What's with the music in the TV series "Stalker?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88049/whats-with-the-music-in-the-tv-series-stalker/92256#92256)

   [How did the first T-1000 die?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74169/how-did-the-first-t-1000-die/92782#92782)

   [Mystery surrounding Ichabod's mother](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74399/mystery-surrounding-ichabods-mother/92618#92618)
7. (0+V) [Were any Jedi actually successful at remaining completely emotionally unattached?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88945/were-any-jedi-actually-successful-at-remaining-completely-emotionally-unattached/92701#92701)
8. (0) [Why doesn't Jane Chatwin simply go back in time and kill Martin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86184/why-doesnt-jane-chatwin-simply-go-back-in-time-and-kill-martin/92732#92732)

   [Is it true that Jodorowsky killed all the lambs himself for the crucifixion procession in The Holy Mountain?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67113/is-it-true-that-jodorowsky-killed-all-the-lambs-himself-for-the-crucifixion-proc/92808#92808)
9. (-1) [How do the SAW movies achieve dismemberment on screen?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80856/how-do-the-saw-movies-achieve-dismemberment-on-screen/92666#92666)
10. (-2) [Why doesn't Jane Chatwin simply go back in time and kill Martin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86184/why-doesnt-jane-chatwin-simply-go-back-in-time-and-kill-martin/92709#92709)

Answer (score 2):

The **October 2018** challenge has garnered 20 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6 and acceptance) coming from [*Tobyffub*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/67047), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How is open head of Commander Data done?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84783/how-is-open-head-of-commander-data-done/93374#93374)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5+V) [How accurate is the language they speak in The Witch (2015)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62835/how-accurate-is-the-language-they-speak-in-the-witch-2015/93373#93373)
3. (4) [What's the first appearance of Becoming the Costume that happens on Halloween?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55229/whats-the-first-appearance-of-becoming-the-costume-that-happens-on-halloween/92968#92968)
4. (3+V) [Why did Paul Reubens use a pseudonym for Flight of the Navigator?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52631/why-did-paul-reubens-use-a-pseudonym-for-flight-of-the-navigator/93372#93372)
5. (3) [What is the term for this kind of final scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55712/what-is-the-term-for-this-kind-of-final-scene/92902#92902)

   [How could Danny Rand be removed from the board when he is the majority shareholder?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88644/how-could-danny-rand-be-removed-from-the-board-when-he-is-the-majority-sharehold/93425#93425)

   [Why didn't Elio and Oliver end up together in "Call Me By Your Name"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87611/why-didnt-elio-and-oliver-end-up-together-in-call-me-by-your-name/93079#93079)
6. (2+V) [What is the significance with so many teeth in the movie Triple 9?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89328/what-is-the-significance-with-so-many-teeth-in-the-movie-triple-9/92899#92899)
7. (2) [What does Harris do to Arnulfo at the end of 600 Miles, and why?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66871/what-does-harris-do-to-arnulfo-at-the-end-of-600-miles-and-why/93018#93018)
8. (1+V) [Is there a trope for people that are quite harmless on their own but when paired with 'this guy' they could make a chaos towards their surroundings?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56660/is-there-a-trope-for-people-that-are-quite-harmless-on-their-own-but-when-paired/92894#92894)
9. (1) [Did Selma Ježková pay money for stay?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53552/did-selma-je%c5%bekov%c3%a1-pay-money-for-stay/92971#92971)

   [Is there a pattern to scenes where Baby isn't listening to music but there's no tinnitus sound?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76606/is-there-a-pattern-to-scenes-where-baby-isnt-listening-to-music-but-theres-no/93201#93201)

   [How much technology does Oz have in Emerald City?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67466/how-much-technology-does-oz-have-in-emerald-city/93126#93126)

   [Why is William unaware of Katherine being alive?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71259/why-is-william-unaware-of-katherine-being-alive/92823#92823)

   [What is the first movie where the audience believes a dream sequence is reality until the character wakes up?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/50589/what-is-the-first-movie-where-the-audience-believes-a-dream-sequence-is-reality/93001#93001)
10. (0) [Why did they call the ship of Davy Jones the Flying Dutchman if its story doesn't match the Dutch legend of the Flying Dutchman?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84736/why-did-they-call-the-ship-of-davy-jones-the-flying-dutchman-if-its-story-doesn/93313#93313)

    [Why did they call the ship of Davy Jones the Flying Dutchman if its story doesn't match the Dutch legend of the Flying Dutchman?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84736/why-did-they-call-the-ship-of-davy-jones-the-flying-dutchman-if-its-story-doesn/93321#93321)

    [How did Qi'ra get to Crimson Dawn?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89390/how-did-qira-get-to-crimson-dawn/93285#93285)
11. (-1) [Was the Untempered Schism depicted in the episodes of any of the other Doctors?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89740/was-the-untempered-schism-depicted-in-the-episodes-of-any-of-the-other-doctors/93344#93344)
12. (-2) [Why did they call the ship of Davy Jones the Flying Dutchman if its story doesn't match the Dutch legend of the Flying Dutchman?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84736/why-did-they-call-the-ship-of-davy-jones-the-flying-dutchman-if-its-story-doesn/93311#93311)

Answer (score 2):

The **November 2018** challenge has garnered 10 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 3 and acceptance) coming from [*Mara*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/57742), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How does Derek Vinyard get away with only a Manslaughter charge for the "Curb-Stomp"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78899/how-does-derek-vinyard-get-away-with-only-a-manslaughter-charge-for-the-curb-st/93862#93862)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3) [Was Carter going to jump on the grenade?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65171/was-carter-going-to-jump-on-the-grenade/93879#93879)
3. (2+V) [What's the weapon on Ross's wall?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88097/whats-the-weapon-on-rosss-wall/93832#93832)
4. (2) [How Long Was the Trip from Earth to the Axiom?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84461/how-long-was-the-trip-from-earth-to-the-axiom/94181#94181)
5. (1) [Why was Ant-Man excluded from the Civil War trailer?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43992/why-was-ant-man-excluded-from-the-civil-war-trailer/94124#94124)

   [Can you use a certain song in a trailer, that has been used in a different movie-trailer as well?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42006/can-you-use-a-certain-song-in-a-trailer-that-has-been-used-in-a-different-movie/94069#94069)
6. (0) [Sarath Sandhya - Hindi film adaptation of the novel Manju](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85948/sarath-sandhya-hindi-film-adaptation-of-the-novel-manju/94167#94167)

   [Why does the grandmother in Rapsittie Street Kids talk in gibberish?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83494/why-does-the-grandmother-in-rapsittie-street-kids-talk-in-gibberish/94238#94238)
7. (-1) [Is there a philosophical significance of "Three Horses" in Michael Clayton (2007)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69666/is-there-a-philosophical-significance-of-three-horses-in-michael-clayton-2007/93652#93652)

   [What year does Cable come from?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89155/what-year-does-cable-come-from/94089#94089)

Answer (score 2):

The **December 2018** challenge has garnered 30 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6 and acceptance) coming from [*Nog Shine*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/48608), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why exactly did Cartman let Kyle in on his voting scandal in Obama Wins?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89739/why-exactly-did-cartman-let-kyle-in-on-his-voting-scandal-in-obama-wins/95748#95748)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5+V) [Is there any significance to the Disney character figurines?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83471/is-there-any-significance-to-the-disney-character-figurines/95720#95720)

   [Was this character actually okay?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83059/was-this-character-actually-okay/95885#95885)
3. (4) [What's with the "cockatoo jump scare" in Citizen Kane?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65960/whats-with-the-cockatoo-jump-scare-in-citizen-kane/95900#95900)
4. (3+V) [What was the meaning of Becky's conversation with mama?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82726/what-was-the-meaning-of-beckys-conversation-with-mama/94651#94651)

   [Is Strickland's candy based on a real candy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87594/is-stricklands-candy-based-on-a-real-candy/95924#95924)

   [Was that Karl actually singing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/was-that-karl-actually-singing/95937#95937)

   ['Baby Driver' Tip Offs](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88306/baby-driver-tip-offs/95968#95968)
5. (3) [What is the place where Christopher is initiated?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63972/what-is-the-place-where-christopher-is-initiated/95898#95898)

   [Why does this character have the dream?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89898/why-does-this-character-have-the-dream/95686#95686)
6. (2+V) [Ending of Zach Stone Is Gonna Be Famous](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59515/ending-of-zach-stone-is-gonna-be-famous/95918#95918)

   [Have any participants ever apologized for their involvement in "Mazes and Monsters"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62335/have-any-participants-ever-apologized-for-their-involvement-in-mazes-and-monste/95922#95922)

   [Has the authenticity of the Raiders story conference transcript ever been determined?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84447/has-the-authenticity-of-the-raiders-story-conference-transcript-ever-been-determ/95915#95915)
7. (2) [What were the precautions taken for Derek's safety in the hill scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/27723/what-were-the-precautions-taken-for-dereks-safety-in-the-hill-scene/95938#95938)

   [Why does Moana say 'I've delivered us to where we are'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83801/why-does-moana-say-ive-delivered-us-to-where-we-are/94638#94638)

   [Why they are much younger?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60752/why-they-are-much-younger/94618#94618)

   [Only the Sith deal in absolutes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55489/only-the-sith-deal-in-absolutes/94470#94470)
8. (1+V) [What significance does this poem add to the movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72620/what-significance-does-this-poem-add-to-the-movie/95847#95847)

   [Why are they counting 10 people missing?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75329/why-are-they-counting-10-people-missing/94509#94509)

   [What tied the show Seinfeld to the East Villiage?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72342/what-tied-the-show-seinfeld-to-the-east-villiage/94560#94560)
9. (1) [Why does Moana say 'I've delivered us to where we are'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83801/why-does-moana-say-ive-delivered-us-to-where-we-are/94636#94636)

   [How does Dr. Perrow know Grace is Traveler 0027?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87555/how-does-dr-perrow-know-grace-is-traveler-0027/95899#95899)

   [Did Jason ever have the pattern of picking his target or was it always random?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88200/did-jason-ever-have-the-pattern-of-picking-his-target-or-was-it-always-random/95768#95768)

   [Significance of the Magnificent Seven reference in The Nest](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/14479/significance-of-the-magnificent-seven-reference-in-the-nest/94486#94486)
10. (0) [Why are they avoiding showing Arys Oakheart's face?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78179/why-are-they-avoiding-showing-arys-oakhearts-face/95820#95820)

    [Visual fuzziness of Necromonger actions/ships](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86124/visual-fuzziness-of-necromonger-actions-ships/95778#95778)

    [Why wasn't Estarossa affected by Grayroad's Commandment of Pacifism when he killed Meliodas?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90137/why-wasnt-estarossa-affected-by-grayroads-commandment-of-pacifism-when-he-kill/94561#94561)

    [What does Anatoly say to Oliver in Russian in Arrow S5E16?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70223/what-does-anatoly-say-to-oliver-in-russian-in-arrow-s5e16/95959#95959)

    [What's the deal with Dutch (one of Johnny's Friends) from the Original KARATE KID?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72038/whats-the-deal-with-dutch-one-of-johnnys-friends-from-the-original-karate-ki/95767#95767)

    [Why does Chang care so much Mei has left the company?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62046/why-does-chang-care-so-much-mei-has-left-the-company/95725#95725)

Answer (score 1):

The **June 2018** challenge has garnered 13 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 7) coming from [*RappaportXXX*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/64150), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Was there a scene in Honey I Shrunk the Kids where Nick talked about the size of his database?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71460/was-there-a-scene-in-honey-i-shrunk-the-kids-where-nick-talked-about-the-size-of/89459#89459)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5) [Which is the first movie to show movie right after production logo without cuts?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73447/which-is-the-first-movie-to-show-movie-right-after-production-logo-without-cuts/89534#89534)
3. (3+V) [What did Auggie's father give to his wife in the movie Wonder?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85246/what-did-auggies-father-give-to-his-wife-in-the-movie-wonder/89953#89953)
4. (3) [How does Bitsey Bloom think that the murder is staged just from seeing towel?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73489/how-does-bitsey-bloom-think-that-the-murder-is-staged-just-from-seeing-towel/89840#89840)
5. (2+V) [How did Jim and Alfred know that the guards weren't real?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83874/how-did-jim-and-alfred-know-that-the-guards-werent-real/89484#89484)

   [How does the voicing for "Ma vie de Courgette" work in British and American English?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70299/how-does-the-voicing-for-ma-vie-de-courgette-work-in-british-and-american-engl/89674#89674)
6. (1+V) [Why did Baz and Josh paint room white before stealing the safe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76316/why-did-baz-and-josh-paint-room-white-before-stealing-the-safe/89587#89587)

   [Are there any other references to Gang Starr lyrics in Luke Cage dialog?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61861/are-there-any-other-references-to-gang-starr-lyrics-in-luke-cage-dialog/89851#89851)
7. (1) [Did Aldrich Killian believe Extremis to be safe in his case?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59363/did-aldrich-killian-believe-extremis-to-be-safe-in-his-case/89958#89958)
8. (0) [Was Gunda planned as a Trash movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36044/was-gunda-planned-as-a-trash-movie/89813#89813)

   [Was Gunda planned as a Trash movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36044/was-gunda-planned-as-a-trash-movie/89815#89815)
9. (-1) [Was there an intentional reference with the quote "smoking cigarettes and watching Captain Kangaroo"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76652/was-there-an-intentional-reference-with-the-quote-smoking-cigarettes-and-watchi/89888#89888)
10. (-2) [Why didn't Inadu's curse effect Hope Mikaelson?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81037/why-didnt-inadus-curse-effect-hope-mikaelson/89947#89947)

Answer (score 1):

The **July 2018** challenge has garnered 13 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6) coming from [*Alvaro Fuentes*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/64671), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [What is the deal with Elle's and Budd's accents?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23920/what-is-the-deal-with-elles-and-budds-accents/91516#91516)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [Why does Dante become a Spirit Guide?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85738/why-does-dante-become-a-spirit-guide/90167#90167)
3. (4) [Why did Fred Johnson say the crew of the Rocinante was no longer welcome on Tycho station?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81995/why-did-fred-johnson-say-the-crew-of-the-rocinante-was-no-longer-welcome-on-tych/90209#90209)
4. (3) [Was the character of Brooks Hatlen modeled after the real life "Birdman of Alcatraz"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81616/was-the-character-of-brooks-hatlen-modeled-after-the-real-life-birdman-of-alcat/91537#91537)
5. (2) [Are people from Wayward Pines vegans/vegetarians?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56998/are-people-from-wayward-pines-vegans-vegetarians/90073#90073)

   [How does Gazerbeam find out the password to Syndrome's plan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73325/how-does-gazerbeam-find-out-the-password-to-syndromes-plan/90086#90086)
6. (1+V) [Why did Lee buy another basement apartment with limited furniture?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68466/why-did-lee-buy-another-basement-apartment-with-limited-furniture/91360#91360)
7. (1) [What about the Double Jeopardy in The Client?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82646/what-about-the-double-jeopardy-in-the-client/91370#91370)

   [List of languages spoken in "Vikings" TV series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48911/list-of-languages-spoken-in-vikings-tv-series/91576#91576)

   [Did the Predator franchise ever address AvP or AvP2 being canon or not?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87723/did-the-predator-franchise-ever-address-avp-or-avp2-being-canon-or-not/91287#91287)
8. (0) [Why did the party scene in Precious cut suddenly to a black screen for several seconds then skip to the next scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74913/why-did-the-party-scene-in-precious-cut-suddenly-to-a-black-screen-for-several-s/90265#90265)

   [Why eels don't attack in the pool in "A cure for wellness"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78429/why-eels-dont-attack-in-the-pool-in-a-cure-for-wellness/91529#91529)
9. (-1) [Why was Reddington looking for the girl?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48958/why-was-reddington-looking-for-the-girl/91481#91481)