# Monthly Answer Challenge 2019: Solve old unanswered questions!

Tags: discussion, challenge, answers

Due to the success of our [previous challenges for answering unanswered questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4156/49), We're continuing our **monthly habit** of rewarding the best answer to any old unanswered question in order to encourage people to engage into solving some of our old unsolved problems. Thus independent from our more question-centered [weekly topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49), we'd like you to **answer any question that was asked more than 3 months before the current month and that doesn't have an answer yet**.

To check for eligible questions you can use the [search function](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+created%3A..2019-06) or [this data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/370061). The top-voted answer given each month will be rewarded **a bounty of 100 points if it has a score of at least 3 or has been accepted**.

Comment: So how do you know which questions have been answered as part of this challenge? Do we need to post it somewhere?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf The criteria for which questions/answers are eligible are given above, all you need to do is answer those questions. If you mean how I know which answers to select as candidates/winners, through the magic of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

The **January 2019** challenge has garnered 41 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 5 and acceptance) coming from [*Laurel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/70064), which makes her the winner of this challenge and earns her a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Runic inscription on Finn's mug](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68467/runic-inscription-on-finns-mug/96649#96649)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5) [Why change translation text into a picture for international versions?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64336/why-change-translation-text-into-a-picture-for-international-versions/96832#96832)

   [Were the sex scenes in "The Handmaiden" perceived as inauthentic, e.g. by lesbian reviewers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88354/were-the-sex-scenes-in-the-handmaiden-perceived-as-inauthentic-e-g-by-lesbia/96811#96811)
3. (4+V) [Who are these two persons Travis was staring at?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83121/who-are-these-two-persons-travis-was-staring-at/96786#96786)
4. (4) [The Travelers loophole](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87552/the-travelers-loophole/96057#96057)
5. (3+V) [Kern's eavesdropping in Three Colours: Red](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92556/kerns-eavesdropping-in-three-colours-red/96069#96069)
6. (3) [Does the cat have a significance in Inside Llewyn Davis?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69479/does-the-cat-have-a-significance-in-inside-llewyn-davis/96200#96200)
7. (2+V) [Why does Mattie become angry at Mr. Younger?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78181/why-does-mattie-become-angry-at-mr-younger/96101#96101)

   [What is Terry's connection to Nevada in S05E01?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78584/what-is-terrys-connection-to-nevada-in-s05e01/96516#96516)

   [Were the references to substandard food in Spider-Man: Homecoming a dig at the previous Spider-Man duology?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89547/were-the-references-to-substandard-food-in-spider-man-homecoming-a-dig-at-the-p/96325#96325)

   [Why did the Big Guy say "Small world" when she first arrived?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92020/why-did-the-big-guy-say-small-world-when-she-first-arrived/96684#96684)
8. (2) [What attracted Selby to Lee when she first met her?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92446/what-attracted-selby-to-lee-when-she-first-met-her/96729#96729)

   [Explaining the door between the offices of House and Wilson](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85341/explaining-the-door-between-the-offices-of-house-and-wilson/96603#96603)

   [What is the significance of Captain America Comics?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89394/what-is-the-significance-of-captain-america-comics/96819#96819)

   [How did Hannah and Tony meet in "13 Reasons Why"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72847/how-did-hannah-and-tony-meet-in-13-reasons-why/96726#96726)
9. (1+V) [Why did Merrimen's girl tell him "I did what you told me" after sleeping with Nick?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89723/why-did-merrimens-girl-tell-him-i-did-what-you-told-me-after-sleeping-with-ni/96616#96616)

   [Can anyone explain this reference with Jeremy Piven?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51802/can-anyone-explain-this-reference-with-jeremy-piven/96514#96514)

   [Why the movie titled "Babylon A.D."?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82038/why-the-movie-titled-babylon-a-d/96676#96676)

   [Where is Turkish's boxing office?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88124/where-is-turkishs-boxing-office/96601#96601)

   [Why does Marty put a golf ball in his glove?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89200/why-does-marty-put-a-golf-ball-in-his-glove/96424#96424)

   [Why was Will Graham not charged with the attempted murder of Hannibal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92359/why-was-will-graham-not-charged-with-the-attempted-murder-of-hannibal/96712#96712)

   [Why did the Fairy Queen have to die for a poor deal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88718/why-did-the-fairy-queen-have-to-die-for-a-poor-deal/96804#96804)
10. (1) [What did Edith/Sydney whisper in Irving's ear?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/what-did-edith-sydney-whisper-in-irvings-ear/96825#96825)

    [Chaplin was a composer too?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66026/chaplin-was-a-composer-too/96831#96831)

    [What attracted Selby to Lee when she first met her?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92446/what-attracted-selby-to-lee-when-she-first-met-her/96710#96710)

    [The Travelers loophole](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87552/the-travelers-loophole/96093#96093)

    [The Travelers loophole](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87552/the-travelers-loophole/96098#96098)

    [Why did WCKD send new kids up to the Glade once a month?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73339/why-did-wckd-send-new-kids-up-to-the-glade-once-a-month/96078#96078)

    [Why do fairies' lives not matter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84528/why-do-fairies-lives-not-matter/96472#96472)

    [What's exactly happening to Charlotte Byrde in the swimming at night scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91581/whats-exactly-happening-to-charlotte-byrde-in-the-swimming-at-night-scene/96340#96340)
11. (0) [Why didn't the last survivors of krypton go to the phantom zone to live?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92637/why-didnt-the-last-survivors-of-krypton-go-to-the-phantom-zone-to-live/96360#96360)

    [Can someone explain the ending of the movie "Bleed"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55075/can-someone-explain-the-ending-of-the-movie-bleed/96515#96515)

    [What attracted Selby to Lee when she first met her?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92446/what-attracted-selby-to-lee-when-she-first-met-her/96711#96711)

    [Why did they still accept Deckard into the family even after what he'd done in previous movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73379/why-did-they-still-accept-deckard-into-the-family-even-after-what-hed-done-in-p/96297#96297)

    [Why is Philip 'Lip' Gallagher such a sad character in Shameless?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85150/why-is-philip-lip-gallagher-such-a-sad-character-in-shameless/96588#96588)

    [Film Location of Don Ciccio's Villa](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52903/film-location-of-don-ciccios-villa/96554#96554)

    [Why did Olivia's family celebrate Thanksgiving?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67819/why-did-olivias-family-celebrate-thanksgiving/96202#96202)

    [Why do the three boxes appear when the parademon explodes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92755/why-do-the-three-boxes-appear-when-the-parademon-explodes/96689#96689)

    [When can companies (or other entities) be directly referenced?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60026/when-can-companies-or-other-entities-be-directly-referenced/96776#96776)

    [Why were so many character names changed in the 1974 Murder on the Orient Express?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84118/why-were-so-many-character-names-changed-in-the-1974-murder-on-the-orient-expres/96775#96775)
12. (-1) [Why did the werewolf kill an "innocent" victim?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78519/why-did-the-werewolf-kill-an-innocent-victim/96595#96595)

Answer (score 4):

The **March 2019** challenge has garnered 20 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 5) coming from [*David Regev*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/62112), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [In "Raiders of the Lost Ark", what script appears on the headpiece of the staff of Ra?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89539/in-raiders-of-the-lost-ark-what-script-appears-on-the-headpiece-of-the-staff/98075#98075)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (4+V) [Who are the people in the opening sequence of Mr Robot episode 1 season 1?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80494/who-are-the-people-in-the-opening-sequence-of-mr-robot-episode-1-season-1/98071#98071)
3. (4) [What was the motivation and fate of the Polish Jew?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/18302/what-was-the-motivation-and-fate-of-the-polish-jew/97936#97936)

   [How does merchandising work in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74389/how-does-merchandising-work-in-the-marvel-cinematic-universe/98037#98037)
4. (2+V) [Ragnar's injury after the Paris battle](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89664/ragnars-injury-after-the-paris-battle/97763#97763)

   [What happened to Eli and Oskar in Let the right one in?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74248/what-happened-to-eli-and-oskar-in-let-the-right-one-in/97693#97693)
5. (1+V) [What does Makoto want to do with her future?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87741/what-does-makoto-want-to-do-with-her-future/97600#97600)
6. (1) [Why was Valak not sent back to Hell?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92338/why-was-valak-not-sent-back-to-hell/97571#97571)

   [Shinkai had to stop working on Your Name (Kimi no Na wa), what was left incomplete or unbalanced?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90230/shinkai-had-to-stop-working-on-your-name-kimi-no-na-wa-what-was-left-incomple/97673#97673)

   [Is Vincent a corrupt cop or an undercover cop trying to catch corrupt cops?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73398/is-vincent-a-corrupt-cop-or-an-undercover-cop-trying-to-catch-corrupt-cops/97687#97687)

   [How does Victoria get convicted if Emily is still deemed a nutjob?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41495/how-does-victoria-get-convicted-if-emily-is-still-deemed-a-nutjob/97624#97624)
7. (0) [How can Chae Young-Shin Drive at the end of Healer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/38888/how-can-chae-young-shin-drive-at-the-end-of-healer/97988#97988)

   [How does Christopher Moltisanti respond to the "bridge and tunnel boy" insult?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73629/how-does-christopher-moltisanti-respond-to-the-bridge-and-tunnel-boy-insult/97782#97782)

   [In the movie "Hugo", what are these Pictures supposed to mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93825/in-the-movie-hugo-what-are-these-pictures-supposed-to-mean/97570#97570)

   [Is there an explanation for Batroc's accent?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53595/is-there-an-explanation-for-batrocs-accent/98061#98061)

   [What was Paul trying to achieve by lying to his wife in the final episode of the first season?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47501/what-was-paul-trying-to-achieve-by-lying-to-his-wife-in-the-final-episode-of-the/97758#97758)

   [Why does David go back instead of just telling Christina that he has feelings for her?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92562/why-does-david-go-back-instead-of-just-telling-christina-that-he-has-feelings-fo/97601#97601)

   [When did the cosmic event first occur in Coherence?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93535/when-did-the-cosmic-event-first-occur-in-coherence/97889#97889)

   [What was the crime of the second condemned man in the second episode?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72504/what-was-the-crime-of-the-second-condemned-man-in-the-second-episode/97757#97757)

   [Why couldn't Cage and Rita take a military helicopter to reach the dam?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84779/why-couldnt-cage-and-rita-take-a-military-helicopter-to-reach-the-dam/97602#97602)

Answer (score 3):

The **February 2019** challenge has garnered 27 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 7) coming from [*Joachim*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/67810), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How many restraining orders does Sheldon have?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85816/how-many-restraining-orders-does-sheldon-have/96920#96920)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (6) [Why make replicants so hard to detect?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82242/why-make-replicants-so-hard-to-detect/96928#96928)
3. (5+V) [Did Garibaldi and Sinclair not meet in “War Without End” due to a falling out between the actors?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83116/did-garibaldi-and-sinclair-not-meet-in-war-without-end-due-to-a-falling-out-be/97204#97204)
4. (4+V) [Did Captain Flint love Miranda Barlow more than Thomas?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91422/did-captain-flint-love-miranda-barlow-more-than-thomas/97385#97385)

   [Whose boat got hit by the missile?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90236/whose-boat-got-hit-by-the-missile/97074#97074)
5. (4) [Does Homer dream of killing his father?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83207/does-homer-dream-of-killing-his-father/97090#97090)
6. (3+V) [Where is Wade from s6e6 of walking dead in season 8?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83017/where-is-wade-from-s6e6-of-walking-dead-in-season-8/97329#97329)
7. (3) [Wolverine didn't wake up in the future so he didn't change the past?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89057/wolverine-didnt-wake-up-in-the-future-so-he-didnt-change-the-past/97305#97305)

   [Words on the screen in John Wick](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32522/words-on-the-screen-in-john-wick/96850#96850)

   [Was Gary Connell using an "advance technology" pistol?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85205/was-gary-connell-using-an-advance-technology-pistol/96903#96903)
8. (2+V) [What is the insect they put on Jennifer's chest, and why?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84313/what-is-the-insect-they-put-on-jennifers-chest-and-why/96898#96898)
9. (2) [Where was Zod in the Phantom Zone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68903/where-was-zod-in-the-phantom-zone/97404#97404)
10. (1+V) [Did Cartman truly change during season 20?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89422/did-cartman-truly-change-during-season-20/97069#97069)
11. (1) [How does Shaw know the Engineers hate humans?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74298/how-does-shaw-know-the-engineers-hate-humans/96925#96925)

    [How could Germans be using an animated presentation to depict their attack plan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73234/how-could-germans-be-using-an-animated-presentation-to-depict-their-attack-plan/96981#96981)

    [Does the DVD version of Galavant change this joke telling viewers to set their DVR?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82590/does-the-dvd-version-of-galavant-change-this-joke-telling-viewers-to-set-their-d/96998#96998)

    [Wolverine didn't wake up in the future so he didn't change the past?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89057/wolverine-didnt-wake-up-in-the-future-so-he-didnt-change-the-past/97319#97319)

    [How long was Sabrina in Paris?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87833/how-long-was-sabrina-in-paris/97140#97140)

    [How fast is Bifrost?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89195/how-fast-is-bifrost/96846#96846)

    [Is it possible to start watching Battlestar Galactica (2004) at Season 4.5 and understand the rest of the series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/59563/is-it-possible-to-start-watching-battlestar-galactica-2004-at-season-4-5-and-u/97013#97013)

    [Does the eternal flame reanimate only evil people?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82159/does-the-eternal-flame-reanimate-only-evil-people/96986#96986)
12. (0) [Missing Dock Structure in Alien: Covenant](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73774/missing-dock-structure-in-alien-covenant/96931#96931)

    [How does Shaw know the Engineers hate humans?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74298/how-does-shaw-know-the-engineers-hate-humans/96938#96938)

    [Why are Valerian and Laureline so young, yet have such high ranking positions?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82393/why-are-valerian-and-laureline-so-young-yet-have-such-high-ranking-positions/97231#97231)

    [Were Landa and Hellstrom lovers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41265/were-landa-and-hellstrom-lovers/96861#96861)
13. (-1) [What is the meaning of the tall clouds in "The Girl who leapt through time"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85165/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-tall-clouds-in-the-girl-who-leapt-through-time/97394#97394)
14. (-2) [Why/how does Gupta have Buck's knife?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74333/why-how-does-gupta-have-bucks-knife/97297#97297)

Comment: I must add, Asked the question *How many restraining orders does Sheldon have?* and sadly the answer only gave out facts that I included in the question. nothing more. anyway, I do appreciate very much that Joachim tried to answer while I got nada for long time.

Answer (score 3):

The **June 2019** challenge has garnered 8 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 5 and acceptance) coming from [*Abhinav*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/74753), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why is there a box in Detective Charles Boyle's pants?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66908/why-is-there-a-box-in-detective-charles-boyles-pants/101470#101470)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3) [Why does Sister Charlotte have a baby blanket in her suitcase?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94578/why-does-sister-charlotte-have-a-baby-blanket-in-her-suitcase/101798#101798)

   [What did they do to Sook-hee's face in The Villainess?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83001/what-did-they-do-to-sook-hees-face-in-the-villainess/101744#101744)
3. (2+V) [Why did Villanelle kill that man?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89336/why-did-villanelle-kill-that-man/101537#101537)
4. [High ground in Star Wars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84122/high-ground-in-star-wars/101771#101771)

   [Why wasn't Cole Williams ever convicted of assault?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/why-wasnt-cole-williams-ever-convicted-of-assault/101476#101476)
5. (0) [What is the significance of the black spot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96578/what-is-the-significance-of-the-black-spot/101570#101570)
6. (-3) [Why wasn't Cole Williams ever convicted of assault?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78625/why-wasnt-cole-williams-ever-convicted-of-assault/101471#101471)

Answer (score 3):

The **Semptember 2019** challenge has garnered 9 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 5 and acceptance) coming from [*JohnP*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/6234), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Are there two versions of The Notebook's ending? If so, why?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92824/are-there-two-versions-of-the-notebooks-ending-if-so-why/104268#104268)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3) [How much money was the last bet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71499/how-much-money-was-the-last-bet/103082#103082)

   [What was the first occurrence of background music turning out to be diegetic music for comedic purposes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63819/what-was-the-first-occurrence-of-background-music-turning-out-to-be-diegetic-mus/104267#104267)
3. (2+V) [Why did the troglodytes come to Bright Hope?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92908/why-did-the-troglodytes-come-to-bright-hope/103061#103061)
4. (2) [Was Keanu Reeves cast due to his past hockey experience?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68798/was-keanu-reeves-cast-due-to-his-past-hockey-experience/104271#104271)
5. (1) [Do you get enough information in Midsomer Murders to solve the crimes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78415/do-you-get-enough-information-in-midsomer-murders-to-solve-the-crimes/103014#103014)

   [Which movie started the common practice of 2 sets of closing credits?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60454/which-movie-started-the-common-practice-of-2-sets-of-closing-credits/103130#103130)
6. (0+V) [Product placement in Thieves Like Us?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96899/product-placement-in-thieves-like-us/104144#104144)
7. (-3) [Why is there a Fairy shortage](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66840/why-is-there-a-fairy-shortage/104421#104421)

Answer (score 3):

The **December 2019** challenge has garnered 22 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 7 and acceptance) coming from [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Is there alternate versions of What's Your Raashee?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49221/is-there-alternate-versions-of-whats-your-raashee/105513#105513)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (6) [Why was Breaking Bad's (and other shows) "Intro" so short?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85219/why-was-breaking-bads-and-other-shows-intro-so-short/105455#105455)
3. (5) [Why is this music box given a prominent role in the credits scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95779/why-is-this-music-box-given-a-prominent-role-in-the-credits-scene/105640#105640)
4. (4+V) [Did Anthony Hopkins need to do any prep work for Hannibal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96050/did-anthony-hopkins-need-to-do-any-prep-work-for-hannibal/105489#105489)
5. (3+V) [Was Flash's message in Batman vs Superman for the event occured in Justice League?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97445/was-flashs-message-in-batman-vs-superman-for-the-event-occured-in-justice-leagu/105559#105559)

   [Which one is the guy in yellow? Is he Pat or Mat?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99823/which-one-is-the-guy-in-yellow-is-he-pat-or-mat/105433#105433)
6. (3) [How accurate an adaptation was "Behind the Candelabra"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61311/how-accurate-an-adaptation-was-behind-the-candelabra/105610#105610)

   [Is the rowboat painting in more than 2 episodes and does it have multiple meanings?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97000/is-the-rowboat-painting-in-more-than-2-episodes-and-does-it-have-multiple-meanin/105560#105560)

   [How did Superman know that Lois was falling to catch her in time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92059/how-did-superman-know-that-lois-was-falling-to-catch-her-in-time/105586#105586)
7. (2+V) [Was there ever a plan for more titles in the The Fugitive/US Marshals universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97478/was-there-ever-a-plan-for-more-titles-in-the-the-fugitive-us-marshals-universe/105754#105754)
8. (2) [When does Nate start to train the next generation of Leverage, Inc?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66271/when-does-nate-start-to-train-the-next-generation-of-leverage-inc/105999#105999)
9. (1+V) [How come Kalkeya Chief knew about what Bijjaladeva said a day before war](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43657/how-come-kalkeya-chief-knew-about-what-bijjaladeva-said-a-day-before-war/106012#106012)

   [How do they create the side-impact-crash "from inside the car" shots?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81304/how-do-they-create-the-side-impact-crash-from-inside-the-car-shots/105528#105528)
10. (1) [Why was the New Orleans flag altered in NCIS New Orleans?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89146/why-was-the-new-orleans-flag-altered-in-ncis-new-orleans/105757#105757)

    [Do movie stars need regular teeth whitening?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52352/do-movie-stars-need-regular-teeth-whitening/105456#105456)

    [Is there any connection between Indiana Jones's whip and his fear of snakes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87938/is-there-any-connection-between-indiana-joness-whip-and-his-fear-of-snakes/105918#105918)

    [How many are there in "The 200"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93739/how-many-are-there-in-the-200/105541#105541)

    [How do they guarantee the celebrities' safety?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63989/how-do-they-guarantee-the-celebrities-safety/105457#105457)
11. (0) [How come the ground shook for days after the bombing raids?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97809/how-come-the-ground-shook-for-days-after-the-bombing-raids/105458#105458)

    [Is episode S09E03 a comment on It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia's success at the awards?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24902/is-episode-s09e03-a-comment-on-its-always-sunny-in-philadelphias-success-at-th/105653#105653)
12. (-2) [Why do Auntie Em and Uncle Henry not have counterparts in Oz?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95953/why-do-auntie-em-and-uncle-henry-not-have-counterparts-in-oz/105917#105917)
13. (-6) [First Big Bang Theory episode with none of the guys in pre-credit sequence](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71861/first-big-bang-theory-episode-with-none-of-the-guys-in-pre-credit-sequence/105532#105532)

Answer (score 2):

The **April 2019** challenge has garnered 19 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6 and acceptance) coming from [*Walt*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [On what story is Good Kill (2014) based?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93994/on-what-story-is-good-kill-2014-based/98091#98091)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (5+V) [Why is John Malkovich in Deepwater Horizon omitting words?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93259/why-is-john-malkovich-in-deepwater-horizon-omitting-words/98093#98093)
3. (4+V) [Why isn't there an "I" (Incredibles logo) on Jack-Jack's suit?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90126/why-isnt-there-an-i-incredibles-logo-on-jack-jacks-suit/98434#98434)
4. (4) [Why was Michael Dorn in Star Trek DS9 and not someone else from TNG?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83052/why-was-michael-dorn-in-star-trek-ds9-and-not-someone-else-from-tng/98440#98440)

   [What are the major themes of Alien: Covenant?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95818/what-are-the-major-themes-of-alien-covenant/98580#98580)
5. (3+V) [How does the Big Market work?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85770/how-does-the-big-market-work/98325#98325)

   [Why do Cleo and the other robots build a bug like creature using a nuclear battery?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/66069/why-do-cleo-and-the-other-robots-build-a-bug-like-creature-using-a-nuclear-batte/98443#98443)
6. (3) [What does "There came into Egypt a Pharaoh that did not know" mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86378/what-does-there-came-into-egypt-a-pharaoh-that-did-not-know-mean/98406#98406)

   [Was Mojo Jojo the first mad scientist chimpanzee?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/67249/was-mojo-jojo-the-first-mad-scientist-chimpanzee/98573#98573)

   [Where does poor video quality in some TV series originate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88570/where-does-poor-video-quality-in-some-tv-series-originate/99614#99614)
7. (1) [Do the previous Batman movies adhere to Batman's rules?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85907/do-the-previous-batman-movies-adhere-to-batmans-rules/98409#98409)

   [Were any of these comedian actors actually auditioning for the show?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87712/were-any-of-these-comedian-actors-actually-auditioning-for-the-show/98438#98438)

   [How will Makoto and Chiaki be together in the future?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87746/how-will-makoto-and-chiaki-be-together-in-the-future/98449#98449)

   [Why is King Herod's song ragtime?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94164/why-is-king-herods-song-ragtime/98433#98433)

   [Why did David use his real name instead of Walter's to get the access to the spaceship?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91487/why-did-david-use-his-real-name-instead-of-walters-to-get-the-access-to-the-spa/99607#99607)
8. (0) [Who is the walker that Michonne saw in Season 4 Episode 9?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89816/who-is-the-walker-that-michonne-saw-in-season-4-episode-9/98112#98112)

   [What happened Gennaro Malanga (Little Pussy)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72955/what-happened-gennaro-malanga-little-pussy/99723#99723)

   [Why did Jordan kill herself?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57118/why-did-jordan-kill-herself/98430#98430)
9. (-1) [Who or what killed the camp of people in so little time?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89183/who-or-what-killed-the-camp-of-people-in-so-little-time/98113#98113)

Answer (score 2):

The **May 2019** challenge has garnered 20 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 7 and acceptance) coming from [*Phil*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/73811), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How does Scott Lang afford to live in a townhouse in San Francisco?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90261/how-does-scott-lang-afford-to-live-in-a-townhouse-in-san-francisco/100396#100396)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (7) [What does Louise write on the barrier with Abbott?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70138/what-does-louise-write-on-the-barrier-with-abbott/100852#100852)

   [Why is everyone surprised by Jack-Jack's powers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91434/why-is-everyone-surprised-by-jack-jacks-powers/101188#101188)
3. (6+V) [Why is Christopher hiding at the end of the fifth season?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79116/why-is-christopher-hiding-at-the-end-of-the-fifth-season/101185#101185)
4. (5) [Why did the Wachowskis change the story's themes so significantly?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89322/why-did-the-wachowskis-change-the-storys-themes-so-significantly/100810#100810)
5. (4) [What did they do to David Schwimmer to simulate the tan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52720/what-did-they-do-to-david-schwimmer-to-simulate-the-tan/101254#101254)
6. (3+V) [Was April trying to commit suicide?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76247/was-april-trying-to-commit-suicide/101257#101257)

   [Who manufactured the corrupt Intersect and deposited it in the castle?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30498/who-manufactured-the-corrupt-intersect-and-deposited-it-in-the-castle/101173#101173)
7. (3) [Was V saving Evey really coincidence?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89321/was-v-saving-evey-really-coincidence/100809#100809)

   [Why does Andrew Borba say "pork and beans"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89902/why-does-andrew-borba-say-pork-and-beans/101187#101187)

   [How much is Stan Lee paid for his cameos in MCU films?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/43742/how-much-is-stan-lee-paid-for-his-cameos-in-mcu-films/101255#101255)

   [Why does the Watchers Council not seem to care how or why a slayer dies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89471/why-does-the-watchers-council-not-seem-to-care-how-or-why-a-slayer-dies/100561#100561)
8. (2+V) [How can Credence be Dumbledore's brother?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96170/how-can-credence-be-dumbledores-brother/101243#101243)

   [What is the symbolism of the tree canopy shots in It Follows?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89749/what-is-the-symbolism-of-the-tree-canopy-shots-in-it-follows/100778#100778)
9. (1) [Who is the guy in the men’s wash room who got killed accidentally?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95944/who-is-the-guy-in-the-men-s-wash-room-who-got-killed-accidentally/101245#101245)

   [Why can't King Horik face Jarl Borg alone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/87808/why-cant-king-horik-face-jarl-borg-alone/101249#101249)

   [How Does the Delta Flyer Get Repaired in Star Trek: Voyager Season 7?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/65504/how-does-the-delta-flyer-get-repaired-in-star-trek-voyager-season-7/100741#100741)

   [How did A.M.A.Z.O. manage to copy Kryptonian powers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96471/how-did-a-m-a-z-o-manage-to-copy-kryptonian-powers/101241#101241)
10. (-1) [How can Credence be Dumbledore's brother?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96170/how-can-credence-be-dumbledores-brother/100548#100548)
11. (-3) [Name for this common stock scream? (not the Wilhelm scream)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62456/name-for-this-common-stock-scream-not-the-wilhelm-scream/100866#100866)

Answer (score 2):

The **July 2019** challenge has garnered 23 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 6) coming from [*Flater*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22424), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. ["Fland Canyon" and Maude](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52316/fland-canyon-and-maude/101901#101901)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [What is the meaning behind the use of time in Donnie Darko's cinematography?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82292/what-is-the-meaning-behind-the-use-of-time-in-donnie-darkos-cinematography/102222#102222)
3. (3) [What are the colors on the globe in the 90s-00s Universal Studios logo?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56524/what-are-the-colors-on-the-globe-in-the-90s-00s-universal-studios-logo/102371#102371)

   [Is there any possible explanation for why the chairman of the museum adores Mr.Bean in the Bean movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/70463/is-there-any-possible-explanation-for-why-the-chairman-of-the-museum-adores-mr-b/102007#102007)
4. (2+V) [Relation between Warlock Lord and Allanon in The Shannara Chronicles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86406/relation-between-warlock-lord-and-allanon-in-the-shannara-chronicles/102252#102252)

   [Is there any significance in the text above the door in Outlander?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97981/is-there-any-significance-in-the-text-above-the-door-in-outlander/101946#101946)
5. (2) [Who was in the coffin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97300/who-was-in-the-coffin/101877#101877)

   [What are the colors on the globe in the 90s-00s Universal Studios logo?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56524/what-are-the-colors-on-the-globe-in-the-90s-00s-universal-studios-logo/102367#102367)
6. (1) [How did Thomas know about "Her Ladyship's soap?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97304/how-did-thomas-know-about-her-ladyships-soap/102169#102169)

   [Relation between Warlock Lord and Allanon in The Shannara Chronicles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86406/relation-between-warlock-lord-and-allanon-in-the-shannara-chronicles/102194#102194)

   [How did Efraim cut out Henry?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69354/how-did-efraim-cut-out-henry/101971#101971)

   [Customs and decisions on putting bloopers in end credits](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62004/customs-and-decisions-on-putting-bloopers-in-end-credits/101856#101856)

   [Customs and decisions on putting bloopers in end credits](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62004/customs-and-decisions-on-putting-bloopers-in-end-credits/101861#101861)

   [What is the connection between Guillermo del Toro and the video game Portal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86353/what-is-the-connection-between-guillermo-del-toro-and-the-video-game-portal/101878#101878)

   [What was the ending of Night Moves about?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97991/what-was-the-ending-of-night-moves-about/101913#101913)

   [What was the ending of Night Moves about?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97991/what-was-the-ending-of-night-moves-about/102079#102079)

   [How are movies distributed internationally?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/63368/how-are-movies-distributed-internationally/101915#101915)

   [Why was Sartaj astonished on seeing the passport in Gaitonde's possession?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96917/why-was-sartaj-astonished-on-seeing-the-passport-in-gaitondes-possession/102260#102260)
7. (0) [What was the ending of Night Moves about?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97991/what-was-the-ending-of-night-moves-about/102085#102085)

   ["Fland Canyon" and Maude](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52316/fland-canyon-and-maude/101906#101906)

   [How is it that Madeline and Nathan are both living (with their families) in Monterey?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/91838/how-is-it-that-madeline-and-nathan-are-both-living-with-their-families-in-mont/102399#102399)

   [How did Thomas know about "Her Ladyship's soap?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97304/how-did-thomas-know-about-her-ladyships-soap/102134#102134)
8. (-3) [How historically accurate is the climactic briefing scene in Downfall?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53040/how-historically-accurate-is-the-climactic-briefing-scene-in-downfall/102199#102199)

Answer (score 2):

The **August 2019** challenge has garnered 15 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4) coming from [*MivaScott*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/63448), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [What happened to the Mondoshawan trapped in the chamber of the elements?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80899/what-happened-to-the-mondoshawan-trapped-in-the-chamber-of-the-elements/102517#102517)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [Why did Hannibal hide his fingerprints on the elk when killing Tobias?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90149/why-did-hannibal-hide-his-fingerprints-on-the-elk-when-killing-tobias/102422#102422)
3. (3) [Why is the Spirit of the West metal detecting in Rango?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90069/why-is-the-spirit-of-the-west-metal-detecting-in-rango/102674#102674)
4. (2) [What was the significance of two different shoes worn in Peaceful Warrior?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69416/what-was-the-significance-of-two-different-shoes-worn-in-peaceful-warrior/102807#102807)

   [How are the tethered able to plan a revolt in Us?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97999/how-are-the-tethered-able-to-plan-a-revolt-in-us/102572#102572)

   [Why did Gaitonde kill himself in Sacred Games?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93941/why-did-gaitonde-kill-himself-in-sacred-games/102631#102631)
5. (1+V) [Over what time period does Once Upon A Time In The West take place?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31921/over-what-time-period-does-once-upon-a-time-in-the-west-take-place/102870#102870)
6. (1) [The Glaive from Krull](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74130/the-glaive-from-krull/102641#102641)

   [What is the significance of Jessica drawing a chain of circles?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89507/what-is-the-significance-of-jessica-drawing-a-chain-of-circles/102922#102922)

   [Why did Khudabaksh behave inconsistently in Thugs of Hindostan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93758/why-did-khudabaksh-behave-inconsistently-in-thugs-of-hindostan/102845#102845)

   [June's behavior with the Waterfords](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97930/junes-behavior-with-the-waterfords/102609#102609)

   [What happened to the Mondoshawan trapped in the chamber of the elements?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80899/what-happened-to-the-mondoshawan-trapped-in-the-chamber-of-the-elements/102514#102514)

   [Significance of Clay Jensen's journey of getting his tattoo completed?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89237/significance-of-clay-jensens-journey-of-getting-his-tattoo-completed/102923#102923)
7. (0) [June's behavior with the Waterfords](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97930/junes-behavior-with-the-waterfords/102615#102615)
8. (-1) [Shouldn't Master Roshi have been disqualified for using Containment Wave?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79923/shouldnt-master-roshi-have-been-disqualified-for-using-containment-wave/102589#102589)

Answer (score 2):

The **November 2019** challenge has garnered 5 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 3 and acceptance) coming from [*Luciano*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/19762), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How did Smith deduce that Heydrich was the one who ordered his ambush?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93419/how-did-smith-deduce-that-heydrich-was-the-one-who-ordered-his-ambush/104965#104965)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (2+V) [What does Freysa mean by this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101636/what-does-freysa-mean-by-this/105321#105321)
3. (0+V) [What was the role of the private detective in the conspiracy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81577/what-was-the-role-of-the-private-detective-in-the-conspiracy/105116#105116)
4. (0) [Why was Flash affected by the prison pudding in Season 4?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93565/why-was-flash-affected-by-the-prison-pudding-in-season-4/105097#105097)

   [Why doesn't Sgt. Howie never seek person who filed police complaint in The Wicker Man?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35047/why-doesnt-sgt-howie-never-seek-person-who-filed-police-complaint-in-the-wicke/105330#105330)

Answer (score 1):

The **October 2019** challenge has garnered 15 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4) coming from [*Tim*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/41652), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why didn't Darth Vader just use the force to choke and throw Darth Sidious into the electric core?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81707/why-didnt-darth-vader-just-use-the-force-to-choke-and-throw-darth-sidious-into/104762#104762)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (3+V) [Cookie Monster's first appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/98300/cookie-monsters-first-appearance/104875#104875)
3. (2) [Was there a real-world reason for Lou to leave Flashpoint?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101767/was-there-a-real-world-reason-for-lou-to-leave-flashpoint/104876#104876)

   [How does the use of common commerical products work in movies/TV?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85683/how-does-the-use-of-common-commerical-products-work-in-movies-tv/104845#104845)

   [Why didn't they send more complex data through the wormhole?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95875/why-didnt-they-send-more-complex-data-through-the-wormhole/104541#104541)

   [Who did the uncredited Magic Voice for MST3k, prior Mary Jo Pehl?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64064/who-did-the-uncredited-magic-voice-for-mst3k-prior-mary-jo-pehl/104579#104579)
4. (1) [Why did Gamora appear to Thanos as her younger self?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/95934/why-did-gamora-appear-to-thanos-as-her-younger-self/104455#104455)

   [Is it known what would have happened in later seasons of "Everything sucks!"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96672/is-it-known-what-would-have-happened-in-later-seasons-of-everything-sucks/104539#104539)

   [The recording being played in Pawn Sacrifice while Jefferson Airplane's "White Rabbit" plays](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49393/the-recording-being-played-in-pawn-sacrifice-while-jefferson-airplanes-white-r/104630#104630)

   [What is the cultural significance of the "kaiju screech"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60231/what-is-the-cultural-significance-of-the-kaiju-screech/104852#104852)
5. (0) [What is the cultural significance of the "kaiju screech"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60231/what-is-the-cultural-significance-of-the-kaiju-screech/104866#104866)

   [What is the significance of "C-12" in In The Line Of Fire?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97735/what-is-the-significance-of-c-12-in-in-the-line-of-fire/104699#104699)
6. (-1) [Ending of "The Man From Earth: Holocene"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92055/ending-of-the-man-from-earth-holocene/104606#104606)

   [Why does Hugh Glass look at the camera at the ending scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74246/why-does-hugh-glass-look-at-the-camera-at-the-ending-scene/104643#104643)
7. (-2) [What is the significance of "C-12" in In The Line Of Fire?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97735/what-is-the-significance-of-c-12-in-in-the-line-of-fire/104823#104823)