# Monthly Answer Challenge 2020: Solve old unanswered questions!

Tags: discussion, challenge, answers

Similar to our [previous challenges for answering unanswered questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/49), we're continuing our **monthly habit** of rewarding the best answer to any old unanswered question in order to encourage people to engage into solving some of our old unsolved problems. Thus independent from our more question-centered [weekly topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49), we'd like you to **answer any question that was asked more than 3 months before the current month and that doesn't have an answer yet**.

To check for eligible questions you can use the [search function](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3Ano+created%3A..2019-12) or [this data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/370061). The top-voted answer given each month will be rewarded **a bounty of 100 points if it has a score of at least 3 or has been accepted**.

Comment: when do you usually update these?

Comment: @DForck42 Update what? The challenge results? Whenever I get around to it. I try to do it in the month after, but sometimes I also forget it and do two months at once, in that case the votes might not reflect the exact score at the end of the month.

Comment: neat, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The **January 2020** challenge has garnered 11 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 4) coming from [*user45266*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/73507), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [How old are Love Händel?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84732/how-old-are-love-h%c3%a4ndel/106422#106422)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (2) [Does the little boy Brock know who poisoned him?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104168/does-the-little-boy-brock-know-who-poisoned-him/106272#106272)
3. (1) [Why did the detective help drop the charges against the cult leader in Sinner season 2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102544/why-did-the-detective-help-drop-the-charges-against-the-cult-leader-in-sinner-se/106387#106387)

   [How do Cobb's children know which hotel he's staying at in Kyoto in Inception](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71738/how-do-cobbs-children-know-which-hotel-hes-staying-at-in-kyoto-in-inception/106304#106304)

   [Why didn't Sonny kill the hostages?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73375/why-didnt-sonny-kill-the-hostages/106039#106039)

   [What is a map of India doing at a US Army hospital?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72513/what-is-a-map-of-india-doing-at-a-us-army-hospital/106291#106291)
4. (0) [Ben Gardner's eye in Jaws](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97631/ben-gardners-eye-in-jaws/106169#106169)

   [What Object Did Marilyn Take and What Does it Mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82946/what-object-did-marilyn-take-and-what-does-it-mean/106377#106377)
5. (-1) [What is the significance of the cat in the final episode of The Sopranos?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89473/what-is-the-significance-of-the-cat-in-the-final-episode-of-the-sopranos/106214#106214)
6. (-2) [Watching Stewie sleep and rubbing knife against face reference?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93429/watching-stewie-sleep-and-rubbing-knife-against-face-reference/106163#106163)
7. (-5) [Was Alex Forrest actually pregnant?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64002/was-alex-forrest-actually-pregnant/106398#106398)

Comment: I'll try not to let it get to my head :) Seriously, thank you for the award. I didn't know about this challenge until you pinged me saying I had won it!

Answer (score 2):

The **March 2020** challenge has garnered 16 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 3 and acceptance) coming from [*GendoIkari*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/42015), which makes him the winner of this challenge and earns him a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [Why is Joe attacked earlier in the movie "You were never really here"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102551/why-is-joe-attacked-earlier-in-the-movie-you-were-never-really-here/107114#107114)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (2+V) [When were animal masks first used in horror or espionage in cinema?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/97237/when-were-animal-masks-first-used-in-horror-or-espionage-in-cinema/107118#107118)
3. (2) [Were the Borg originally their own race, before assimilation started?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/103141/were-the-borg-originally-their-own-race-before-assimilation-started/107143#107143)

   [Is Bruce Lee being made fun of?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102424/is-bruce-lee-being-made-fun-of/107012#107012)
4. (1+V) [Why would Kim Murphy be scared that her parents bought a piano for Bob?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99612/why-would-kim-murphy-be-scared-that-her-parents-bought-a-piano-for-bob/107267#107267)
5. (1) [How did Annabelle disappear from the closet?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90250/how-did-annabelle-disappear-from-the-closet/107005#107005)

   [Why was Kes ignored in Year of Hell?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69082/why-was-kes-ignored-in-year-of-hell/107123#107123)

   [Why do Mike and Tuco have the same boxing charm?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/88069/why-do-mike-and-tuco-have-the-same-boxing-charm/107011#107011)

   [Did Jamal miss the second shot on purpose?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/86099/did-jamal-miss-the-second-shot-on-purpose/107185#107185)

   [What does Hiroshi Abe (阿倍) do in Legend of the Demon Cat (妖猫传)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92936/what-does-hiroshi-abe-%e9%98%bf%e5%80%8d-do-in-legend-of-the-demon-cat-%e5%a6%96%e7%8c%ab%e4%bc%a0/107219#107219)
6. (0) [Where did this boy come from in The Nun?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/94405/where-did-this-boy-come-from-in-the-nun/107004#107004)

   [The Conjuring 2 dining room and library name of demon fact or fiction?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/62182/the-conjuring-2-dining-room-and-library-name-of-demon-fact-or-fiction/107002#107002)

   [Could Bill Cipher be an avatar of Nyarlathotep?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75362/could-bill-cipher-be-an-avatar-of-nyarlathotep/107333#107333)

   [Why does Matthew think that no one else realizing Steven’s two drinks was lucky?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/99752/why-does-matthew-think-that-no-one-else-realizing-steven-s-two-drinks-was-lucky/107297#107297)

   [Why does the old woman in the film The Survivalist die?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/52011/why-does-the-old-woman-in-the-film-the-survivalist-die/107295#107295)
7. (-1) [How did Agent C realize who the traitor was?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105148/how-did-agent-c-realize-who-the-traitor-was/107385#107385)

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The **February 2020** challenge has garnered 6 answers, with the top voted answer (with a score of 2 and acceptance) coming from [*codeczar*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/60982), which makes them the winner of this challenge and earns them a bounty of 100 additional reputation:

## 1. [What happened to Jessie Quick?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104671/what-happened-to-jessie-quick/106591#106591)

The other answers in order of votes are:

2. (1+V) [What is the round object given to Philippe by Papa Rudy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/60821/what-is-the-round-object-given-to-philippe-by-papa-rudy/106613#106613)
3. (1) [Is this scene from Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. essentially a realistic depiction of filming a fight scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51335/is-this-scene-from-agents-of-s-h-i-e-l-d-essentially-a-realistic-depiction-of-f/106573#106573)

   [What is the significance of the ending line of Brokeback Mountain?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90116/what-is-the-significance-of-the-ending-line-of-brokeback-mountain/106622#106622)

   [The baby in "The Wind"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/103068/the-baby-in-the-wind/106593#106593)

   [What are the 'true events'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69295/what-are-the-true-events/106562#106562)