# Community Promotion Ads - 2015

Tags: discussion, community-ads

This is supposed to have coincided [with the arrival of your new design](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/site-graduated-new-design-launched), but apparently I never actually posted it. Whoops.

At any rate, let's not delay this any longer. You've officially gained Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting blogs and websites for the curious
- cool events or conferences for particular movies or shows
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1745).

Comment: Other meta community ad questions (like [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/2318)) come with a template for answers and reject answers without images. Could this be done here, too?

Comment: @Martin It takes some time for the system to be hooked up - but yes, that will be in place. I already had it queued up when I posted this.

Comment: @GraceNote what happens when none of them get 6 votes?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I guess it just won't get switched to Community Ads and remain at random SE ads, until there are enough answers with reasonable traction. But it might just be a matter of time, even if that time is longer than on sites with a more active meta community.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Meet the Real Thor -- Join the Mythology Stack Exchange]

Comment: from [here](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/a/193)

Comment: Wow, one of the most craftily designed ads in all SE!

Answer (score 11):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]
<sub>(source: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/movies.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>

Comment: This is an adaption of [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/1884) that will adapt if we have questions with bounties. The resolution is _not_ a problem.

Comment: Is it possible to make one for unaswered question?

Comment: @AnkitSharma: See [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1446)

Comment: thanks for the link, ahhhh...its not that dynamic, need to do my homework first ;)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Visit our meta site!]

Comment: Inspired by [Chemistry.SE](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/2721) and [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5888), Created with help from [Napoleon Wilson ♦](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/users/49/napoleon-wilson).

Comment: can you make one for new dimensions?

Answer (score 9):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Filmmaking]
<sub>(source: [stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/ads/proposal/85123.png))</sub>

Comment: I'd love it if we could promote the Filmmaking Q&A site here. I'm so bad at coming up with questions, but I haven't abandoned it... Just need a boost.

Answer (score 8):

[image: I Remember This Movie]

Comment: Nice idea to send off ID's :)

Comment: why are we asking the number one type of question we seem to get to go elsewhere?

Comment: @CGCampbell Because they're also the worst questions we get. If someone is engaged enough in this community to conciously ask it here, then that's someone who'll probably also put a recent amount of effort into the question. For everybody else who merely didn't find a better place for the question it can't hurt to at least inform them that there are other places that might not put as many evil quality restrictions upon those questions as we do.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Name That Movie]

Answer (score 5):

[image: 3D graphics!]

Comment: Learn more about the processes used to add that nasty CGI to movies!

Answer (score 3):

[image: The Armory Proposal at Area51]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Suits - Law.SE]

Comment: It looks quite nice (even if the lower text could use some antialiasing and colour correction), but I don't really see the two sites in particularly close relation, if any at all. But well, it's up to the community to vote for it anyway.

Comment: Well, I'd imagine people wonder, "hey, I've seen people do X on Suits/Law & Order, can they _really_ do that?" (I'll actually fix up the AA on it and put another one up soon!)

Comment: Hmm, also interesting viewpoint, maybe the text could even adress that point more. (Afterall, I'd be looking forward to the *L&O* ad more, since I guess that often treats some interesting legal intricacies in a not too unrealistic way. But I've admittedly never seen *Suits*, maybe it does, too).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson yeah, something that GIMP does must mess with the colours, it's happened on  my L&O one, too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Like us on Facebook!]

Comment: @NapoleonWilson thank you for the help.

Answer (score -2):

[image: Support this proposal]

Comment: Um you might actually be a year too late with your update. ;-)