# Is there any news about the graduation swag?

Tags: support, design, graduation

As part of the [site's graduation over 3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521/49) there was promise for certain graduation swag to be delivered to the top users of the site during graduation (the first 2 [user pages](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), that is, i.e. the top 72 users by reputation). This swag was supposed to be based on [*Kurtis Beavers*' amazing design](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/49), especially a very nice T-shirt in the site's colors and featuring those neat little movie images (earlier pictures also had a coffee mug).

[image]

It was said, that SE will somehow make forms accessible for the respective users in order to fill in the necessary contact information to get this stuff delivered. However, nothing to this effect happened since then. So **I'd like to acquire *some* kind of information about the status of this**. Is notice on this to be expected in the future? Will it be delayed for a significant time? Did I just miss that contact form? Or is this just an absolutely natural delay of things.

<sub>While I and others have received the swag for moderator candidation already (and the form came pretty fast, compared to this), it came with a standard SE T-shirt and not a Movies.SE T-shirt, contrary to my specification on the form. So there is the possibility that the notice has been deleayed due to the difficulties of creating those amazing Movies & TV T-shirts. If that is the case this would be nice to know, too, and would be worth the waiting time indeed.</sub>

Comment: I got something about being given swag for at least stepping up to be a mod, but I don't recall receiving a package. I believe I set the address to be my parent's in the event it came while I was out of the country, but I can't remember where the link to the original form came from to verify that, or if I could even verify the address at this point.

Comment: I haven't received the mod candidate package either. I am not so sure if what you got wasn't more of a SE mod welcome shirt.

Comment: No response to my last mail. I don't think they will send anything. :/

Comment: I was promised some swag on another SE site. Eventually I prodded a CM via the contact-us form below and lo-and-behold, it turned up within a few days.

Comment: I'd like to say that the issue of site swag is one of the things that SE staff seem to do appallingly badly. There are promises made and broken, ignored and eventually everyone just gets pissed off. If you're going to offer free stuff, actually send it. If you aren't going to send it, don't bloody offer it.

Comment: @Richard I already asked the CM's about it and the answer was similar to the one quoted by Ankit in his answer (i.e. *"wait and see"*). I'd wager in your case it was a site that already had swag produced for it and you simply got forgotten on an individual level, rather than the site not having any swag at all. (I can't help but agree with your more general sentiments, though.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - In my instance it was the "took part in a mod election" swag that took nearly 7 months to arrive. I'm still waiting on my "hit 100k" swag. It's been 2+ months since I last asked about it. I've stopped expecting it by now.

Answer (score 1):

From the meta answer on:-

[How will graduation/election swag work with the changes to the “graduation” process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264222/how-will-graduation-election-swag-work-with-the-changes-to-the-graduation-proc)

> Don't expect any new graduation swag to start popping up until the
>   design backlog gets cleared out and they have more time to spend on
>   other things. -  [animuson♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268888/182734)

As we know graduation queue is bit long, so it was not expected to come any soon.

Comment: I suspect it doesn't help that they offered free swag to the squillions of people that responded to the "free swag" question over on Stack Overflow.