# Movies&TV — Top User Swag!

Tags: discussion

Good news! If your name is on the first two pages of:

https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

...I'll be getting in touch with you soon to send you a little care package, as a token of our appreciation for being awesome and making this site a success! Inside a little blue box of wonders, you'll find:

**A T-SHIRT!**

[image: T-SHIRTS!!!!!!!]

**STICKERS!**

[image: STICKER SHEET]

The whole sheet shown here is 8.5” x 11” (~20cm x ~28cm) and each little frame ~1.25” x 1” (~3cm x ~2.5cm).

I'll be reaching out to you at some point next week, so be sure to fill out the form as soon as you're able to do so. You'll have two weeks to do so, after which, this stuff will be shipped your way! I could tell you this would take 6 to 8 weeks, but I'm not gonna offer a precise prediction for when these will arrive at your doorstep.

If you're not on the list, don't worry too much about it — we've got some extra swag stored we can send to you for events and such.

Thanks to all of you for making this site great!

Comment: WUUUUUT????!!!! Finally! And right for christmas, thank you so much! \o/

Comment: No love for page 6ers ;) jk. Cool shirts.

Comment: Good news.....!!!!!! Finally its arrived.

Comment: Is the other [mentioned stuff](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ObzyW.jpg) from Design post canceled or is it part of some yet to come event.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - It seems unlikely that they're going to send out a hundred iPhones.

Comment: @AnkitSharma We're only doing t-shirts and stickers ;)

Comment: @Richard i was expecting mug or pen drive. I think phone image were just for app or wap view

Comment: Schwiiiing!!  And I just got a Swag Bag today from SO.  It's gonna be a doubly-kewl Christmas!

Comment: Why is Jack's face all red???

Comment: @cde because he's angry?

Comment: I'd be angry too if it looked like someone ripped all the skin off my face like that :O

Comment: As of right now, I'm the last user on page two of the reputation leagues. If I end up being overtaken, do I still get mad swag? Or do I need to remain on the page?

Comment: @DrRDizzle I'll be pulling the names today, so hopefully you won't get overtaken — but I'll make a note to send you stuff either way ;)

Comment: Awesome stuff!! Can't wait to get it! :D Thanks very much

Comment: I just got my email. I shall [wait eagerly by the postbox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iIEZE.gif)

Comment: Looks great! It's very kind of you. Greetings from Istanbul.

Comment: I got my email. :-)

Comment: Still havent got my mail.....what do I do?  :(

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher I did send an e-mail to the e-mail address associated with your account. Did you check your spam folder? Or maybe your address is out-of-date? If that's the case, please let me know by e-mailing it to me directly.

Comment: @JNat: My bad! It got lost in the heaps of mail that I had. On top of that, silly me was trying to search the mail using the filter 'StackExchange' instead of 'StackOverflow'. Form filled! Can't wait for my swag to arrive. Many thanks :)

Comment: The swags are on the way!

Comment: Got my shirt today. Looks great. More red than orange, which I like a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Checking in from Belgium: got my swag today! Muchas gracias!

Comment: My t-shirt arrived yesterday. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JNat: I was inactive for a while, but am one of the top rep users on the site. Is it too late to claim some swaggy swag?

Comment: @AndrewMartin Shoot an e-mail using the "contact us" form located at the bottom of the page, and we'll try to get it sorted as soon as we can (which could take a while, since the existing stock hasn't been loaded into the database yet).

Comment: @JNat I didn't got the swag yet. Is their a way to track it? Even i have seen someone from India wearing it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma There's no way to track it, unfortunately. Give it a little more time. If it still hasn't been delivered by the end of February, shoot me an e-mail to let me know.

Comment: @JNat k, will surely do that.

Comment: Same here, nothing yet.

Comment: The same applies to you, then, @cde ;)

Comment: @JNat I still didn't got the swag.

Comment: I'll try to check out what might have happened, @AnkitSharma. Will report later.

Comment: @JNat Will eagerly wait for the reply.

Comment: Looks like your order got stuck on customs, @Ankit. I'll be sending a new one, this time with tracking (which I'll get to you once it's been shipped).

Comment: @JNat thanks for the response :)

Comment: Your swag has been delivered, @Ankit — can you confirm that you got it?

Comment: @JNat i didn't received

Comment: Will reach out to you via e-mail, @Ankit.

Comment: @sanpaco Well, [here's another chance](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2504/49) then.

Answer (score 8):

As keen as I am to get graduation swag (Gimme! Gimme! Gimme!), shouldn't those that were in the top 2 pages **[when the site actually graduated](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/is-there-any-news-about-the-graduation-swag)** also get some swag?

I'm certain that in the months since the promise of swag was first made, there will be those that contributed to the success of the site in earlier days that have since dropped off the bottom of the list and are now on page three.

Comment: Very selfless from you, I'm impressed! ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - I'm *fairly* certain that I was in the top 2 pages three months ago.

Comment: You've got a point. I'll look up those users and send 'em swag too. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @JNat - While you're down in the post-room, I'm still waiting on my swag for hitting 100K on SFF:SE :-)

Comment: @Richard Maybe, but I don't think you were during graduation (which was nearly 10 months ago).

Comment: @Richard I know, I handle those. We're currently out of stock for SciFi swag. I'll ship 'em your way as soon as we're restocked ;)

Comment: @JNat - I had some SFF:SE swag when I became a mod. I'm quite happy with generic SE stuff if that's all you've got. And I also want a stapler.

Comment: @Richard is there some rule for 100K swag? Never heard before

Comment: @AnkitSharma - https://twitter.com/mark_baker/status/577906176458924033

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I got my stapler too :-)

Comment: And I am still waiting for my movie swag :(

Comment: Let me know if it still didn't get there by next week, @AnkitSharma ;)

Comment: Surely will tell you

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for all your effort and this great swag!

Unfortunately, as you can see, the T-shirt turned out completely red instead of the site's trademark organge-red color as promised in all the swag pictures we were shown and as devised by the designers as the colour of our site. This slightly hurts both the orange-lover in me as well as the avid M&TV user striving for a consistent branding in all its design properties.

However, we should be glad that we got anything at all and apart from the conceptually off color, the T-shirt looks and fits really nice and the whole idea of those little film and TV-show pictures yet again turns out to be a great design choice that makes itself really good on a T-shirt. Thanks again to the SE team for providing us with this stuff.

[image]

Comment: I'm wearing my t-shirt right now. It fits OK and it turned up so that's at least 2 out of 3 as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Nice pic +1. I hope people don't get confuse with the hat as its mod specific only.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - Are the grey camo trousers also mod-specific?

Comment: @Richard Yes, they are customly made for German mods only :P

Comment: We had a limited color choice, and this was the closest we could get. It's like designing with web-safe colors :)

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Thanks for the info. I hoped something like that.

Comment: You look very good & handsome!! :)

Comment: @AnkitSharma We need Mike to change it to a Steelers hat.  Hehehe :)

Comment: @steelerfan with his new name, I don't know how to even ping him to do so.

Comment: @steelerfan Wow, so many [steelers hats](http://www.nflshop.com/Pittsburgh_Steelers_Hats)