# 5 Years of Movies & TV - Free T-shirts!

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event

## Movies & TV Stack Exchange celebrates its 5th anniversary!

We'd like to take this opportunity to thank the community of this wonderful site for the years of dedication and hard work they put into it. And luckily we can even thank you materially, since as it turns out, we still have a T-shirt left from [last year's christmas event on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271359/162011).

[image]

About one year ago this site [finally got graduation swag](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2040/49), including a cool T-shirt with our beloved little images of famous films and TV-shows. However, this was only awarded to the top 72 users by reputation and there could very well have been forgotten many people who actively contributed to making this site as great as it is today. Therefore, and in celebration of the site's 5th anniversary, we want to give you the chance to

### Win a free Movies & TV T-shirt! Tell us your story!

Just answer this question and tell us about your experiences on this site, how you contributed to it and **why you deserve that Movies & TV T-shirt**. It doesn't matter if you found this site just a year ago and didn't have enough time to amass a whole lot of reputation, or if you have been a long-time member and simply didn't do so many glamourous reputation-awarding things. Whatever you feel is relevant and however you feel you contributed to the site. You might as well want to tell us what could be improved on the site or any other nice ideas you have for the next 5 years of Movies & TV. But those are all just hints for inspiring your answer, no strict rules. You don't have to have provided a certain amount of answers or cast a certain amount of flags. Just tell us whatever you think makes you the one best dressed in a Movies & TV T-shirt.

---

**Some technical details:**

- There will be one winner, **chosen by the community itself through their votes on the corresponding answers** here on meta.
- We'd like to only award people who actually want a T-shirt, so **self-nominations only** please.
- It would be preferable to award users who didn't already get a T-shirt from the graduation swag event. However, if you already have a T-shirt, you can still try to get another one, but you might want to bring up a really good reason (maybe your loved one is a huge fan of the site too and half of your questions and answers come actually from him/her, or maybe a dingo ate your previous shirt, or you just want to have it in order to gift it away during a crazy meta event, ...).
- When the event is over, **SE will reach out to the winner** for the shipping and size details.
- Nominations closed on **December 14th**, 12:00 UTC.
- Voting closed on **December 24th**, 12:00 UTC.

---

## Voting closed - congratulations to DVK for winning the T-shirt!

Comment: You generous fellows :-)

Comment: ... & I missed the whole thing & only found this post today :/ It has to be said though, that most of my rep was gained by correctly recognising a cooking utensil used in The Shining, so I doubt I'd have been in the running anyway ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin - in other words, the most practical piece of info possible! Can't knock that down.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## My story:

> Forgery of Imperial documents. Possession of stolen property. Aggravated assault. Resisting arrest. On my own from the age of 15. Reckless, aggressive and undisciplined.

Sorry, wrong tab, was applying for a job elsewhere. My most unusual movie-related story:

> I was once hauled before a school's principal and nearly arrested, for participating **in a contest to name a newly built local movie theater**, as an avid movie-goer.
>   They mistook my idea of naming it "Metallist" based on the fact that nearly everyone in the borough worked at a metallurgy plant; for wanting to name a theater after heavy metal. In USSR. Oups.
>
> As a matter of fact, I was so much a fan of movies, my parents almost got arrested once trying to smuggle somewhat-underaged myself into a film-club showing at that movie theater, showing Tarkovsky's *[Andrey Rublyov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Rublev_(film)#Plot)*. *(for those who haven't seen it, it has a rather adult scene showing pagan rites of nature that was at the time unacceptable in soviet films)*.

## Why do I deserve a t-shirt?

1. Because I provide (somewhat quality, I hope) [content on the site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/235/dvk).
2. Because **I already earned that t-shirt in the graduation swag giveaway**, but missed out on a chance at it when it was offered in 2015 due to unfortunate incident involving Yahoo spam filters and their apparent dislike of a certain CM at StackExchange. I wouldn't bet against a chance that the t-shirt being offered here may have supposed to be mine :)

   > I don’t really get that shirt. - *Frannie, "The fault in our stars"*.
3. Because I already provide free advertisement for SFF.SE by wearing their T-shirt to general public as well as nerd/geek audiences, and have gotten chances to send people to that site as a result. M&TV deserves the same PR.
4. Because I'm a movie fan who quotes random (obscure and not) movie lines to people at work, in my life, and (sometimes) generally on the street.

   > "**I deserve this today. Today I deserve it**" - *Batman*, *"The Lego Batman Movie"*
5. Because I offer a unique combination of being Napoleon's <strike>best friend</strike> <strike>strong ally</strike> supporter as a strident opponent of ID questions; and Napoleon's worst enemy (as someone who likes *gasp* books and novelizations and posts in-depth answers using them as source material).

Comment: When you say "missed out on it" do you mean to say that you've since contacted them and they are unable to send you a shirt?

Comment: @catija no,  I only saw the email after deadline passed,  so it was too late.

Comment: You might still consider writing to them to see if they have any left. They might see your explanation and feel pity for you. :)

Comment: Congratulations for winning, I'll let SE know and they should reach out to you for the shipping and size details. If there's problems again, please let me or them know about it this time.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - so far, nothing. This being around the holidays time period, I guess more patience is advisable :)

Comment: @DVK Well, I didn't contact them until 31.12. anyway. ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - 6 to 8 weeks. :)

Comment: @dvk did you ever got it ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma - yep, I did eventually, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I joined this SE a year ago and am a big fan of this site. I've visited this site almost everyday during this period.

I can't write long posts like others, so I will write short and simple one.

**Tell us about your experiences on this site**

I don't have much to say except that my experience here is great so far and people here are wonderful and friendly too.

**How you contributed to it**

This kinda question is usually asked to moderator candidates. Anyway, action speaks louder than words.

1. I've edited posts in order to make posts clean and organized.
2. Helped new users to learn how to use the site with helpful comments.
3. Reviewing posts from time to time.
4. Raised helpful flags
5. Asking and answering questions
6. Suggesting Topic Challenges

**Why you deserve a Movies & TV T-shirt.**

I've missed it the last time and I'd really love to have a souvenir. That's list of a movies contains my favorite ones. It'd look really cool.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer :-
I got mail and shared my address last time. But actually didn't receive last time. Anyways, my address was changed after 3 months of getting mail , not sure if it takes that much time to deliver.
You know last time , when I got mail that I am receiving t-shirt and I shared my address. I was really happy because I was not expecting t-shirt due to my geographical location.
But then I got disappointed when I did not received, like really really disappointed :-( :-(. That's why don't want to try as even if you dispatch, I may not get it due to courier services or whatever.

So Guys if you decide to send T-shirt by any chance (fingers crossed), do share courier tracking number or something so that I can share.

Long Answer :-
 <strike>Do I really need to share my contributions, when you can pull out the data.</strike>
My stats :-

258 helpful flags

1687 votes cast

4023 reputation

I have contributed fairly to this site, I am in **second position in two of Review queques**, that is , first post and Late answers.

I am gonna keep adding to this answer as this t-shirt going to be on my mind for sometime.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, I actually originally stumbled upon the Movies & TV StackExchange while looking for quotes to use in a [blog post](https://oldnewsisgoodnews.wordpress.com/2015/07/30/did-the-hobbit-movies-suck/) about Peter Jackson's Hobbit movies. (I ended up linking to an [old question about the Eagles](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9172/why-not-make-full-use-of-the-eagles-in-the-hobbit/9178#9178) because Oliver_C's answer to the question explained why the Eagles made so much more sense in the book than in the movies.)

I would later join Movies & TV (in case you hadn't noticed) and even asked my own [Hobbit-trilogy-related question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42424/why-was-the-hobbit-split-into-three-films). While a lot of my other questions are identification questions, I like to think that I'm pretty detailed when I ask them - to the point that one user (Walt) was [able to identify](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/47225/22599) one of the movies I was asking about even though [I got the decade and country of origin completely off](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/47222/22599).

Plus, while my questions game isn't always as on-point as I'd like, I'll admit that I'm pretty proud of some of my answers to others' questions about film [production](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/51067/22599) (slash [post-production](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/57114/22599)) and [history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/41736/was-regeneration-planned-right-from-the-start-of-doctor-who/41739#41739). (I am still disproportionately disappointed that my [overview of film "firsts"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42182/22599) didn't get officially picked as the correct answer for that ["world's first movie"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/42179/22599) question last year.) Other answers that I am particularly proud of include:

1. Laying out various TV tropes to explain how characters like Jack Bauer get away with so much ([an answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/41972/22599) that not everybody may agree with, but that made me happy because I researched and found a bunch of tropes that I felt describes the typical "action (anti-)hero" pretty well).
2. [Identifying a show](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/42713/22599) for somebody through strategic Googling, even though I had personally never seen it.

And on top of that, even when I'm quiet on the questions and answers front, I do quite a bit of editing to make sure that readers can understand other questions and answers as easily as possible. (Professionally speaking, I'm a copy editor as well as a videographer and video editor, so I'd like to think that my edits are quite meticulous!)

So... do I deserve a t-shirt?

Well, I know I'd *like* one. Like fabrice d, I missed it the last time, so didn't get the chance to put my name in. Up to you whether you think my contributions are more worthy of a free t-shirt than those of the rest of these good people!

Answer (score 3):

### My Story

My story actually begins long before I joined this community, back in December 2013 when I went to watch **The Hobbit: Desolation of Smaug** with my family. We went every Christmas to see the original **Lord of the Rings** films when I was a child, and now we were recreating that with these new releases.

Well, that film was so utterly awful that it actually ruined all movies for me for a whole year. For 12 months I picked holes in every single thing that I watched, overanalysing minor details and ruining my enjoyment of anything on screen, which I hated about myself because it meant that I didn't have the fulfillment that I previously felt when watching movies.

Ironically enough, it was **The Hobbit: Battle of the Five Armies** that fixed this problem for me. I felt that that movie was so close to being exceptional that even though it had many glaring problems, I could look past them in my own mind to allow myself to enjoy films again. (If anyone is interested in how I did this, I've commented on it previously [in this Writers.SE post](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/22014/how-to-avoid-slipping-into-fault-finding-when-reading/22022#22022)).

3 months later in March 2015 I joined this community, and felt that I could put my work in overanalysing the plot of movies to good use (over half my answers are under [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation)), to look past what is on the screen to see deeper into the meaning of the film, and to help others to understand things that I myself couldn't a short time earlier.

It feels great when someone asks a question on understanding a finer point of a movie, and knowing an answer that will help them out. My personal favorite that I posted is [this answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61035/explanation-on-the-ending-of-500-days-of-summer/61041#61041) about **500 days of Summer**, explaining the deeper theme of the movie and why the last scene is such a good way to end it.

I've even gone one step further and now run own my own movie review blog with my wife (I won't post a link as that's against [the rules](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) to advertise personal products), all of which wouldn't have been possible if this community was not here. And what better way to celebrate that than wearing a fancy Movies.SE T-shirt whilst writing further reviews?

### Contributions

I've done my fair share of upvoting, but my greatest contribution is in the answers I've posted. Of the **49 answers** that I've posted to questions on this site, **28 of them** were accepted by the Original Poster, doing some quick maths shows that *over 50% of my answers* were the accepted answer.

I actually didn't know this until I just looked now in order to research this answer, but I've actually impressed myself. Whilst that knowledge is itself reward enough, a fancy Movies.SE T-shirt would be the icing on the cake.

### Do I deserve a T shirt?

Whilst I have only been a member for under 2 years, in that time I've contributed quite a lot. So much so that I have gained enough reputation to put me currently at [the 71 spot](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/167/alltime/movies/2011-11-30?sort=reputationchange&page=3) on the reputation leadership table.

So this means that even though I never had the chance to receive a T-shirt in the original giveaway, I am now **in the top 72**, which was originally the cutoff for receiving the T-shirts the first time.

I think this means that I am deserving *enough* for the free giveaway, but whether I'm the *most* deserving is down to you, kind voter. And don't let my obvious attempts at pandering dissuade you from upvoting, you wonderful beautiful human.

Answer (score 2):

I first discovered the Movies & TV SE site in July of 2015 and I was super excited because I had finally found a place where I could participate in the sharing of knowledge on this topic.

I have always enjoyed visual arts but discovered early on that I had a passion for following plots and analyzing film as a hobby. I would often pick up on things in movies that my friends and family didn't and would be the one explaining the movie to them in the lobby. When I discovered this site and saw the many intelligent questions being asked, I was thrilled to discover many new challenges. I have spent many hours in the past year and a half coming here and looking for unanswered questions to movies I have never seen and being able to expose myself to some great films and approach them very analytically, with a goal of gathering evidence or examples to answer a specific question.

I also find myself watching movies in a different way. I often try to identify possible questions that I could come here and ask that would add value to the site and that others might be interested in. I love the feeling I get when I am able to notice something that others might not have noticed before. I also love the feeling I get when I am able to answer a question to the asker's satisfaction.

I am not nearly as good with my response format as I'd like to be, but I have improved since I've been active here. I've found my ability to present an argument has increased and improved and this has spilled over into my job, part of which involves maintaining technical documentation and answering technical questions via email.

My site reputation has increased to a level that if the original giveaway were happening this year, I would qualify to receive this wonderful swag. I was on page 6 last year after 6 months of membership. Today after another year I am on the top of page 2. I'll admit that reputation is a large part of my motivation for using this site, but only because I love the rewarding feeling of peer validation and I enjoy having something that I can work towards and feel like I am improving myself.

Finally, I love swag. I am a swag producer myself and collect items like this from all communities that I feel like I am a part of. Many of my coworkers know of my love of film and also know that I actively participate in this SE site. I've even had some of them tell me that they googled a question about a movie and were led to one of my answers. I would love to be able to display my love of this site to others.

Thanks for the opportunity to win this gift and thanks to everyone who helps make this a great place to share our passion!

Answer (score 2):

**Why?**

I joined this website because I guess, like many people, the world of films and TV shows holds a few mysteries that the Internet can't always solve.

Or because there are [movie bits floating in my head](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36901/movie-with-children-chased-by-adults-dressed-in-black) that I can't really link to anything in existence. And because, obviously, any movie fan should get on here and learn behind-the-scenes secrets or [expand their understanding of films](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/64162/does-mia-mistake-vincents-heroin-for-cocaine-because-its-in-a-baggie-rather-th) they saw.

**How did i help?**

I'm pretty active on the site. I edit, I ask, I answer. There was a time last year when my answer really made a difference. I helped out someone  by finding a short film they were looking for. It was hard but I was really curious to find it for them. I browsed lots of pages on IMDb before changing methods. Dinner came and I missed it. I kept on looking, using another technique.

I found a small clue and started unravelling the answer, piece by piece. After a good 2 hours spent looking, I had found the answer. I wrote a long answer, even linking to a video of the short film the asker was looking for.

I imagined them watching it and revisiting their past memories of the day they first saw the film, almost 30 years ago. How films bring back memories sometimes. How bittersweet the nostalgia that it brings does taste.

[Eventually my answer was accepted](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42310/early-90s-short-film-made-up-entirely-of-bullet-time-camera-work/49430#49430) and I was filled with joy. Happy that I could have helped. Happy that the search was over for the asker, almost 30 years on. Happy to get some karma points - and some SE points as well.

And hoping that more people will keep coming on this website to ask, answer, help or simply learn.

**Do I deserve a tee-shirt?**

Gee, I don't know. If I do, it could be because I believe that doing something nice... feels nice! I always try to improve the site and contribute. Of all the SE communities I'm a part of, it's the one for which I have the highest number of points. I like the way it looks and I'm sure that if I wear it people would be interested to check out Movies & TV SE. Which I think they should!

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't contributed much to this community, I always been a fan. Movies.se was always helpful for me to understand a movie or series completely. In other words, movies.se completes the story. It covers all unexplained, unpredictable moments of a story. If you are a big fan of movies or a series, you should definitely hangout here. I always hangout here browsing questions about my favorite programmes and the detailed answers which mesmerize me always. I feel like a kid in a fantasy world while being here. I enjoy this community. I want to show people around me that I am a fan and a community member of movies.se. :)

Answer (score -4):

Well honestly i have never contributed here but yes i found really great talks about series and movies. And i started watching it. Many TV Series i have started after joining this site.

I have watched

- **Breaking Bad** (Whole series) ,
- **GOT**(Till last season),
- **How I met you mother**.
- **Sherlock** (Big fan)

And i am still watching

- **House of Cards**(Completed just season 1, Yes i know i am very late) ,
- **The Big Bang Theory** (Till Season 10 episode 6) ,
- **Dexter** ( Till season 3. I got too much into Breaking Bad that i stopped it there only. But never started it again.Wanted to start) and yes
- many other Local Indian Web series (oh that was by my own:D)

Even i got inspired to see movies like **Enemy At The Gates** , **The Great Gatsby** and many more.

Now the main question **why i deserve a Movies & TV T-shirt** :

***Short Answer*** : I like free stuff :D

***Long Answer*** : Honestly i was not into much movies and series. But since i have joined this site i got too much into the movies and series. Its really good to be the part of this community although I've not contributed here but still it helped me to find some really good stuff. And I'm sure it will inspire me in future as well.