# Identify movies and TV shows from the image in the top bar / banner

Tags: support, faq, design

Which are the TV shows and Movies shown in the image of the top bar?

Comment: Is there a reason this is on the meta? Wouldn't it be on topic for the site?

Comment: @jpmc26 It has been discussed in meta before, [Should we move the canonical top-bar image identification question to the main site?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1625/should-we-move-the-canonical-top-bar-image-identification-question-to-the-main-s)

Comment: Related: ["UPDATED (January 9) Design for Movies SE"](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/74275)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The header background image contains the covers or famous scenes from 17 TV series and movies.

[image: Site Background]

Here is the background shown with the original (or similar) beneath.

[image: With Original]

1. Star Wars (A New Hope)
2. Batman
3. Gone with the Wind
4. Metropolis
5. Breaking Bad
6. Citizen Kane
7. Dr. Who
8. Forest Gump
9. Twin Peaks
10. The Lion King
11. Godfather 2
12. North by Northwest
13. Sharknado
14. The Shining
15. Dragon Ball Z
16. King Kong
17. Star Trek

Comment: After adding images, i suspect you work with them and spy in here :p anyways nice work.

Comment: SHARKNADO made it here ? Goddamit

Comment: Wow, didn't know the images were *that* accurate. Great work!

Comment: Still amuses me that Sharknado made the cut.

Comment: One thing I notice is that Jack Nicholson live is (to me) much scarier than the drawing....

Comment: Great findings with actual images.

Comment: I would have guessed a scene from _Jaws_ would be better than _Sharknado_.

Comment: I thought the _Dragon Ball Z_ one was Cruella De Vil from _101 Dalmations_!

Comment: @yondaime008 The trailer of Sharknado is impressive! (but the 3.3 / 10 on IMDb less impressive)

Comment: Huh. I spent years thinking the "Breaking Bad" image was actually "Mythbusters".