# What happened with this question that was migrated to meta... why was it closed rather than duped?

Tags: support, migration, closed-questions

Due to a question on SFF, I was playing with the 10K tools and looking around a bit. When I clicked on the "rejected" tab, I was surprised to find only one... [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/what-are-the-movies-and-tv-shows-on-the-movies-stackexchange-header):

[image: Rejected Question to meta]

This is a dupe of our "what are the images in the header" question and it usually gets migrated to meta and then duped to the [existing question](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/identify-movies-and-tv-shows-from-the-image-in-the-top-bar)... like [this one](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2145/what-are-the-movies-and-tv-shows-in-this-sites-header).

For some reason, this one got put "on hold", which sent it back to the main site and then deleted by the OP. Now, in the long run, does it really matter? No... but it's a bit odd to me.

As you can see, it's still technically on the main site:

[image: What's going on here?]

Why did it get closed instead of duped? Closing effectively rejects the migration, sending it back to the main site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here's what happened with that question, the first 2 steps of which are exactly the proper way as outlined in your question already:

1. It was *migrated* from the main site to [meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2150/49).
2. Then it was indeed *closed as a duplicate* of the existing [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question.
3. Then **the user actually *deleted* his migrated question** on meta later.
4. Then he also deleted the original question on the main site later.

And the third step seems to be what rejected the migration. A migrated question getting deleted seems to reject a migration in the same way closing does. And when looking at the time stamps of the actions, the rejection of the migration happened at the exact same time as the deletion of the migrated question.

So there wasn't any unusual treatment of the question, it got **handled in the same way as the other questions** of that kind. It was the deletion of the migrated question by the asker himself that led to the rejected migration.

Comment: Looks like it's a [known issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133524/migration-to-per-site-meta-should-not-be-reversed-by-closing-or-deletion) that SE isn't responding to.