# Bounty color mismatching to color scheme

Tags: support, design

I'm not sure if this a bug or a concious design decision.

In the [initial design proposal](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1501/49), the color of the "bounty tag" was adapted to the general color scheme of the site, thus it used some kind of cyan/green-blue instead of the classic blue, which seemed to fit very well:

> [image]

But in the final version, we're back at classic bounty blue:

> [image]

Was this forgotten to adapt or was there a particular reason this idea was dropped? Did it maybe violate existing SE practice too much (yet, there are other more extreme sites where the bounty color is red)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've been working to standardize some UI elements between our different Q&A sites. There are a few places when we were creating the Movies & TV theme we made a conscious decision to standardize rather than customize. This is one of them, but it's not an exact science yet.

Comment: Ok, this also explains the similarity of other small things (accept background shape, favourite stars, vote arrows) I've seen across many of the new designs. Nothing wrong with standardization, I guess, it's just that I liked this color scheming very much, but nevermind, it isn't a big deal.