# Why was the design of the sub-headers in the Community Bulletin changed?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, design

I recently noticed that the design of the sub-headers in the Community Bulletin has been changed to not use all caps anymore and I wonder why this has been done.

[image]

Seeing that [a request for this](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1660/49) has been declined by the community for various reasons, as described [in this answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1661/49), and that it seems to go against the general design guidelines of the site (afterall the rest of the sub-headers in the sidebar still use all-caps, but don't take that as a motivation to change those, too, please ;-)), **I wonder what the reasons for this are**. Is this just a bug or was this part of the profile page revision (for whatever reason) or has this been changed for a completely different uncommunicated reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the new profile, we've been been converting sites across the Stack Exchange network to a new CSS framework. As we have been doing this there is an ongoing critical rethinking of which site elements should be custom per site vs. which should be standard across all sites. The community bulletin is one of those items that we felt wasn't necessary to customize—this makes it more of a global network feature and more recognizable to users who visit more than one of the SE sites. Plus it makes it easier to launch new features around the bulletin in the future. I apologize for the lack of communication around the change, it was not intentional.