# MOVIES & TV community name need to be CAPS in communities drop down list?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

In the explanation by the community [moderator's answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1661/29292)

> The all-caps style of captions is inherent to the style of this site, as also evident from the site's logo text, which isn't "Movies & TV" but **"MOVIES & TV"**. And I think this all-caps style is fitting very well to the topic .....

If so the same should be applied in the **Current Community** and **Your Communities** drop down list also. But it was not.

Screen shot for reference:

Community drop down list

[image: Community ddl]

Logos

[image: Logos]

**Note:** I am not sure, it is a bug or feature-request. So I tag it as discussion. Please feel free to change the relevant tag(s) to this post.

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

The all caps on the M&TV *site* makes sense, as the logo is in all caps.

The navigation is *not* specific to the site you're on, it's uniform to the Stack Exchange network's overall styling.

Making M&TV all caps in that dropdown menu would cause it to look out of place with the rest of the items in the menu.

To make this clear:

From a design standpoint, topside nav is for navigating across the entire Stack Exchange network, and anything bellow that is site specific.

Comment: Worth noting that other sites have funky logo choices; biology is all in lower case, Mi Yodeya isn't even in English.

Comment: Right, but that's the *logo*. The text in the menu here referring to is still uniform with the other sites in that menu. At least that's what I see via the mobile app when I checked just now.